# Why won't you close a question I asked and later flagged for moderator attention as a duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/25678/how-does-windows-7-licensing-work-for-running-the-os-as-virtual-machines) on superuser, and [Lee](https://superuser.com/users/5605/lee) referenced [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/53380/can-a-windows-7-ultimate-product-key-be-used-for-virtual-machines-as-well) on serverfault in [his answer](https://superuser.com/questions/25678/how-does-windows-7-licensing-work-for-running-the-os-as-virtual-machines/25708#25708).

I then marked the question for moderator attention and noted it should be closed as a duplicate. I never received a response of any kind. It seems one of three things happened.

1. A moderator has yet to look at the question after I flagged it (doubtful)
2. A moderator feels that the question is not a duplicate and simply did not communicate that to me.
3. I am going about getting my question closed the wrong way.

Comment: I'm editing this because you tagged the wrong user...

Answer (score 11):

I don't understand your request. You're arguing that cross-site duplicates are grounds for closure?

I'm not sure I agree with that, as the different audiences may have significantly different viewpoints on a question that is "the same".

Comment: Jeff, Perhaps you need to weigh in at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates

Answer (score 4):

Duplicates aren't closed cross-site unless they are migrated to said site beforehand.

The mods on SU are top-notch, and I'm sure they looked at your request and gleefully acted the opposite way for that reason.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. I am sure the other moderators will appreciate the compliment :)

Comment: Eric,

I didn't mean to insult the moderators. I listed possibility one of the trichotomy for completeness. I can see how my wording of possibiltiy two was bad. I'll make a feature request for the ability of a moderator to note that they looked at the flagged post, perhaps with a flag.

Comment: @Justin: I'm sure they didn't take it as an insult. I mean, TXI is a little sensitive, but don't worry about Diago, splattne, and HowToGeek. They'll be fine :)

Answer (score 2):

I would not consider the question a cross site duplicate. Questions can be asked on both sites and would most likely get different answers on different sites. As Jeff already mentioned there is no way to close a "cross-site duplicate". We also don't always feedback moderator tags since if there is no action required, there is no need to make others aware a post had been flagged.

If it is however a problem you can have the question deleted. Personally I think it belongs on SU since I have seen at least 4 similar questions already.

Answer (score 0):

btw; there's a "close > exact duplicate" feature for marking duplicate questions; flagging *may* work (depending on a number of factors), but isn't necessarily the primary aim of the "flag > Requires Moderator attention" button.