# Close as exact duplicate + belongs on 

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The ability to link cross site duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16703/the-ability-to-link-cross-site-duplicates)

Take a look to https://serverfault.com/questions/156639 and https://superuser.com/questions/142102

The first one is both a duplicate of the 2nd and also belongs to superuser.com

As [cross duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16703/the-ability-to-link-cross-site-duplicates) is not possible, we have to close it as belongs to... then when it's moved to the other site set it as duplicate.

There is 2 problems:

- This need 2 action
- In my case when it's on superuser I can't close it as duplicate because of my low reputation. So if the question is moved, may be it will never be set as duplicate

So it would be nice to close it (on serverfault) as a duplicate of superuser question, and as the duplicate is cross site the question would also be moved from SF to SU.

I agree that in some case duplicate can exist across site because answer will be different, but in this case the question is out of the scope of SF and has duplicate on SU, so beeing able to close as duplicate of SU would be nice.

Comment: You can flag a question on SU if you don't have the reputation to vote. Moderators are very active there. You can also write a simple comment explaining the duplicate, and 3k users will vote on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being I used my new super powers to take of this particular example.  Not sure if this happens enough that it is worth implementing as a feature instead of just flagging it for moderator attention and attaching a note to the flag.

Comment: Pff, not letting me the pleasure to vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: You're probably right, this might not append so much time but I see the case from time to time on SF.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, two action is the "correct" behaviour, because each site should be self-inclusive and self-monitored.

The fact that you are *aware* that it is a duplicate on SU, doesn't matter to most of the people on SF, because they are (and should be) primarily concerned with ServerFault. It is not reasonable to assume that most users of any StackExchange site would know the questions that have already been asked on another site, but they can recognize questions which don't belong.

This is akin to 'internal policing'. The question *belongs* on SuperUser, and then it is up to the SuperUser mods and community to decide if it is a duplicate.

As for actions. You should comment that it is a cross-site duplicate, nominate to close as "belongs on X" and flag for moderator attention to explain.

Comment: Since I wrote approximately the same thing, I'll just remove my answer.

Comment: Belongs on X and comment as duplicate is what I did