# Duplicate Close dialog misleading when given an off-site URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, cross-posting

I found a user had posted the same question question on both SU and SO.  I voted to close as a duplicate on SO, and pasted in the SU link.  It brought up the SO question with the same question number instead of the SU one.

[If we aren't going to enable cross-site duplicate closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55588/close-as-exact-duplicate-belongs-on) then *entering an off-site URL in that box should give an error, not present the wrong question.*

[image]

Comment: There are good reasons not to have cross-site dupes (e.g. if it's off-topic, close it as such; if not, maybe the asker wants a particular community's perspective), but good catch on the bug.

Comment: Some posts are on-topic on more than one site, but SE/SO discourages cross-posting.  They need to post it in the best site first.

Comment: Ah, for the specific case of cross-posts then yes, I was thinking too generally. I would just flag it as a cross-post rather than a dupe, personally.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good idea -- no reason to not block this in a saner way.

If what you pasted looks like an URL, we will now check to make sure it's an URL to the current site first, and if not, give you an explanation.