# Allow Cross Site duplicate closing for cross posted questions

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close as cross post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94322/close-as-cross-post)

Sometimes people will cross post on more than one Stack Exchange site.

How about enabling us to Close as Duplicate those extra posts.
Right now the only correct thing to do seems to be flagging for a moderator's attention.

Comment: @Jeff, yep, you're right.  I looked for it, but it didn't come up.

Comment: I just searched `cross post` and it was the first result.  ;)

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55588/close-as-exact-duplicate-belongs-on