# Are there conflicting answers about what to do with cross-site duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, migration

The two questions below appear (to me) to duplicate each other, and provide conflicting answers:

- [What is the proper way of dealing with a question that is a duplicate with a question on another SE site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106323/what-is-the-proper-way-of-dealing-with-a-question-that-is-a-duplicate-with-a-que) (This answer is older by a couple years, and much less popular.)
- [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates) (This answer is newer, more popular, seems to conflict with the first answer, and was never considered a duplicate.)

The conflict I perceive, which may or may not be correct, is that the first seems to say there is no such thing as cross-site duplicates, while the second suggests that there is... and that the way to deal with it is to first migrate the post and then mark it as duplicate (or leave them on both sites, if they are appropriate to both sites). This has left me confused.

Do these two questions duplicate each other, and conflict as it has appeared to me? If so, what is the proper way of dealing with that?

*(I did not want to go into either of two well-established questions and attempt to flag one as a duplicate. I didn't think that such a flag would be well-received.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is an exact duplicate and the answer is the same, it is a cross-site duplicate. What happens next is up to the community. Either one of them gets closed being off-topic or they can both stay and are possibly answered.

The first question talks how to flag those questions, where the answer is: you can't close as duplicate of a question on another site.

The second question points out in general what to do with those cross-site duplicate questions. They don't conflict, they just attribute another part of the process.