# Would it be a good idea to allow questions that apply to multiple stack sites to be linked?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

### Idea

Here is a possibly new idea. Why not let a question that could belong to multiple sites be added and shared to all of these sites. It wouldn't take much effort to allow such an action. It would be created on one site and then the other sites it applies to could have a pointer to that question but display it as if it is part of that site.

This could fix duplicate questions and would allow merging of questions to become simpler.

### Problems

A few problems do exist in this format but might be solvable:

- The asker's points (Go to where it was asked? Or where it was answered?)
- The answerer's points (Same as above)
- Tagging (Shared tags or limited to the origin site? But if limited then what do the shared sites show.)
- Users (profiles) will need to be created on all of the sites that the question is linked to.

### Good idea?

If not then why and what would you suggest?

Comment: "`It wouldn't take much effort to allow such an action`" - what is this statement based on?

Comment: I usually make web applications and I think adding a shared pointer functionality would be very simple. Wouldn't require changing old functions, just appending some conditions for how to handle a question "pointer".

The problems might make this not true. (Unsure how difficult it would be to fix these issues.)

Comment: I'm just saying that it's quite an assumption to make without having seen/worked on the codebase. In my experience, having someone out side of the team who isn't familiar with the codebase give effort estimations is a bad idea.

Comment: @Lix 6-8 weeks would be fairly accurate...

Comment: This is never going to happen and would be difficult to police (how do you stop people posting on all the sites every time), but I quite like the idea.

Comment: I think this has been proposed before and was quite well received. Can't find the link anymore though.

Comment: Fair enough that I haven't seen your code. But I still feel it is a fairly simple solution to implement. A well coded program should be extensible, and 6-8 weeks doesn't sound terrible. However, as mentioned before, I am not a coder for stack sites so I wouldn't really know. It is still good to discus ways to improve and change an idea to make it worth while.

Comment: Be aware 6-8 weeks is a joke for "will never happen". Im not sure why

Comment: Well if it will never happen, that's fine too. It's not my place to make them implement it and I was only offering an idea. I thought it was pretty good but if the developers don't like it then I guess it won't happen.

Comment: @RichardTingle it doesn't necessary mean never, but it was always Jeff's estimate and was never accurate.  [Many Meme's of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/182513)

Comment: I am amused that this site has memes. Guess I should expect that of every internet community. Thanks for the insight and link @psubsee2003.

Comment: Related to [The ability to link cross site duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16703).

Comment: Different sites have different policies, tags, markup features etc. I'd like to weaken site separation, but it isn't as easy as you think