# When MSE splits from MSO, what content will be quickly migrated back to MSO?

Tags: support, migration, mso-mse-split

It's my understanding that when Stack Exchange [splits meta.stackexchange.com off to its own site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own), and brings meta.stackoverflow.com back up as a standard child meta, there are no plans for immediate mass migration of questions.

I have some unresolved discussions, bugs and feature requests that are very specific to Stack Overflow, I think they should be moved back to MSO quickly. What can I do?

Also, if I have a question about the split in general, is there a tag I should use?

Comment: I believe meta.stackoverflow.com only needs [one post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem). Then you can turn off the "Ask Question" page and you'll be done.

Comment: @AdamDavis I think SE team would be happy to move [67 more posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vote-to-close+stackoverflow+review "about The Queue") there, especially if  the "Ask Question" page gets turned off

Comment: Good grief we're taking _Iceland_ with us, what more do you people _want_?

Answer (score 21):

We're now in the process of identifying questions that are:

- Recent (in the past three months)
- Unresolved (there's obviously a discussion still happening)
- Very Stack Overflow specific (retag, tag burnination, cleanup, etc)

We will be keeping a list of these, and migrating them back to MSO very soon after everything stabilizes. Note, this is going to be a *very* conservative list, we expect it to be between 50 and 100 questions in all.

After the split, if you think that we've missed something, flag it on MSE and let us know that you think it needs to be shipped back over to MSO. However, ***please do not flag just for the sake of bucketing or sorting content*** - unless it's very recent and seemingly unresolved, we'll probably decline.

A major requirement is to make sure that people keep as much of their rep on MSE as possible, so we're not inclined to pull questions about Stack Overflow that *also* relate to the network as whole. However, some of you might lose 50 - 100 rep from *very* recent questions or answers, unfortunately there's not much that we can do.

Beyond the very *recent* and unresolved questions, it's up to Stack Overflow to talk about the stuff that they want to talk about on their meta site - so the announcement is accurate, we're not going to be sending a lot of content back.

If you have additional questions about the split, use the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag, along with the [mso-mse-split](/questions/tagged/mso-mse-split) tag. Please make sure to include the latter, as questions about this project will be quickly obsolete once it's completed and any remaining issues settled - at which point they'll be going away.

If you want to leave answers to this question with links to posts you feel should be shipped immediately after the split, please feel free to do so, just try to avoid duplication.

Comment: Hopefully losing Meta rep makes people cry less than losing SO rep when questions about which xkcd is funniest are supposed to be deleted (but kept in stasis instead)

Comment: What will end up happening with new questions on MSO that are *clear* duplicates of not-very-recent, resolved questions on MSE that don't get migrated? Judging from the answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/212780) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16703/212780), I assume we should let them live on both sites (giving new answers to them on MSO), but I'd like to be clear.

Comment: @Geobits: I expect the same thing that's generally done on per-site metas when a question is asked: Answer the question and provide a link back to Mother Meta, perhaps quoting the accepted answer in the process.

Comment: @AlE. Thanks, that makes sense. I don't spend much time on per-site metas since I'm mainly active on SO, so I didn't know that was the standard there.

Comment: @Geobits: I wouldn't call it a "standard", but it's pretty common.

Comment: *"Hopefully losing Meta rep"* That's what they get for posting useful questions to Meta about Stack Overflow rather than the generic "always iceland in friday" questions users like me post. ;-D

Comment: @TravisJ Really?  I thought meta votes on other sites didn't result in rep changes.  When did that change?

Comment: @TimPost : Just a question : instead of identifying specific cases on thousand of questions, why not describe them and let users migrate their own questions *(perhaps with some controls mechanisms like creating a temporary dedicated review queue)*?

Comment: @user2284570 Folks can (and have occasionally been) asking for certain questions they've asked to be sent back over. If it's still relevant there's a good chance we'll do it (provided that we're not going to cause someone to lose privileges by doing so)

Comment: @TimPost Sorry, I can't translate *`they've asked to be sent back over`* at all.

Comment: @user2284570, Tim is saying (and I'm not sure that's proper English, no offence Tim) is that people can ask for their questions to move back to MSO.