# What happens to our contributions, hence rep after the MSO/MSE split?

Tags: discussion, meta, mso-mse-split

What happens to our questions and answers (and rep) when the MSO/MSE split occurs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MSO will become MSE - essentially a regular site, albeit a Meta one, with its own reputation and users.

This will be done mostly as a rename of MSO - so people on MSO will retain their reputation, but it will belong to MSE.

The questions and answers will remain as "belonging" to whoever they "belong" to now.

The new MSO will become a regular child-meta site, governed by the same rules of other meta sites across the network - that is, it will not have reputation of its own, but will inherit the reputation from its parent site - in this case, Stack Overflow.

Comment: Will there be migrations of posts from the MSE to MSO at all?

Comment: Will questions tagged [stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) be migrated to MSO?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215677/when-mse-splits-from-mso-what-content-will-be-quickly-migrated-back-to-mso, @hims056

Comment: That explains my concern @Mat.

Comment: @Helios - yes, some questions will get migrated. I don't have a definitive list.

Comment: @hims056 - not to begin with, I believe. Though the CMs can migrate specific ones later on.