# Is it Ok to ask for a clarification for a comment?

Tags: support, comments, english, translations

Sometimes, I see comments on [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com) which I definitely can't understand or translate.
In that case, I write something like that :

> @userxxxxx Sorry, I can't translate "*`incomprehensible sentence example`"* at all.

Usually, you do this for the question, or the answer.
Most of the time, I didn't write any answers nor the question.

That kind of comment is very chatty, because it reply to an another comment without bringing anything useful for the question *(since others peoples seems to understand the comment)*.
In the same time, I can't understand the comment which prevent me from really understand the answer.

So, shall I continue to write that kind of comments? If not, what shall I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the meta, it's probably not as big a deal because understanding a comment is not terribly important (posts have all the weight, comments are more side conversations).

On main sites like Stack Overflow, it would be a good idea to ask for clarification, normally because the OP adds details about the problem in the comments instead of editing the post (and god I hate when they do). So in that case understanding the comment lets you better understand the question.

Comment: I was especially thinking to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215678/242800) with my question.

Comment: @user2284570 So in your example, Tim is the author of the post (answer), and it seems that understanding the comment would help give you more information. I might not say it in those words, maybe "I don't understand what you just said..." followed by your best guess at what you think it means.

Comment: Yes, and I don't understand it due to my English level. I have no idea for my example.

Comment: @user2284570, that's fine (it's one of those strange idioms English has). If you ask for clarification, the author or someone else has a good chance of getting back to you.