# How do I report a duplicate question when I cannot cast close votes?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Is there a way to *report* that a question is a duplicate of another one?
Some users are able to cast a close vote, but what can users who see a duplicate question but cannot vote to close it do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates)

Comment: This question is not about cross-site duplicates. It's about users who cannot cast close votes, but noticed a question is a duplicate. Since casting a close vote is only possible when both the questions are in the same site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays*, the best option is to [flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) the question as a duplicate. You only need 15 reputation for this. This flag will leave a comment (even if you do not have the reputation to comment everywhere, which on most sites comes with 50 reputation), just like a normal duplicate close vote would, **and** push the question into the Close Votes review queue.

Just leaving a comment like ire_and_curses' answer says won't put it into the review queue; Jeff's answer might, depending on the site, get you a declined flag because "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"; duplicates can be handled by the community.

*<sub>: this was not an option at the time this question and the other answers were written.</sub>

Comment: When the question was asked, flagging a question as duplicate had only the effect of adding a flag to the moderator's queue; no comment was automatically added, and the question was not pushed to the review queue.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno. I probably already used Stack Overflow back then but as 'just another repository for information', without an account.

Answer (score 13):

The standard practice is to leave a comment, like this:

```
duplicate:link/to/dupe
```

Users with voting powers can then look at your proposed duplicate, and vote to close if they agree (or argue the case if they disagree). It seems to work pretty well.

Comment: is path the question URL or somethin else (just the part after sitename)?

Comment: @DDS You could also use /q/33408, which is the relative URL for this very question, but a complete link would be much more helpful, since users can directly click it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also flag for moderator attention, it's helpful to include the URL to what you think the dupe is in the mod flag comment.

Comment: That was the other question I thought to ask (when a question should be marked as requiring attention).

Comment: True enough, but in general, I tend to avoid this because 1) Mods are busy, and votes do the same job quite efficiently, and 2) I think the more democratic system should be preferred. Calling a mod is effectively privilege escalation. Arguing the case is often valuable. IMO, the site should be community driven wherever possible.