# Can I post the same question to both StackOverflow and ServerFault?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates)

Sometimes I am confused by which audience is best to ask the question for. For example, I'm currently having a series of questions regarding Tomcat, and my assumption was to post them to ServerFault. However, I don't get many views there, and when I check the tomcat tag on StackOverflow, I see a number of questions there for what appear to be admin related.(and getting answered.)

So, for the situation like this, is it better to post the same question to 2 sites. Or is there anyway to link the question across 2 site?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates). Similar, but from an answerers/moderators view point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-posting (posting on two sites at once) is discouraged.

It's very rare that a question would belong on *both* sites. If you have one of those rare edge cases, it's okay to ask here (in Meta) where you question belongs.

But, in general, I would pick one site over the other and try it there first. If you don't get the reply you need, ask in the comments of the question if the users feel it would better be posted to the other site. That way you can manage on which site the question remains.

Comment: I see, our audience can move the thread. I will follow that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it depends on what the nature of your question about tomcat is...Relating to an example I have more of an understanding of is that questions relating to managing an asp.net server or setup of IIS etc may well be better answered by serverfault sys admin type people who manage web servers and asp.net programming, theory or whatever is clearly a stackoverflow question

But if you're getting no views, I'd be trying stackoverflow

Answer (score -1):

I'd say "yes" but include in both questions links to the other so that you are transparent that it is in both places. And link your preferred answer in the same way.