# Questions that cross over between SO and SF?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, serverfault

I have a somewhat obscure question about the impact of a specific connection string property on SQL server and its effect on the application:
[JDBC connection to very busy SQL 2000: selectMethod=cursor vs selectMethod=direct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622500/is-using-api-server-cursors-an-application-transparent-option)

I posted it on SO, but haven't yet gotten any answers. There is some crossover to ServerFault

[This meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates) seems to imply that its occasionally OK to post the same question to more than one site. Just wanted to confirm, can I do that without risking the wrath of the CloseHammer?

Answer (score 3):

Just go ahead and ask.
There is no shame in having a question closed.

Answer (score 1):

Explain yourself just as you did here and within the question itself (short, link to SO question) and emphasize on the SF part of the question.

There is no guarantee not to risk "the wrath of the CloseHammer", as you call it. (I never found myself thinking of it that way, maybe because I am a pastor and talk about the wrath of God sometimes - no comparison in effects). Yet being upfront with your concern should prevent downvotes at least.