# Add a warning about cross-site duplicates

Tags: feature-request, questions, duplicate-questions, cross-posting

In case a user asks the same question on two different SE, it would be great to automatically warn the readers that the question has been cross-posted and give a link to the cross-posts.

The motivation is twofold: making cross-posting abuses easier to detect and avoiding answering a question that has been answered on a different SE.

Comment: Note also all of the linked questions to that post, including [Check if a user has an identical open question on another site before allowing them to post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193425/).

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6795/perform-automatic-checks-for-cross-posting-and-question-ban-at-so-when-post-ente