# How to avoid cross-posting but still get a good answer?

Tags: discussion, support, cross-posting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-posting on StackExchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65931/cross-posting-on-stackexchange-sites)

So, yesterday I asked this question on Stackoverflow: [Why did creating this new index improve performance so much when existing index included all columns in new index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565461/why-did-creating-this-new-index-improve-performance-so-much-when-existing-index?noredirect=1) which was answered very fast and then promptly migrated to DBAs (which I just learned existed, due to my question being migrated): [Why did creating this new index improve performance so much when existing index included all columns in new index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9406/why-did-creating-this-new-index-improve-performance-so-much-when-existing-index)

Today, due to the migration yesterday, asked this question on DBAs: [Will Entity Framework and/or Linq-To-SQL queries show up as "Adhoc Queries" in SSMS' "Server Dashboard" Report?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9481/will-entity-framework-and-or-linq-to-sql-queries-show-up-as-adhoc-queries-in-s)

These are quite different questions, but I get the feeling that if I had posted on Stackoverflow I would have gotten some type of response by now, but since I posted directly to DBAs I've only had a hand full of views.

The selfish bit of me would like to double post, but I realize that introduces its own issues; so how should I post my question to the correct place but still get the answer I need, even when that community is much smaller, if more focused on the topic of my question?

Comment: I think [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65931/cross-posting-on-stackexchange-sites) covers it pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be some sites where there is some cross over, especially as StackOverflow (and programming in general) is such a broad site. There are some migration options set up for some of the sister sites to be used when a question fits better there than on SO, but DBAs.SE is not one of them (I don't know if mods have this option or not).

If you are sure that your question fits **equally** in either site, then post the same question on both sites, but at least provide a footnote and link on each question to point to the other, with a brief explanation of the cross post. Nobody likes it when cross posting is done willy nilly, but there is nothing wrong with it if done in a controlled and disciplined way. If you receive an answer on one site then you should also update the question in the other site (if the answerer doesn't want to do it).

Do keep it in mind though that there will be few questions that fit equally across two sites, normally one is a better fit than others.

Comment: That is my point exactly, while I admit that DBAs is a better fit for my question, the community is much smaller than at StackOverflow and thus less likely to be answered.

Comment: I agree, that one expert you need for your answer isn't necessarily on DBAs. If in doubt you could always try DBAs first, then SO after a reasonable period of time.