# Deny cross-posting, but enable site-sharing?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-crossover, cross-posting

I know cross-posting (writing the same question on more than one SE site) is discouraged and should not be done. I also see the reason for this and agree, but sometimes it is indeed not clear where a question should belong best or it would be useful on several sites, as every site usually has its special kind of experts and for some issues more than one kind would be good.

So what I would like to propose and discuss its advantages and disadvantages with you is that SE could implement a "site-sharing" feature for questions. You write the question on one site, but you have the option (starting with a reputation score of e.g. 200 or 500) to tick some checkboxes, so that it will also appear on the main/question sites of other SE sites. It should not create a clone question but instead link to the original post or create a reference that looks like it was created on the site you visit it, but is synchronized with the main post. Important is, that all shared questions are always at the same state on all sites.

You think this can be implemented by the SE team? What problems or further improvements do you see? Please express your opinion not only (but also) with votes, but rather write constructive comments and answers. Thanks!

Comment: What questions would work on more than one site? Why would you want answers from more than one site?

Comment: A question may have a topic that is covered by multiple sites or contains parts that would belong to different sites. E.g. a question that has to do with both Windows and Ubuntu would fit both on [SU] and [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se]. A question about an electronic part like a diode may fit on both [physics.se] and [electronics.se], about batteries it would also fit on [chemistry.se]. We have many sites that have similar topics or are a specialized subsite of another (like all questions on [ubuntu.se] are on-topic at [unix.se] and those of both sites also fit [SU]).

Comment: @RobertLongson The people on [unix.se] would give a different option to those on [ubuntu.se]

Comment: Link to [original question on meta.askubuntu.com](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14223/367990), link to [another related question on meta.askubuntu.com](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1480/367990)

Comment: Similar proposal (positive vote score!): http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65932/280883

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: Well on paper this would seem like a good idea, but practically, it's very hard to implement. "What sites will appear on those check boxes?" would become the next million-dollar question and deciding it will be as hard as deciding if a migration path is good or not.

Comment: I've always seen cross posting as not enough effort put into narrowing the question.  If it can fit onto more than one site, then think about it some more; what's the issue?  Where does it lie?  Continue narrowing until it's only valid on a single site.

Comment: Heh, the only usage that I can see is to "share" post about SE mobile app bug posted on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to [meta.se]. Other than that, I don't see the need in everyday case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a really interesting idea, and in some respects could be useful, but I see a few problems which (currently, for me) stop it being worthwhile, or even useful.

---

I'm not sure what benefits there are, as you're only argument seems to be:

> A question may have a topic that is covered by multiple sites

This is *very rare*, and even then a question which could arguably be on 2 sites nearly always has a specific *scope* which would be more suitable for one site or another. e.g. One site has more traffic/activity for your tag(s) than the other.

> or contains parts that would belong to different sites.

This is a null argument, as then it's simply 2 questions on 2 different sites.

These arguments do not give much hope for your idea as sites have tight niches and questions are *nearly always* suitable for 1 site only.

### Misuse

People will (or at least *could*) use this incorrectly:

1. By mistake, as it's not clear which sites have an acceptable
   *overlap*
2. On purpose, as they don't care about the sites and just want their
   answer
3. Because we said they could and it is a *juicy* feature to gain a
   wider audience

It's hard to have stats or figures to identify how much of a problem the above will be. However based on experience I *strongly suspect* that when you (essentially) state something like:

> Use this tickbox to have your question on X and Y site also

Then people **will** use it - whether it's appropriate or not.
And that would mean "clean up" and moderation (somehow), and given the fact the usage of this would be *rare*, the problems caused even by needing to clean up grossly outweigh the *occasional* and *weak* benefit gained.

---

### Other problems

**Not very useful**:
All sites are pretty tight in what is *on-topic*. There is some overlap in some sites, but not enough to be an actual *problem* and not enough to warrant your request.

**A question needs to be functional on that site**:
If there is no actual question on the site with the shared link, then what is the point if people on siteX (shared link) cannot answer on that site and have to go to another site altogether to answer/comment/vote/flag/etc?

**Moderating problems**:
While we don't have to figure out the technical aspects to feature requests, "*off-topic* shared links" is something which would be a major issue worth mentioning:

> It should not create a clone question but instead link to the original
>   post

So on the site where the shared link is, do people have to go to *another site* to flag it being off topic on the site they *were* on?
This could be resolved, but then you introduce more functionality and technical aspects, and again for so little gain.

**Which sites?**:
It's *impossible* to identify which other sites a question *could* be suitable for, so we'd have to allow the ability to push to *all* other sites.

This is bad because people don't know what other sites they *should* push to, especially as it will be rare when they can do this correctly. This is why the sites limit migration to very few scenarios.

Do we allow them to post on all sites at once? Or limit them to "X other sites"? The latter is not ideal because we do not know what their question is so we could be allowing them to post to *too many* other sites, or not enough.

**Spam**:
Imagine how easy we'd make it for nuisance and spammy users to post their crap to various sites in one go. Sure this can happen with other means, but when the proposed feature will be very rarely useful, potential problems can easily outweigh the benefits.

Comment: Of course this feature would need a reasonable reputation minimum like e.g. 500 which would prevent spam and reduce wrong usage.

Comment: You think users with 500 rep do not make mistakes? Rep does not equal common sense, or site knowledge, or a care for others, or even knowing which sites their question would be ok being "shared" on. Even users with well over 1k rep can be lazy or not care about the sites and so would incorrectly push to other sites just to get more answers. Rep does not solve the problems

Comment: Additionally, I'm not against your idea in principle, I just think the basic idea doesn't work. If you can think of a way to avoid issues (mostly people using it incorrectly) then I might be behind it :)

Comment: @ByteCommander You're going to demand 500 rep on all sites that the post is simulataneously displayed on?

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't demand, I propose to demand... But that's a good question. Probably the best thing would be to use network-wide reputation instead (all points of sites with >200 rep summed up) and require at least 1k or 2k of that. Or don't make it as tick boxes that show up while writing the question but rather implement it as moderator/review flag?

Comment: I think that this is a great idea, for instance I keep on needing to ask a security question that involves law stuff as well, so being able to ask it on [law.se] and [security.se] would be great! Well, not ask, but have it on one site, and then a link on the other. And you could even only have this ability given to mods so that users would have to flag stuff up, like is done for migration, this is just a different sort of migration. I think it's worth another look at.