# Cross-site question association

Tags: feature-request, site-crossover, cross-pollination

We have already working association mechanism between Stack Oveflow in Russian and Stack Overlow in English.

Something like this

<sub>Text translation: This question has answers on StackOverflow in Russian.
 [Link to associated question].</sub>

[image]

[More about this](https://stackapps.com/questions/7208/stack-overflow-association-tools).

**My suggestion**:
I suggest to extend the same mechanism to all Stack Exchange sites.

If very similar (nearly the same) questions were asked on different Stack Exchange sites (that have some topic intersection) we can show link under associated questions `This question has answers on [StackExchange site of associated question]. [Link to associated question].`.

This will increase visiting of other Stack Exchange sites and knowledge transfer.

### UPDATE

Nice examples of questions are also listed in [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/346987). BTW my suggestion is duplicated in [one of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297074/346987).

Comment: Wouldn't usually the question be off-topic on the site it was asked? What benefit does this have besides encouraging bad behavior?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Not always. Questions about bash shells scripts are on topic on a least 4 different sites ...

Comment: Not sure how useful it would be to the english speaking crowd. As a third party app, it makes a ton of sense, but russian/portugese/japanese -> english makes sense more than vice versa.

Comment: @PatrickHofman no, there are many sites which are overlapping with other sites.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek We have many English sites which have a lot of overlapping topics. And when we have very similar questions on different site we facilitate knowledge transfer and popularity of other sites.

Comment: I kind of like this, actually, as a compromise between the current system and the oft-requested cross-site dupe ability.

Comment: @PatrickHofman There's *tons* of overlap, you see cross-site stuff all the time that's appropriate in many places.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek If you need examples here is [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264510/deny-cross-posting-but-enable-site-sharing#comment860736_264510). Besides this I can remember enSO and dba, enSO and GameDev and so on.

Comment: An even subtler alternative to this could be some sort of "related questions on other sites" sidebar list, perhaps with an automatic algorithm.

Comment: @JasonC Theoretically related questions can be made cross-site and associated question functionality would be for cross-site duplicates.

Comment: speaking of overlap @PatrickHofman [official position](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/current-state-of-the-job-market#comment19869_6950 "source here") known to me was as follows: "getting rid of the overlap is probably the wrong direction to be going... The topics overlap; accept it and mark the natural boundaries."

Comment: I'd actually prefer the ability to close as dupe of a question on another site. That would be much more helpful.

Comment: @RoryAlsop It's sometimes legal to have the same questions on multiple sites. And if a question will be closed as duplicate it might be unclear what site is more appropriate. But if we won't close them and show associations users will benefit from both communities.

Comment: I just asked a question on Arqade.SE about baseball video game emulation, which I think is quite relevant to Sports.SE, so I could see this being used for that.  I had a similar question on Movies.SE that someone else appropriately x-posted to Arqade.SE as it had to do with games and the film Pixels; it also could have benefited from this.

Comment: It's always legal, but that doesn't stop being able to close as dupe on another site being useful.