# How can I "ping" other communities / Stack Exchange sites without cross-posting the question?

Tags: discussion, chat, cross-posting, site-crossover

I found that an interesting and important question that someone asked on one SE site is likely to benefit from answers coming from users who frequent other SE sites. **What are the best ways to attract attention to this question from the users of other Stack Exchange sites?**

Suggesting that the author cross-post the question is one possibility (but not the best one, in my opinion). Is there a way to "ping" a few selected communities? I am looking for something less intrusive than cross-posting.

Note that I am not the OP of the question. I merely provided one possible answer to the question. Even though it was upvoted and accepted, I think the OP would benefit from other answers.

---

My question above is general. But for the curious, the post I refer to is on Parenting.SE:
*[Supporting kid in innovation](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/40662/supporting-kid-in-innovation)*

I think that it may benefit from answers by users in the "makers" communities (there are a few of those on SE).

**SEE ALSO:**

**The pros and cons of cross-posting:**

[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/578690)
[Cross-posting on StackExchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65931/578690)
[Is cross-posted forbidden/discouraged on Stack Exchange sites? If so, why?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9337)
[Is cross-posting wrong (to an external site)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141823/578690)

Comment: I can only imagine Chat.

Comment: There is nothing really wrong with cross-posting as long as you do it sequentially, stop as soon as you have an answer and link all the cross-posts with each other, I'd say.

Comment: @Trilarion And focus each post on the specific site. 1:1 cross-posts usually don't go over well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Post the question link (share):

[image]

in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=meta.stackexchange.com), or the selected site's chat room(s).  Also, it's usually useful to leave a short note on why you're doing this, and why you hope someone will answer your question - dropping in random links will get you nowhere.

Comment: "dropping in random links will get you nowhere" If you do it often enough, it will get you kick-muted from the room.

Comment: @Mast Had no idea.  Then, I've never been there ;)  No wish to either.

Comment: As a room-owner, I've been tempted once or twice. But it's usually not necessary :-)