# Simultaneous cross-posting - should it be discouraged?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to post questions across a couple of the sites because it's debatable which site it fits best?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata)

I came up upon - and answered - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4711465/507519) question, which its asker cross-posted to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/234185/55602) and [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/223267/60384) at virtually the same time.

I will admit that this question does seem to be a bit in the gray area between StackOverflow (bash programming) and SuperUser (shell tricks) - though it seems at least slightly off-topic for ServerFault.

In any case, this question collected a number of answers on all sites.

- Should I cross-post my own answer? Is there a policy on the issue of answers to cross-posted questions?
- Is there a way to merge those answers, so that they are all in the same place? Right now I can only think of adding comments with links in each one...
- Should habitual simultaneous cross-posters be penalized by e.g. downvoting?

Comment: It's already discouraged; Jeff's answer on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata) covers it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SO version has been closed.

There are cases where a question might well be on (or at least nearly on) topic on more than one site and this might well be one of them. However, simultaneous cross posting should be discouraged. You should post on one site as this allows for off topic questions to be migrated if necessary without creating duplicates on the target site.

If you don't get an answer on Server Fault (say) then I can't see why posting on Super User (as in this case) or Web Masters (if it's a web admin type question) shouldn't be allowed, but migration should be the preferred option.

In those cases where it's not migrated it might be worth referring to the original question to stop the question being migrated (but not being closed as off topic).