# What about stackexchange crossposting?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to post questions across a couple of the sites because it's debatable which site it fits best?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata)

A user brought up this crosspost:

[Where can I shrink database directly from Central admin (SharePoint2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723925/where-can-i-shrink-database-directly-from-central-admin-sharepoint2010)

and

[Where can I shrink database directly from Central admin (SharePoint2010)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/where-can-i-shrink-database-directly-from-central-admin-sharepoint2010/8651)

Is there an official word on whether this is OK or not?  I'm on the side of eh.

Comment: Searched for crosspost and didn't hit, Oh, well.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too.