# link questions between sites

Tags: feature-request

[What can I do to decrease load times of HTML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005827/what-can-i-do-to-decrease-load-times-of-html-pages)

This question would be well-suited to both SO and Webmasters. (Maybe better suited just to Webmasters, but there is enough traffic about reducing HTML load latency on SO that I would like an excellent question / answer here that can help stave off duplicates. :)

I think it'd be super if there was some way to symlink / hardlink this question and answer between the two sites: it would bring a larger audience to bear on editing it, and it would have only a single copy to maintain for those who would like it to be in sync on both.

So: is there any mechanism for symlinking / hardlinking / linking questions on multiple SE sites? If not, is there enough reason to *build* one?

Thanks!

Comment: There's already the linking system for interlinked questions.  I had always wondered if it could be retrofitted to allow cross-site linking.

Comment: See also: **[Please add support for “crossover questions” between StackExchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually best for each SE site to be very specific in terms of what is on-topic and what is off-topic. If a question would fit one site better than it would another, then it belongs on the better site.

So far all of the answers to the question that I see are things that a software developer or Web developer would normally be asked to handle. A Webmaster may be interested in them, but so may senior managers, or sales managers, or the customer service department.

As an engineer, I've had to perform many of those same steps with the Web applications I've built. Therefore, this question would not belong on Webmasters.

In addition, the [Webmasters FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) makes it clear that questions that would be of interest to programmers or system administrators belong on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

> If your question would be of interest to …
>
> **Professional and enthusiast programmers**, ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).
> **System administrators and desktop support professionals**, ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Thus, by the very definition of this question being of interest to programmers, it belongs on Stack Overflow and would be considered off-topic on Webmasters SE.

You also may find Jeff's answer to my very similar question helpful, which is about linking related sites together:  [Is it Possible to Create Multiple Stack Exchange Sites that Share Some Questions and Answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79222/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-that-share-some-questions)

Comment: Excellent question, and indeed, Jeff's answer was _also_ excellent. :) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but programming bleeds into servers, which bleeds into networking, which bleeds into cabling, which bleeds into physics, which bleeds into philosophy, which bleeds into religion, which bleeds into...  Lots of overlap there.