# Asking questions relevant to multiple sites?

Tags: feature-request, cross-posting, site-crossover

Many questions are relevant to multiple SE sites, e.g.,:

- [Can a bash script tell if it's being run via cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214935/can-a-bash-script-tell-if-its-being-run-via-cron)
- [Check if script is started by cron, rather than invoked manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46789/check-if-script-is-started-by-cron-rather-than-invoked-manually)
- [How can I tell a script is running under cron?](https://serverfault.com/questions/658015/how-can-i-tell-a-script-is-running-under-cron)
- [with a shell script, it is possible to tell when it's run with cron vs run manually?](https://superuser.com/questions/172142/with-a-shell-script-it-is-possible-to-tell-when-its-run-with-cron-vs-run-manua)

It would be nice if it were possible to have *one* question instead of *four* above, or at least a way to link them together "officially".

One possible approach would be to allow marking questions as duplicates of questions.

A more ambitious proposal is [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with "crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/215439) (and many others).

My actual questions are

- What is the *current* "best practices" for cross-over questions?
- What is the *future* roadmap - planned changes &c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the current "best practices" for cross-over questions?

You can ask the same question on multiple sites, but start with just the one you expect to be the best fit. If you don't receive an answer there, go to the other site and rewrite your question to fit the other site for the full 100 percent (so don't just copy-paste)

> What is the future roadmap - planned changes &c?

Only SE can say anything on that, but the general sentiment there have been: not too much interested.