# What would be the appropriate community to ask questions about prompt engineering? (Like for GPT-3 or Stable Diffusion.)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What would be the appropriate community to ask questions in relation to engineering/ designing/ writing [a prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prompt_engineering) for [deep learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) models, such as [DALL-E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DALL-E), [GPT-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-3) or [Stable Diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_Diffusion)?

These prompts, especially when automated with APIs and accessed from programming languages, can often become quasi-programming in themselves; for instance, the prompt may include JSON, and the output may include actual parsable code, etc. At other times, these prompts are just natural language, with no trace of programming.

Comment: I don't think there's one site for any possible question. If it is programming then Stack Overflow, if not then maybe cross-validated or ai depending on what exactly the question is. If you have a specific question you want to ask we could likely help a bit more.

Comment: AI is a great suggestion, thanks. As far as questions go, here are two examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74055222/good-way-to-create-list-of-many-different-items-e-g-personas-in-gpt-3), [2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/237102/what-are-ways-to-build-a-world-using-gpt-3).

Comment: *"[prompt engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prompt_engineering)"* - *"... is a concept in artificial intelligence, particularly natural language processing (NLP) ... description of the task is embedded in the input, e.g., as a question instead of it being implicitly given."*

Comment: *"[Prompt-based learning](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/34832/prompt-based-learning) is a strategy that [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) engineers can use to train large [language models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model#Notable_language_models) (LLMs) so the same model can be used for different tasks without re-training."*

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Wow. That Wikipedia article still says "implicitly" instead of "explicitly".

Comment: Related: [Starting the Prompt Design Site: A New Home in our Stack Exchange Neighborhood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390463/241919)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 SE sites on AI:

- http://stats.stackexchange.com/
- http://datascience.stackexchange.com/
- https://ai.stackexchange.com/

one on NLP: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

and Stack Overflow if purely about coding.

We really need [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with "crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/178179).

Comment: Note though that questions which are about programming without statistical content tend to get closed on the stats site.

Answer (score 1):

Some questions about prompt engineering might be asked on [GenAI Stack Exchange](https://genai.stackexchange.com). This site was launched in July 2023. As of August 13, 2023, the site name and scope are still being discussed in their respective [child meta](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com).

---

Based on the keywords found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prompt_engineering, below are some of the related tags by site

**Artificial Intelligence**

[deep-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning), [gpt-3](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpt-3), [machine-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning),  [reinforcement-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinforcement-learning), [chatgpt](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt), [fine-tunning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fine-tunning), [prompt](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prompt)

- [Are "prompt engineering" and "prompt design" used as synonymous?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/39168/42632)

**Computer Sciences**

[artificial-intelligence](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence), [machine-learning](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), [learning-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-theory), [natural-language-processing](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language-processing)

**Computer Sciences Educators**

[artificial-intelligence](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence), [machine-learning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), [deep-learning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning), [reinforcement-learning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinforcement-learning)

**Cross-Validated**

[artificial-intelligence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence), [machine-learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), [natural-language](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language)

**Data Science**

[machine-learning](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), [nlp](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp), [openai-gpt](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openai-gpt)

**Stack Overflow**

[artificial-intelligence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence), [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning), [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp), [reinforment-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reinforment-learning), [gpt-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpt-2), [gpt-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpt-3), [stable-diffusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stable-diffusion) , [openai-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openai-api)

- [Does this ChatGPT "swap" snippet do anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75415943/1595451)

*From Meta Stack Overflow*

- [What tags might help me find questions about "prompt engineering"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423459/1595451)

**Web Applications**

- [chatgpt](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/chatgpt)

## Prompt Design / ( Generation AI? ) site

- [Starting the Prompt Design Site: A New Home in our Stack Exchange Neighborhood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390463/289691)

## Related

- [Is there a list of ChatGPT or other AI-related discussions and policies for our sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384922/289691)
- [Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396/289691) ([status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined))
- [Where to ask / migrate questions about ChatGPT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384797/289691)