# Ban ChatGPT network-wide

Tags: discussion, status-declined, answers, policy, chatgpt

Use of ChatGPT generated text for posts on Stack Overflow [is temporarily banned.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/5306507)
However, the reasons for the ban really apply to much or all of the network, and certainly for sites that are similar in nature to Stack Overflow.

**I suggest (temporarily) banning ChatGPT network-wide.**

Comment: So far, if someone copies text generated by ChatGPT without attribution, it's at the very least plagiarism, so you could argue most of it is already banned. When attribution is given though, that becomes a bit harder, but probably just a case of up/downvoting as appropriately (or deleting if it doesn't answer the actual question because someone only pasted e.g. the title)?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell the problem is when it _looks_ like an answer, smells like an answer, _could_ be an answer, but is actually completely incorrect... And then that user dumps a load of those AI-generated non-answers on a load of questions... That's in a very tiny nutshell why the decision was made on SO to just ban it.

Comment: @Cerbrus How to 'ban' users from actually posting ChatGPT stuff in the first place? I understand SO made a featured post about it to get it some attention, maybe stop the ones that were considering doing this from actually doing it... but unless SE/SO can come up with a way to determine that the text on someone's clipboard comes from ChatGPT... it can't prevent any user from pasting and posting it. Posting without attribution is already plagiarism, and when attribution is given it should probably end up under extra scrutiny and have no 'return on investment'.

Comment: Technically? Impossible. But as is often the case, there are systematic offenders that are relatively easy to recognize (manually)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell "ban", not "block". It's a preventive measure, and give mods the stamp to suspend if someone is found "guilty".

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I'm still left wondering why I would need that 'extra power'. I can already suspend users, either for plagiarism or continuous low-quality contributions, regardless of whether those come from ChatGPT or their own skulls. Policies are nice, but I think in this case, it would be a way too specific (limited to ChatGPT, what about other AI generated nonsense?) addition to something that to me seems quite clearly already covered by existing tools I have at my disposal?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell it's not that you don't have the power, it's that if 2000 users posted an answer every 3 minutes just after you went to bed you'd have a lot of clean up to do. We'd like to avoid that in the first place, ideally by making as many people as possible aware that they shouldn't do it.

Comment: @RobertLongson so basically, an awareness campaign that these are things that are already not okay to do? I could live with that.

Comment: The problem is they're deeply plausible but incorrect answers, and they're a ton of work to ferret out. I'd be tempted to just throw them a year's suspension for being a jerk and wasting people's time. I'd even be inclined to destroy their accounts for posting nonsense

Comment: @Tinkeringbell If copying the work of a ML model is plagiarism is an area of debate, not only for language models but for image generators too, and most voices seem to go to "a model is a tool and tools don't have authorship". If there's no policy, suspending for plagiarism because you've used a language model to help answer something doesn't seem appropriate to me. We need specific policy for this situation

Comment: Apparently OpenAI gives you full rights to the output of the conversation: _"As between the parties and to the extent permitted by applicable law, you own all Input, and subject to your compliance with these Terms, OpenAI hereby assigns to you all its right, title and interest in and to Output."_ ([source](https://openai.com/api/policies/terms/))

Comment: @ErikA fair enough, IF I encounter any I shall pick low-quality contributions as the suspension reason, just to be sure it won't be overturned in a court of copyright law. :)

Comment: @Cerbrus interesting - under Restrictions it says "[You may not] (v) represent that output from the Services was human-generated when it is not"

Comment: So, not plagiarism, but misrepresentation?

Comment: I just got it from skimming. Technically, the service doesn't allow you sharing output as is your own creation. Which answerers have been doing. But there is probably nothing the service can really do. At most, they'd cancel your plan for that account. If they bother at all. But then you can probably just register a new account ant continue. There is nothing they can really do about that output already in the wild. IMO, the clause is there to just cover themselves if somebody says "Some output from your service was used for <some abuse>" then they can just say it's not their responsibility.

Comment: We have begun internal discussions to identify options for addressing this issue. We’re also reading what folks write about the topic on their individual sites, as one piece of assessing the overall impact. While we evaluate, we hope that folks on network sites feel comfortable establishing per-site policies responsive to their communities’ needs.

Comment: Why are we completely against ChatGPT? Is everyone afraid for their jobs? Why not simply make a daily limit and if the user continues to churn out unhelpful answers that it is obvious that they did not edit or work on then ban them?

Comment: @JoshL1516 Because there's simply too much incorrect answers being generated to properly distinguish between them. We do not have the manpower for this level of quality control needed.

Comment: IANAL: Plagiarism, as used on our sites, is simply presenting a work as your own. If you didn't create it, it's not your work. As a non-existent thing ChatGPT doesn't own the copyright, and it seems that the user receiving the response is given what amounts to the Unlicense, or perhaps becomes the owner, even as far as copyrights are concerned. But, it's not a question of whether or not it's a copyright violation, or against what ever license you have to use the content. It's really a binary decision: did you create it [not plagiarism], or did someone (something?) else create it [plagiarism]?

Comment: @Slate At some point (probably sooner, rather than later) it may be necessary to clearly state on answering page that posting AI generated answers (on sites that don't allow them) is not acceptable and can result with account suspension. There are many policies that are not clearly stated and people post garbage because of that, but AI answers are way worse for detecting. There needs to be clear signal, and then there will be no surprises if someone gets a suspension. Also this could significantly reduce the influx of AI generated answers.

Comment: @tuskiomi ok thanks. **Important note**: [ChatGPT's sharing and publication policy](https://openai.com/api/policies/sharing-publication/#content-co-authored-with-the-openai-api-policy) requires that "_The role of AI in formulating the content is clearly disclosed in a way that no reader could possibly miss, and that a typical reader would find sufficiently easy to understand._"

Comment: @starball if only people would follow policy, lol. They don't. They want easy rep, and they'll do anything for that. So this crappy ChatGPT thing is the jackpot for them: way to write answers that look smart, get upvotes, and hard to detect it's not legit.

Comment: @starball it's also important to note that AI's cannot produce copyrighted works. This holds no water in a criminal context. It *may* have some recourse in a civil context, but the claim would be limited in damages, extremely so.  That's not to say you should break any ToS, but the recourse is limited, the ethics of the demands are dubious, and what you're really asking for is for stack exchange to enforce a contract between two third parties... It is a liability at  best.

Comment: @tuskiomi As I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide#comment1282245_384407) some ChatGPT output is synthesised from numerous sources, but some of it directly quotes long passages from a single source. That kind of plagiarism is actually quite common with the computer code that it produces.

Comment: This whole ordeal is a tragic comedy, wherein humans are trying desperately to define themselves separately from AI, and the only thing they can muster is that the AI makes the same mistakes humans do to a somewhat greater extent.   The only difference is in this case the AI is Odysseus and Stack Exchange is Charybdis. One day the arrow will perfectly pierce the axe handles, and we are not prepared.

Comment: While I agree that ChatGPT generated content does not belong in any StackExchange site, surely, to effectively **ban** this content we need to determine its existence. Apart from lack of citations, what definitive clues are there to determine that an answer was generated with ChatGPT compared to a basic uncited answer?

Comment: @tuskiomi True, there's a lot of plagiarism on the network, some due to ignorance, some wilful. If I suspect that the author is simply ignorant, I try to educate them in a brief, polite comment. Sometimes, (eg, when I recognise material from Wikipedia) I edit in an attribution myself. If it looks like wilful plagiarism, I flag it. Obviously, these processes don't scale well if a site gets inundated with ChatGPT content.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Please see [How can we identify ChatGPT-generated posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384457/334566) But as [Makyen says there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384459/334566): "We (mods and some users working specifically on handling these posts) have not been publicly sharing information as to how we detect such posts, because doing so would give people using ChatGPT information that would be directly helpful to avoid detection".

Comment: I think sooner or later **someone will make a browser plugin to select questions from the web and show its answers.** People can easily select the questions on SE and see the AI-generated answers. And we can't affect this. Anyway, this will reduce the need to copy paste. So for people who want to read its answers (and thus opposing the ban), this plugin will reduce the need to oppose the ban.

Comment: Abstracts written by ChatGPT fool scientists: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-00056-7

Comment: Maybe we need a bot that can detect vacuous answers!

Comment: @WalterMitty [DetectGPT](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.11305)

Comment: With GPT-4, the situation changed. You can expect better than human answers in many cases. The improvement from ChatGPT is impressive. The difference from ChatGPT to GPT-4 is much larger than the difference from GPT-3 to ChatGPT.

Comment: I read here a suggestion to ban the users that post GPT answer. Is there a way to ban people using a VPN?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar unless you have a reason why that's related to this question, post that as a separate question. Tag it either with [tag:support] or [tag:feature-request].

Comment: @starball you should just flag my comment if you think it's inapropriate, not replying to it. Thank you

Comment: @BelowtheRadar I was going to, but I wanted to give you the benefit of the doubt. Did you post that comment because you have reason to believe there is a connection between users using VPNs and users using ChatGPT to post answers?

Comment: @starball off course, users that will continue to post GPT answer after it was banned will try to hide behind a VPN. It is in the nature of some humans to do things like that.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar The ban is of an account- not an IP address. If they want to circumvent the ban, they would create a new account (which they shouldn't, but they won't care if they want to), and there's not much we can do about that unless they do anything to trigger certain detectors like voting-ring detection.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel "You can expect better than human answers in many cases." Not sure if better than human in many cases. I would rather say surprisingly good almost as good as human in many cases. But what is mostly evident is a lack of specificity. The general problem area is well explained, but when it comes down to grasping the core of the problem there is often still a lack. It can be helpful, but you always have to take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Trilarion That makes the impression that you are talking about answers without much prompting to steer the answer in the direction you want? It should be easy to make it specific, like by literally including "Be specific" in the prompt or the system prompt. Do you have an example query, so I can try to prompt it for very specific and very unspecific answers? (Try to include "Be terse." in the prompt for illustration)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With due consideration, we've decided no network-wide, general policy regarding banning ChatGPT, or other AI generated content, is necessary or helpful at this time. However, as detailed in [answer to: "Is attribution required for machine-generated text when posting on Stack Exchange?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384648), we do consider AI generated content to be "the work of others" and the [requirements for referencing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) must be followed for all such content on the network.

I want to be clear: I am not in any way intending to downplay the significance of ChatGPT, nor the disruption it has caused to the platform over the last few weeks.

Instead, we're going to stand by [the comment I left on this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide#comment1282259_384396) on December 5th:

> While we evaluate, we hope that folks on network sites feel comfortable establishing per-site policies responsive to their communities’ needs.

Each site on the network is going to be impacted by ChatGPT (and its future iterations) in different ways. Of all the sites on the network, Stack Overflow was hit by far the hardest. However, we are measuring its impact both on Stack Overflow and across the network -- and, the impact of ChatGPT is currently diminishing everywhere. Some sites will see more or less activity on a given day, but outside Stack Overflow, it appears to be leveling off to a very slow trickle. On Stack Overflow, its usage rate is still falling quickly.

Because sites are impacted to such different degrees by the usage of ChatGPT, we encourage sites to create these policies **as they become an issue**. A blanket policy does no good if affected communities are not simultaneously developing the methods they use to combat the material problems they face. Instead, it risks being actively unproductive, by setting an expectation that sites will purge this content without giving them targeted tools to do so.

Our work internally progresses on identifying these posts and making our systems more resilient to issues like this in the future. We recognize that this is a shot across the bow, and the problem isn't going to go away in the long term. But for now, it seems we've weathered this storm mostly intact. As always, we'll reevaluate this decision in the future, if the circumstances warrant it.

And, of course, if any site experiences a volume of GPT posts that are cumbersome to manage, or a site needs any other support managing an influx of unwanted content, we are always happy to help apply the tools we have at our disposal.

Comment: In very simple terms, this feels like you're protecting Stack Overflow while throwing the rest of the network below a bus and letting it get run over. Without clear policy, terrible low quality AI generated content will flood the sites, eventually bringing them down. And I really don't like that. It's sad, and I see it a terrible mistake.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Isn't Slate saying that in fact, ChatGPT-generated content isn't actually flooding non-SO sites?

Comment: @Adám perhaps it's not flooding them now, but seeing there is no policy against it, and seeing a clear request to ban it officially declined, I'm 100% sure people will start doing exactly that at some point. It's easy rep.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars But they only declined to ban it *now*. They promise to *reevaluate this decision in the future, if the circumstances warrant it.* So if people start doing it (as you are so sure they will do), further actions may be taken.

Comment: @Shadow If a community is experiencing a serious disruption in their ability to manage content quality, we will happily support that community using the tools we have at our disposal. Rest assured, the plan here is not to throw network sites to the dogs. Rather, that sites need to develop their own guidance specific to how GPT and language learning models are misused in their communities - policies we plan to help support. Overall, though, the median daily volume is very, _very_ low on all ~180 non-SO network sites & decreasing. And I'm monitoring that situation actively for unwanted changes.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars: If users are already unmotivated to try & prevent low-quality AI-generated content's flooding their site, then it's hard to imagine how the announcement of any network-wide policy will spur them into action. And I doubt the people posting this rubbish are paying any attention to policies.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard No; **Stack Overflow** is protecting Stack Overflow, because the ban arose out of community consensus there. As a Stack Overflow user, the process is that I flag suspected ChatGPT content via the normal flagging mechanism, then a Stack Overflow mod acts on that like any other flag. Each other Stack site is free to follow the same process and come to the same conclusions individually.

Comment: Is this officially endorsed by StackExchange? https://pipedream.com/apps/stack-exchange/integrations/openai

Answer (score 182):

I'd advocate for a hard line on this.

Something that's utter random garbage is actually less harmful than *almost correct* garbage that needs an expert to work out.

If you're using the output of a machine learning or AI tool WITHOUT verification and/or disclosure, and we're going to have to waste time working this out, the user clearly isn't here with the right intentions. As such I'd be inclined to treat the user as severely as needed, and I'd  be tempted to *start* with longer suspensions.

It's a good way to prevent folks who are clearly wasting people's time from wasting more of it.

Comment: so you're ok to use ChatGPT in an answer provided it has the proper attributions?

Comment: If its garbage, we'd delete it anyway and suspend the user if there's a bunch of poor quality contributions but seems a more polite way to do it

Comment: so you're ok to use ChatGPT in an answer provided it has the proper attributions and it's a correct answer?

Comment: *and* its verified to be a workable/correct answer.

Comment: Ok then I think your answer and mine are similar.

Comment: @Franck You can't give proper attribution: ChatGPT doesn't identify its sources. And the text it emits may be derived from the work of a few authors or thousands (if not millions). The topic of AI plagiarism is mentioned in https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/191197 for

Comment: My initial reaction to "I'd be tempted to start with longer suspensions" was that it might be too harsh but the fact is a) any user who does that must know _exactly_ what he's doing, b) said user would _at least_ suspect that doing so might be against the rules, and c) the user will have done that multiple times already as it's not easy to identify that behavior with one or two answers; in most cases, one needs a stream of AI-generated answers to spot the pattern. Based on that, I don't really think such punishment is too harsh.

Comment: Exactly - that's the same line of thinking I had

Comment: I fully support complete ban. Even if AI would be able to generate correct answers, then we could just ask AI instead. No need for posting such content on the network. We need to leave Stack Exchange for problems only people can solve. Anything else will not work in the long run and will cause more harm than good.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile "Even if AI would be able to generate correct answers, then we could just ask AI instead". No. Only true if AI is always correct.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Nothing is ever completely correct. If you could get excellent accuracy then you would probably first ask AI. Just like answers on SO are not always correct even some posted by experts.

Comment: @PM2Ring good point, I just meant giving attribution to ChatGPT.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt to be fair - the main advantage here is we can take a look, decide its crap and delete it faster.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Presumably the rule would be posted somewhere obvious before going into effect, so I think that anyone who violated it wouldn't have much excuse. Anyone who had a good excuse for not being aware of the rule could argue that to the mods on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Well, posting nonsense *is* something commonsensically bad. It's grounds for potential account deletion. I don't think there's an argument for posting trash being acceptable in any way, even if it's plausible garbage, rather than the outcome of a cat walking all over the keyboard

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile “Even if AI would be able to generate correct answers, then we could just ask AI instead.” This makes astonishingly little sense. Apply this logic to say, doing research, and now SE has zero reason to exist.

Comment: @Topcode I don't understand what is the point you are trying to make. If you can Google and get your answer, then it does not make sense to ask on SE.  If you could ask AI then it wouldn't make sense to ask on SE. Having said that, there are problems where Google or AI will not give you answer, so then you would ask on SE. Of course, people ask questions without doing research all the time, but that is a different issue.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile “there are problems where Google or AI will not give you answer,” a very small number of problems. If you think that if an answer can be found elsewhere it doesn’t belong on stack exchange (against the idea of stack exchange btw) then almost no answers could ever be posted, and no questions asked.

Comment: @Topcode I am not going to focus on rest of SE because some rules may be different on some sites. But idea behind SO was not creating duplicate of documentation that can be easily found elsewhere, though some duplication will always exist. Idea was creating high quality repository of knowledge and answers to common (or not so common) questions related to programming. So when you have a problem you can easily find solution because someone before already had that problem and it was solved on SO.

Comment: @Topcode That is what doing research means: searching first and asking questions only if you cannot find that information either on SO or elsewhere. And if you have found it and you don't understand something, then you need to explain what is exact problem and what you don't understand.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile “only if you cannot find that information either on SO or elsewhere.” Which is almost never. Despite what you may think SE is not special, and it doesn’t have access to anything that the rest of the internet doesn’t.

Comment: Not only that, on the various sites I frequent, citing sources is encouraged if not required.

Comment: @Topcode Stack Overflow also cites sources when it is applicable. However, vast majority of answers simply does not have any source because there aren't any. We are solving problems with our heads. That includes witting explanations of how something works even if it is not explicitly documented anywhere.

Answer (score 71):

Let me back this up and look at the broader picture here. We're about to enter a time that Star Trek once hinted at, but is now here and ready for your use: **artificially generated content**. The Internet has now reached maturity and search engines can run as much training data down your throat as you can handle. Quite literally we're watching the true next iteration of the Internet be born right now. Google can show you what already exists. AIs can generate almost anything your mind can dream up.

The problem there is ownership. The US helped the Internet in its infancy by [making an environment where you can "Fair Use" just about everything](https://www.eff.org/issues/cda230).

> [O]nline intermediaries that host or republish speech are protected against a range of laws that might otherwise be used to hold them legally responsible for what others say and do.

If you post a meme on SE that's using a copyrighted image, all SE has to do is take it down to avoid liability. With such a low bar to clear, it's allowed Fair Use to thrive. But... what do we do when these AIs [start generating content that is wholly based on the works of others?](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/08/ai-wins-state-fair-art-contest-annoys-humans/)

> Allen's victory prompted lively discussions on Twitter, Reddit, and the Midjourney Discord server about the nature of art and what it means to be an artist. Some commenters think human artistry is doomed thanks to AI and that all artists are destined to be replaced by machines. Others think art will evolve and adapt with new technologies that come along, citing synthesizers in music. It's a hot debate that Wired covered in July.

And [will these tools drown out actual users?](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/09/flooded-with-ai-generated-images-some-art-communities-ban-them-completely/)

> Established artist communities are at a tough crossroads because they fear non-AI artwork getting drowned out by an unlimited supply of AI-generated art, and yet the tools have also become notably popular among some of their members.

These are from September, involving art communities, but all ChatGPT is doing is basically a fancier search than Google can serve up. And this problem isn't going to go away because we're using machine learning **everywhere**. If an AI can't do it now, just wait.

For my fellow mods and I on Stack Overflow, the root problem boils down to two issues

### ChatGPT is a parrot

Parrots are very smart birds and they can mimic sounds very well. But **parrots cannot talk**. They [emulate the sounds they hear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVpFg.jpg) but they do not comprehend what they're saying.

ChatGPT is better than any chatbot we've seen. It writes in natural language, not the stilted text that typifies such systems. It generates what appears at first blush to be quality content. But we've noted that ChatGPT is doing what a lot of inexperienced users on Stack Overflow do: try to be the best-sounding parrot. Someone asked ChatGPT if it should be allowed to answer Stack Overflow questions and posted it in a now-deleted answer on our rule. I do have to admit it's amusing

> I am writing to express my extreme disapproval of the idea of allowing ChatGPT answers on Stack Overflow. This would be an irresponsible move and would fundamentally undermine the integrity of the platform.

Polly want a cracker? ([fascinating English.SE etymology lesson there](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75551/why-does-polly-want-a-cracker))

**ChatGPT is not a writer or programmer**, it's just copying other smart-sounding sources that look highly relevant. It can (to its inventors' credit) write simple, passable code. But ChatGPT doesn't know what [SQL injection is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and another mod experimenting with it found it will merrily give you code suggestions using it. Why? For too long that was how a lot of people did it on the Internet, and you can still find that poor advice everywhere. Hence why a lot of folks on Stack Overflow will incessantly warn you about not doing that.

The various AI image generators can afford to be parrots. In fact, that's what the users want. "Paint me a picture of a cat riding a unicorn carrying a shotgun in the style of Vincent Van Gogh". That doesn't work so well when you need something like "How do I create a contact form on my WordPress blog?" That's not something I would trust ChatGPT to answer. It might give you workable code that someone will use to gain control of said blog.

### Dishonesty

I won't link the person who said this, but this is a real Twitter post

> So I started a new stackoverflow account and I am plugging random questions without answers into https://chat.openai.com/chat and pasting the answer.
> So far, after 9 answers in 1.5 hours it has 1 accepted and 3 upvotes and a reputation of 62...

And

> 6 accepted answers, of the 26, 11 upvotes, 5 downvotes. I am not checking the answers in any way. I'll give it a rest for now and see how we do tomorrow...

I'm sure ChatGPT (or Google if you wanna go old school) can tell you where to find this user, but that second statement is downright scary. **They're not checking the answers in any way**. In other words *they also are not a programmer*. I've already gone over why that part is a problem, but there's another one here: **This user admits they didn't write the code**. From the [Meta Stack Overflow FAQ on non-English content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/2370483)

> Translating a question for a non-English speaker sets them and all participants up for a poor experience, due to the OP not being able to follow and respond to feedback from comments, understand answers, or get assistance from the Help Center.

The inverse of that is true here. A user comes in and asks a question. Someone posts an AI-generated answer without understanding anything about the question. What if the questioner posts a comment asking a clarifying question? What if the AI did something confusing in their answer? This user cannot interact in a meaningful way with said questioner. And, going back to the art site debacle, **who owns it if it's been copied?** I mean, we don't use Creative Commons for no reason. This butts up against plagiarism in a most uncomfortable way.

### TL;DR What do we do about it?

Answers generated by an AI **should be considered as being written by the AI**. That means you can quote them like any other source, but [you must attribute them to the AI, just like any other source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), and not use a bulk-copied AI answer quote as an answer. This way, we're avoiding the thorny issues of people running to the latest AI to get answers so they can copy-paste them as their own. We have plagiarism tools (current and forthcoming) in this wheelhouse so we don't need to reinvent any wheels.

If the AI gives a bad answer, we have votes for that.

Comment: Another piece using the parrot analogy: *[On the Dangers of Stochastic Parrots: Can Language Models Be Too Big?](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3442188.3445922)* ([ACM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_for_Computing_Machinery). 2021-03-01)

Answer (score 44):

#### I believe any AI-generated content needs to be banned network-wide, because it is an attribution/plagiarism nightmare scenario

Some of the other answers have focused on the difficulties with moderating AI-generated content for correctness, accuracy, usefulness, etc., and I don't meaningfully disagree with those answers. But I do think there is a big, big problem, **especially for a website network like Stack Exchange**, which is the near-impossibility of properly attributing credit for the words that the AI is producing.

The main problem is that the vast majority of AI-generating algorithms publicly available, including ChatGPT, do not properly credit the sources that were used in the training model that the AI used to tune its internal model. This means that any answers generated by the AI are, de facto, *plagiarism*.

Many of these AI algorithms/organizations will obviate around the plagiarism issues in ways that avoid obvious legal culpability: ChatGPT, for example, refers to this data as ["human AI trainers"](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/). But it remains the case that any use of these algorithms will constitute plagiarism until/unless stringent rules are applied to these organizations that they A) directly attribute every text that was used to train the AI model, B) only obtained these texts from authors that gave explicit, documented consent to have their texts used in these models, and C) document these contributions and make that data publicly available.

That doesn't necessarily mean it will never be appropriate to reference an AI-generated text per the normal Stack Exchange rules about quoting sources/using quote blocks in an answer (I have some skepticism about *how often* that will be appropriate), but I do think that this means—pending major ethical overhauls in AI-generated content—it will never be appropriate for AI-generated text to manifest as the body of an answer posted on this network.

**EDIT:** I don't know why this answer in particular is attracting users who seem ignorant about the relationship between Neural-Network AIs and actual biological human cognition, but to address a few recurring comments I've been seeing:

#### No, Neural Net AI Algorithms are not capable of Original Thought in the same way that humans are

<sup>Addendum: I am **not** saying that any/all AI Algorithms are not/will never be capable of original thought, but Neural Networks certainly are not.</sup>

Neural Networks [get their name from a conceptual similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network#History) between how biological neurons function and the abstract model of "Neurons" deployed in Neural Networks, which unfortunately has led to false equivalencies being made between the two, implying that human neurons and AI neurons are essentially equivalent or "the same, but varying in speed/power/etc.", and it needs to be understood that this is fundamentally untrue.

There's a lot of technical reasons why the comparison isn't particularly cogent, but to reduce it down to the simplest form possible: the biggest reason that Neural Networks cannot produce original thought is because they're not trying to. Neural Networks are designed with 'emulation' of existing data as an end-goal. To use ChatGPT as an example, its goal is not to create original ideas, its goal is to produce text that its model detects, with high consensus, is similar to the text that a human* has already produced. Stable Diffusion and other AI-Art-Generating algorithms operate on similar principles, attempting not to produce original paintings, but instead to produce an image that is similar to images that humans have already created.

<sup>* as defined by the model's training data, which I am assuming consists entirely of human-produced content but it should be acknowledged this may not be the case since the sloppiness with which sources are pulled into the model can in many cases pull in other AI-generated content, which would train the model not to talk like a human but instead talk like an AI</sup>

A really good case study for this "don't produce something original, produce something that resembles something that has already been created" function of neural networks is a test I performed, using Stable Diffusion, where I described a hypothetical D&D character (*"Githyanki Woman in Red Trenchcoat"*) and had the algorithm try to generate an image. [These were the produced results](https://creator.nightcafe.studio/creation/K8KyeWWgiUGHkZFYBwbM), which give us some important insights. The algorithm attempted to produce 4 images, and of those 4 images, two of them clearly modeled Cosplay photos (with some distressing facial distortion, which I'm guessing is the influence of the 'Githyanki' species modifier) and the other two generated... images of physical tabletop tokens, stand and everything.

It's not difficult to figure out what happened. The metadata of 'Githyanki' (a rare but playable humanoid species in some editions of Dungeons and Dragons) connected the algorithm to images that were created in Heroforge and other TTRPG token creators, along with cosplay photos of people modelling Critical Role characters (or their own original D&D characters). This is how the algorithm tried to establish 'similarity' between the images it created and the images it associates with the prompt provided.

But it's also very clear that none of the images produced are images that a human artist would create. In fact, the only way a human would produce any of those images themselves is if they had attempted to cheat the prompt—grabbing an image from a token generating website or a cosplay photoshoot and passing it off as their own work.

In other words, **the AI did an exemplary job of replicating what a human committing blatant plagiarism might attempt to produce.**

---

The reason I'm going into this long explanation and case study, aside from reinforcing my point about modern AI-generation algorithms only really being capable of committing mass-scale plagiarism, is to emphasize this point about these algorithms not being capable of original thought, and why arguments like "it's just like a human brain!" or "humans don't have to cite their training, why should AI have to?" are invalid. Some prompts are easier for the AI to replicate than others; certainly my example prompt broke the limits of what the AI was capable of replicating. But it's critical to understand that even when the AI is doing a much better job of reproducing what the prompt has asked it to generate, it's still doing the exact same thing as when it broke under the weight of my request: copying the data it found in its training data.

Now, the ethics of these algorithms can be solved: these algorithms could purge their databases, begin taking data only from artists who have explicitly consented to have their art/writing ingested, properly cite each work ingested, and make that data publicly available and easy to access, solving the widespread plagiarism I started out by addressing. I would even go a step further and argue that to be truly ethical the algorithm would also have to be able to cite the specific works whose influences composed the specific resulting output, but I'm guessing that might be technologically infeasible.

<sup>Important: something being "technologically infeasible" is not the same thing as saying "so we don't/shouldn't have to care about it". If AI-Art or AI-Writing can't be done ethically, I would argue it shouldn't be done at all, and whether or not running these algorithms ethically is a thing that can be done isn't in my purview.</sup>

But we need to dispose of this notion that these algorithms are, in any meaningful sense, engaging in original thought. They're not, and they're not truly replicating human thought, either at the macro level of human consciousness or at the micro level of individual brain neurons. Neural Networks are designed to emulate and reproduce existing works based on what the algorithm detects as being similar to those existing works, and they can be in some cases very uncanny replications, but they aren't original creations.

Comment: Does the term "plagiarism" make any sense for copying from a work not subject to copyright?

Comment: @JonathanReez So Plagiarism and Copyright are orthogonal concepts. Works that are not subject to copyright can still be plagiarized (used without crediting the source), and you can commit copyright infringement without committing plagiarism (cited the source but used too much of the copyrighted work and violated Fair Use). Important Distinction.

Comment: @JonathanReez Beyond the question of whether any of the works used in the training algorithms for these AI are, in fact, subject to Copyright (they might or might not be; and the fact that we're not sure is kind of the root of the problem given that, again, these works are not properly cited), failure to properly cite those works would still constitute plagiarism regardless.

Comment: AI writing text by learning from other texts isn’t any different from humans doing the exact same thing. You don’t have to attribute text you write to every single book on the subject that you’ve read. The tricky part is that prior to ~2021 any tool whatsoever was considered fair game to use to help you write text - spell checker, Google Translate, thesaurus, tools that help rephrase things, etc. But all of a sudden it’s claimed that this particular tool goes too far and no longer counts as a “tool”.

Comment: We consider plagiarism to be bad because it allows credit to be stolen. No such concern exists for *tools* because they don’t require human input. If you can write amazing novels using ChatGPT, why should you give your tool any credit?

Comment: @JonathanReez *"AI writing text by learning from other texts isn’t any different from humans doing the exact same thing."* This is not true. It's just flat-out completely false. Proselytizers for AI-generated content will sometimes *make this claim* because they want to capitalize on hype around AI and/or are jonesing for valuable Venture Capital funding, but the neural networks that power these algorithms are extremely unlike human thinking, and should not be treated as though they are performing original thought.

Comment: Um… humans don’t learn how to write text or code by reading the works of others? That’s certainly news to me. Humans need a significantly lower number of samples to learn something but the general principle is the same. There’s nothing magical about how our brain works, it’s just a neural network.

Comment: @JonathanReez This isn't a debate about how Humans learn, it's about how AI learns, and specifically, how Neural Networks operate. Mass-scale Matrix Multiplication is not analogous to human learning.

Comment: The brain uses the biological equivalent of matrix multiplication to achieve the same result. My question is why it's fair for a human to read a few articles and then write their own "original" article on the subject but not fair for an AI to do the same thing. You seem to assume that the human brain does some "magical" process while in reality it "auto completes" text in a fashion not quite dissimilar to ChatGPT.

Comment: @JonathanReez: I think the point that is being made here (underneath all the "AIs are not like humans" chatter, which IMHO is frankly just irrelevant and distracting), is that humans are normally expected to cite their sources, and ChatGPT is currently unable to do so. If you cite your sources, then as a rule, that is generally understood to be enough to defeat a charge of plagiarism. (There may be copyright issues if the text is very similar to the original, but that's a separate issue as Xirema's comment acknowledges.)

Comment: @Kevin people rarely cite their sources on Stackoverflow and many sites like Politics have a rampant lack of source attribution by humans

Comment: @Kevin I wouldn't had to have added that section if I didn't keep getting comments from people insisting otherwise. There's already quite a few deleted comments on this answer from people doing that...

Comment: @JonathanReez Which is why we don't want to introduce a tool that will make the problem exponentially worse.

Comment: @JonathanReez Humans _think about_ things. Transformers _do not think about_ things. The precise mechanics of human learning aren't relevant, because this distinction is enough to explain a lot of the difference between human output and ChatGPT output. (Ask ChatGPT not to plagiarise, and it'll tell you it's not plagiarising _while plagiarising just as much_.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 humans *sometimes* think about things. How often and how successful depends on the subject matter and the IQ of said person. If humans actually applied critical thinking all the time, we'd be living in a completely different world.

Comment: @JonathanReez IQ tests don't test critical thinking. If even [Nobel prize winners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobel_disease), who have made novel contributions to the body of human knowledge, can fail to apply critical-thinking, how would "capacity to solve IQ puzzles" be indicative? (But I suppose I'm just making your point again. As a bonus, I haven't proof-read this comment, so I betcha I've made it a third time, too.) Regardless, _experts_ tend to think about _their subject matter_, and those are the people who are answering questions on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JonathanReez Skynet is hiring.

Comment: "the biggest reason that Neural Networks cannot produce original thought is because they're not trying to." This makes it sound as if they *could* try to, which is rather frightening.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Well, more specifically, "not trying to" is colloquial synecdoche for "was not programmed to do". These neural networks can not try to produce original thought. And I'm dubious that any Neural Network type AI will ever be capable of original thought. If we create an AI someday that is capable of original thought, it probably won't be a Neural Network type AI.

Comment: "the biggest reason that Neural Networks cannot produce original thought is because they're not trying to. Neural Networks are designed with 'emulation' of existing data as an end-goal." Can we say the same thing for the human neuronal system? It is designed to emulate in some way the organization of data our senses and tools can see in the universe, the nature? Maybe an intelligent machine always try to emulate its creator?

Comment: @Xirema When you create something can you make total abstraction of everything else you have seen and know before? I dont think so. The difference with the AI is that they use a huge memory that can remember almost everything that existed in a very precise way,  before creating something. Something AI dont have and that is underestimated in the creation process is emotions.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar As I said before, it's not really my purview to discuss how humans think or behave. It's just my perspective that people are strongly misrepresenting what these specific Neural Network type AIs are doing (and are *capable* of doing) and that's muddying the waters a great deal. A lot of the bigger philosophical questions you're alluding to are, in my opinion, putting the cart waaaaaay before the horse. Interesting topics for Sci-Fi writing, but not terribly germane to the practical reality of these software as they exist today.

Comment: @Xirema haha thank you for that funny answer. What is lacking in the discussion is the philosophical part. You have to define what is a creation before pretending that only human can do such. If you read Kant you would understand that the human mind is pre-determined and it's the ignorance of causes that determine us that make us beliving we have free will and can do creation. For what I know, GPT-4 would be able to made answer just like yours if I ask it to do so. Does it means your answer is not coming from an Original Though because an AI can do the same?

Comment: @Xirema maybe you could translate that article: https://www.philomag.com/articles/chatgpt-est-il-une-personne

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Kant was a hack.

Comment: @Xirema Nietzsche called Kant the "Great Chinese" because he is really hard to understand. A hack? Not really... His critique of the Pure Reason is considered the beginning of the modern science... Anyway, your answer was interesting. That's the reason why I made those comments. Cheers!

Answer (score 30):

**I fully support network-wide AI ban. A permanent one.**

For now, the most prominent issue with AI answers is that they are mostly incorrect. Because they look like well-written elaborate answers they don't look like common low-quality answers that are otherwise poorly written or just contain code snippets (on Stack Overflow).

Because of that, they are harder to moderate - common flags like *low quality* and *not an answer* don't apply. Yes, incorrect answers could be downvoted, but that also requires some expertise in subject matter.

If the user posts plenty of such answers, they can also avoid an answer ban, by getting upvotes from other users deceived by the *initial good impression*.

Overall, incorrect AI generated answers are evidently harmful.

### Why a permanent ban?

If we take a look beyond incorrect answers, it will become clearer why a permanent ban is necessary.

Let's say we allow users to post AI generated answers they will check for correctness (ignoring for the moment other potential issues mentioned in other answers).

#### User is an expert and can verify answer's correctness

If the user has the expertise to verify the correctness of an answer, then they also have the expertise to fully write one. Grammatical errors were never an obstacle when answer content was otherwise good, and there is plenty of users that edit such answers, so improving language is not the advantage in this scenario. Also, there are other tools that can correct language errors.

Because users that have the expertise, don't need AI, if we allow such answers to be posted, there would be extremely small amount of such answers, as verifying the AI generated content would probably take more time than writing the answer.

We are not going to lose any good content posted and verified by the experts in such cases.

#### AI becomes so good it gives correct answers

This will probably never become true, but let's pretend that AI will generate if not always, then correct answers most of the time.

If this would be true, then people could just directly ask AI the question, instead of posting it on Stack Exchange. Similarly, currently people are supposed to read the documentation and use Google or other search engines for solutions before simply asking questions.

We don't need to allow AI generated answers, if AI can directly solve the problem.

---

Another aspect why we need to permanently ban AI, is that AI didn't magically appear. It is being trained on human generated content. Stack Exchange strives for quality, and we need to preserve human generated content to do that. If we allow AI answers, no matter how good they are, we will start losing experts willing to share their knowledge.

If you can post in a few seconds what AI gave you, why would you bother adding original content? With time, less and less people will be motivated to participate, and in the end, Stack Exchange will become a collection of AI generated posts nobody will read anyway because it would be much faster to ask AI directly.

And when you can effortlessly get virtual Internet points, they will lose value fast.

Comment: "If the user has the expertise to verify the correctness of an answer, then they also have the expertise to fully write one." While that is true, the user *might* don't want to take time to write it fully, so leave drafting to AI. After that they can take some time to brush up the draft, then answer it - Does this should also be banned? And if this happened how could you find out that it was actually made by AI?

Comment: @Skye-AT Yes, using AI should be banned in all cases. At some point when expert uses AI as help, it may be impossible to tell whether the answer is AI or not. And we don't need to push and enforce policy on anything even remotely suspicious. But policy needs to be clear without exceptions. Why? Because when you say it is admissible to use AI but you have to verify it, it is not just about the code it is also about explanation. ChatGPT is great BS writer, in other words it makes plausible explanations that only experts can verify, and sometimes even that can be hard.

Comment: We cannot allow people writing wrong answers just because they verified the code. Also even experts can fail to verify some area they don't know well, so this also poses a danger. Yes, there may be human written answers that are incorrect, too and are well written, but AI will only increase that.

Comment: You give people an inch and they will take a mile. We need clear AI ban.

Comment: "when you can effortlessly get virtual Internet points, they will lose value fast." Does rep have any value?

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt: Yes, [it does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide#comment1282441_384458). There is a market for it, driven directly or indirectly by real monies. Much of it is hidden; it would be nice to know more about it. There is [some evidence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421578/), but more is needed. E.g., it is suspected that HR drones use it as a hard filter on job applications, presumably driving some of the plagiarism on Stack Overflow.

Comment: And also driving the plagiarism on, e.g. [Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(website)), presumably because an online presence, e.g. in the form of a blog, is required or presumed to be required to get a (good) job.

Answer (score 23):

I asked this question directly to ChatGPT (the text of the OP's question):

> Use of ChatGPT generated text for posts on Stack Overflow is temporarily banned.
> However, the reasons for the ban really apply to much or all of the network, and certainly for sites that are similar in nature to Stack Overflow.
>
> I suggest (temporarily) banning ChatGPT network-wide.
>
> It turns out that ChatGPT can give correct (or correct-looking) answers even for subjects of sites that are not at all like Stack Overflow. I asked an unanswered question from Judaism.SE and got a fairly good answer.

Its answer was:

> This is a problem because it can mislead people who are looking for help, and it can also give an unfair advantage to ChatGPT users who are also answerers on Stack Overflow.

So, even ChatGPT itself agrees with the ban. Ban away!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421832/21103898

Answer (score 14):

Let's make this broader.

## Ban any form of AI-based content creation from the network.

This would cover both ChatGPT and any AI art-based creations.

I don't think disallowing *discussion* about them in the sense of legal or ethical discussion should be excised entirely from the network; there are plenty of places in which experts could weigh in and help the larger Internet community navigate this whole thing.

But someone sharing their AI art here?  Someone using a bot to answer a question?  Get that crap off the network.

---

Related:  I follow ***a ton*** of artists on Twitter (literally the only reason I haven't left the platform yet), and I can see that they're also worried and frustrated with the likelihood that AI art is both stealing their style and people are actively getting paid for it.  While I believe that the future of AI could be bright, the fact that these models are trained on data without consent is something I morally object to, and have held an opinion on since it's come onto my radar.

Comment: Would a network-wide ban include chat? Maybe I can't be too critical of it because I've posted AI images to chat, but chat isn't supposed to be serious academic prose like much of the network.

Comment: @Laurel I can't see any reason to ban AI generated content in chat. MSE main room, Tavern, already has a lot of AI generated images for several months, and everyone are fine with it. Same can be done with actual messages, within the CoC and ToS of course.

Comment: @Laurel:  I'd defer to those who are more expert on that.  If Chat's content is meant to be covered by copyright that could get complex.  If it's an objective conversation about it then I don't think I'd care too much, personally.

Comment: While I basically agree, there are a lot of exceptions. Besides for Shadow's, there are also e.g. pfps.

Comment: @Adám:  If you're saying that someone should be allowed to use an AI-generated piece of art as their avatar or in their profile, I'm going to firmly disagree with that.  No reason to make carve-outs *there*, after all.

Comment: @Makoto It'll be their responsibility to deal with copyright (but that's already the case with pfps). I should be allowed to use "AI" to generate a pfp e.g. based on all the photos and images I created myself.

Comment: @Adám: It's been a minute since I've had to deal with this, but it's not the individual that receives a DMCA complaint, it's the site.  They'll delegate all of the appeal process down so that yes, if you own the copyright on all the things then you can deal with it then, but it's not the case that these DMCA complaints are targeted so specifically to the individual.

Comment: [pfps](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pfp#Noun) = profile pictures

Answer (score 14):

I agree with this proposal. We are operating under a [similar policy](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6454/use-of-chatgpt-to-provide-answers) on the *[Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site. While moderating and removing answers posted using this tool, I've noticed that the ChatGPT tool is particularly good at generating content which seems eminently plausible to someone without knowledge of the topic, which in some cases has led to arguments developing in comment threads. In one case, the poster of the AI-generated content appeared to be feeding the critical comments back into ChatGPT and posting its replies.

Furthermore, if AI-generated answers were allowed, this would jeopardise the Stack Exchange reputation system, which is meant to be a decent measure of expertise and trust that the community places in a user. Users obtaining reputation through posting AI-generated content would not, in my opinion, have demonstrated that they are worthy of that trust or measure of expertise.

Comment: If high-rep users "have demonstrated that they are worthy of that trust or measure of expertise", why not trust them to only copy ChatGPT when it's correct?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that sounds so... soulless. as a high rep user, don't you take some pride in the humanity of your style and thought-process?

Comment: @starball no pride, just knowledge exchange or improving one's reasoning ability.

Comment: Politics is primarily about persuasion and "oughts", not facts and "ises" - using the term "plausible" muddies the waters. If someone can be tricked into debating one's own political position with an overgrown language model that performs no critical thinking, that should be taken as a sign that the human in that exchange has *also* not met a minimum standard of critical thinking.

Answer (score 13):

I'm surprised it hasn't been mentioned that Quora has a bot that asks questions that humans then get suckered into answering.  It's awful.  I've abandoned Quora (turned off all email notifications) in response, and I think most people who learn about this are similarly turned off.

We should explicitly ban bot-generated answers AND questions, across SE, forthwith.

Comment: I am not surprised. The awful ***moderation*** bots on Quora is sufficient reason to leave. Do you have some examples of such bot-generated questions.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-tell-if-a-question-is-asked-by-the-Quora-Prompt-Generator?top_ans=378375401.  I suppose this could be copied/paraphrased to a Q&A somewhere on SE.

Comment: It used to be quite hard to identify the bot's questions but, As noted at the link, it's become somewhat easier *if you know what to look for* -- now there's an icon on 'em.

Comment: And now they went the [hyphen site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts_Exchange) way by erecting paywalls around ***old*** answers which were freely available for many many years. It only becomes apparent when trying read the rest of an answer by expanding it: *"Access this answer and support the author as a Quora+ subscriber"*. [Sample](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-you-instantaneously-moved-Uranus-so-that-it-was-touching-Earth). [Compensation](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-a-wooden-ball-the-size-of-Texas-fell-into-the-ocean/answer/Dave-Consiglio).

Comment: @WHO'sNoToOldRx4CovidIsMurder no need to paraphrase: [Quora users (bots?) are copying a significant amount of Stack Exchange questions to Quora, without proper attribution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342516/178179)

Answer (score 13):

Sadly, this got another major hit, probably the final blow: [What is the network policy regarding AI Generated content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389582/what-is-the-network-policy-regarding-ai-generated-content)

In short, moderators are no longer allowed to suspend users when they suspect the posts are generated by ChatGPT, or other AI software, not even when using any of the existing detectors.

This can have only one result: ChatGPT answers are going to flood all the sites, and there's nothing to stop it anymore. This is a historical moment, the beginning of the end of Stack Exchange, which lost direction utterly and completely.

Comment: @Laurel you did not fix grammar, you made a major change in my answer. Are moderators still allowed to delete answers, and just not suspend the users? If so, should clarify, if not, should roll back the change.

Comment: You can revert if you want.

Comment: @Laurel but why did you change it in the first place? If it was correct, why you removed it?

Comment: We can delete "low quality" answers. That's pretty standard procedure on a lot of sites, going back before AI.

Answer (score 8):

I like this, but I'm going to split hairs and take that stance that this shouldn't really be "new" policy, and that it should instead just be messaging that reinforces *existing* policy on this new kind of "source" for content (for lack of a better term).

Plagiarism is posting content as your own that is *not* your own, simply put. This is completely regardless of whether a given work's license (or AI's terms of use, in this case) allows or disallows that practice– passing off anything that is not yours as yours is plagiarism, and is not allowed.

Because our network includes many different sites that work in unique ways, I think each individual site should be free to come up with its own decision regarding whether it officially allows or bars ChatGPT as a "source" for answers. But *no* network site allows plagiarized content, which is what wholesale copies of AI-generated responses are.

If this messaging would help deter users, even in some minor way, from flooding sites with AI-generated answers posted as their own, or would give moderators across the network more confidence in dealing with such content, then that sounds like a completely worthwhile message to send.

Comment: "*But no network site allows plagiarized content, which is what wholesale copies of AI-generated responses are.*" this is...debatable. It's a tool - you give it input, it gives you output. The rights to both are given to you. But even if that wasn't specified, it's no more plagiarism than using other tools. Since tools can't *own* content. The TOS of the tool does state that you should not be presenting the content as your own but that's hardly enforceable by non-affiliates. But mostly, the whole legality doesn't matter that much - the output tends to be garbage. Should be the driving factor.

Comment: @VLAZ Firstly; I'm no expert here, and so I genuinely don't know if the way I understand all this is the best way, or whether it will hold up in light of whatever new AIs come out tomorrow and what they can do. But, especially after reading [Machavity's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384429), I lean towards his idea that we can't treat these answers as "tool generated"– we _have_ to consider them as plagiarized, precisely because _they include zero actual input from the author_. **That's** the key distinction. Either a post is from the author to some degree or it's not. These aren't.

Comment: I'd also make the argument that using AI as a "tool" is combining its response with user input, to come up with an end result post that might incorporate ideas or pieces from the generated response but which is still a user-driven presentation of ideas. Obviously that line is _extremely_ blurry (E.g. How much user-generated content is needed for the result to be "user-driven"?)– but wholesale copies of AI responses are well outside that discussion in my view, because the amount of user input they include is exactly _zero percent_, which makes them de facto plagiarism.

Answer (score 4):

I believe a permanent ban on MI generated content is necessary to preserve the quality of answers on Stack Exchange.

Perhaps SE should go further. The GPT neural net (NN) trained on data scraped from many sources including Stack Overflow and related sites. As others have noted this happened without explicit permission, attribution or compensation. I didn't consent for them to use everything I ever posted on the internet for this purpose. Perhaps SE should create an opt-in model so that human creators need to give explicit permission to use their contributions for NN training. The default legal position then becomes, "No. You can't use my creativity to train a proprietary, competing tool". Thoughts?

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to legally block AI training from using CC BY SA licensed content (which includes the entirety of SE). As I understand it, if they attribute the source, they can use the content. If you disagree, the only way to find out who's right is probably to sue. (Do they attribute their sources? Not that I've found, but if that's the only legal qualm then they could continue what they're doing if they properly attributed their sources.)

Comment: @Laurel question is how they scrape the training data, in what tools, etc.

Comment: @Laurel https://law.stackexchange.com/q/11183/31

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt's link (somewhat) addresses the attribution side of things. However, that's not the core of the issue. Stack Exchange posts are licensed under CC BY SA, which cannot be revoked. You can tell someone they can't use your stuff, but it's an empty threat legally if you've licensed it under a license that allows that use. Or was this suggesting a new license for future contributions? Are there any licenses out there like that or is it unenforceable?

Comment: @Laurel "In the case of a share-alike-licensed dataset, must all models trained on it be redistributed under the same or similar license?"

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt And if they distribute it under a compatible license?

Comment: @Laurel I think it's ok, unless perhaps if the license excludes derivative work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not advocating for or against bans here -- I agree overall that there are valid reasons to ban ChatGPT answers, *especially* copy/paste/verbatim.  But I do think some of the answers here are (and this may not be the best word), "overreacting" to certain aspects of the issue:

- Position:  *All* ChatGPT content should be banned.

  Does this include grammar checks done by ChatGPT, verified by the editor, and modified as needed by the editor?  I've found ChatGPT to be a good tool (when it's up) for quickly suggesting better grammar in several posts that *needed* improvements.

  - Example 1:  [Before](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1445104/4) and [after](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1445104/5).  IIRC, I'm fairly certain I did change one word from the ChatGPT suggestion -- I felt "the issue persists" was better than "this issue persists".
  - Example 2:  [Before](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1445103/1) and [after](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1445103/2):  I definitely made some small tweaks to the ChatGPT suggestion to make it slightly more concise, but I can't recall exactly what they were.

  I do a lot of grammar/clarity edits (including, frequently, on my own mistakes).  While I certainly *could* have cleaned up these two posts on my own, ChatGPT saved a *lot* of effort in these cases, and I believe the posts (and site) are better for it.  In no way did ChatGPT suggest an answer here, or rely on any training other than proper English grammar.

  Should this use be banned as well?

  *Counterpoint*:  ChatGPT can still make grammar mistakes that change the meaning of the post.  If the editor doesn't carefully review the changes to assure consistent meaning, then there's a risk of a bad (and disallowed) edit.

  *Counterpoint-to-counterpoint*:  And yet, honest mistakes in editing happen even with human intervention (*perhaps* even more so).

  I'm not saying I have the answer here, just raising the question of whether (or not) there are acceptable and positive uses of ChatGPT.
- Position:  Attribution issues are a nightmare, since ChatGPT can't tell us where it learned something.

  I struggle with this one as well.  Sure, this is a problem, but isn't it a problem for many posts by humans as well?  Unless we came up with an answer *purely* by finding a website with the answer, we typically don't remember *where* we found the information originally.

  Take the Stack Overflow answer to [How to permanently export a variable in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13046663/11810933).  At some point, the user who posted this had to learn how to do it themself, but it's unlikely they remember when or where.  I certainly don't remember where I learned how to do that.  Why would we expect an AI to be able to cite/attribute its source for where it learned something when most of us don't know ourselves?

  The problem, of course, is when there is only a *single-source* of the information.  Even so, if I read something in an article several weeks ago, and the topic comes up in a month in a Super User question, am I going to remember where I read it?  I'll try to search the web to find it again so that I can attribute it, but most people wouldn't even go that far.  But at that point, it has become part of personal my "memory" and "training", regardless of whether it is information from a single-source or available from multiple-sources.

Answer (score 1):

Let me go a little deep in support of this question.

Firstly, Stack Exchange would be useless if ChatGPT was allowed network-wide. Remember that SE is a network of communities such that each person seeks to learn more from each other, not just the questioner. Even answerers get to learn by getting improvements from other users. This would be useless if AI could automatically answer all questions, with little error, and ChatGPT has seemed to achieve this goal.

I hear you saying "But we've got Google!". Well, for starters, most of my programming answers were basically searches into Google, but they mostly redirected to Stack Overflow and related webpages.

Secondly, AI is still not *yet* perfect. So although the range of error is small, now again here we're talking about lots of answers. That means, small translates to a (somewhat) big amount.

Thirdly, most of the issues concerning SO about AI pretty much applies to the entire network.

That's all I've got to say.

Comment: "Stack Exchange would be useless if ChatGPT was allowed network-wide" why? The output is either satisfactory to the asker or it isn't, and in the case it isn't it can still ask the question.

Comment: "_This would be useless if AI could automatically answer all questions, with little error, and ChatGPT has seemed to achieve this goal._" =.= have you been following the discussion on MSO?

Comment: @Braiam Note that AI gets better nearly every week, and if this rate can be reliable enough to keep improving it, then if your comment is right, the percentage of questions asked will go *really* low

Comment: @starball I've been reading it, yes

Answer (score -50):

I disagree: we shouldn't blindly discriminate against AI. If ChatGPT provides a correct answer, then it shouldn't be deleted, provided it has the proper attributions. No need to waste human time if some AI can do it. However, if an SE user tends to post incorrect answers, then they should be banned.

Example of attribution that we could require users to add:

> This answer was (partly) written by [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat), but I have the expertise to confirm it is correct.

Notes:

- The [most upvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384407/178179) is pretty much the same as this answer.
- SO banned ChatGPT on the basis that it can generate a wrong answer, and Puzzling SE [banned](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7426/410) ChatGPT on the basis that it can generate a *correct* answer.

---

Follow-ups:

- [How often does ChatGPT give an incorrect answer to an SE question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384410/178179)
- [How can we identify ChatGPT-generated posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384457/178179)
- [How good should a generative question-answering system or a language model be to be allowed to write answers on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384652/178179)
- [Which online software to use to check answers on StackExchange for plagiarism?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/50793/903)
- [How can a language model keep track of the provenance of the main knowledge/sources used to generate a given output?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38372/4)