# What quality threshold should be established for language models/question-answering systems to be allowed to write answers on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, quality, chatgpt

One of the [main](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396/178179) criticism against using [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat) is that it [may frequently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384410/178179) give an incorrect answer that appears like it's professionally written and therefore correct. As a result of this and a sudden inundation of low-quality AI-generated answers, SO [has banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/395857) its use. Other SE sites [may follow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396/178179).

How good should a generative question-answering system or a language model be to be allowed to write answers on a Stack Exchange site? (either with or without a human checking the correctness of the machine-generated answer)

Comment: Re _"One of the main criticism against using ChatGPT is that sometimes it gives bad answer"_: Wrong. One of the main criticism is that **most of the time**, it gives bad answers.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384410/178179

Comment: Also, counterpoint: suppose some AI reaches 99% accuracy (which is better than humans), still, why would the poster blindly copy and paste the answer without validating it first?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine validating by who?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine the accuracy of human answers on Stackoverflow is definitely lower than 99% :-)

Comment: I guess they need an approved list of calculators: https://www.bbc.com/news/education-27391683 https://satsuite.collegeboard.org/sat/what-to-bring-do/calculator-policy https://apstudents.collegeboard.org/exam-policies-guidelines/calculator-policies --- Should math.SE and mathoverflow.SE allow the use of calculators? --- Should writing.SE allow computer spell check? --- Should astronomy.SE allow telescopes, or should observations be made with the naked eye?

Comment: Isn't *generative* usually taken in the Chomsky sense of the term?

Comment: @bad_coder I use it in the NLP sense (writing answers from scratch instead of extracting them from some passage).

Comment: It would be good enough when AI will have a soul. Or, in my humble opinion, ***never***.

Comment: "*validating by who?*" by the poster. It asks "*why would the **poster** blindly copy and paste the answer without validating it first*". There is no change of the subject until it reaches "validating". Moreover, the main problem which has repeatedly been cited that blatantly incorrect content was posted where the answerer either knowingly or completely without care copy/pasted the generated content. Often in rapid succession, as well, just to nail down that their motive is not to provide good content but just *any* content. The context around this discussion seems to be quite clear.

Comment: @VLAZ I see, then "why would the poster blindly copy and paste the answer without validating it first" is answered by your comment.

Comment: But not by your question where you put forward the premise suggesting that there should be some form of metric to allow such blind copy/pasting.

Comment: @VLAZ Not necessarily blind. Good point, I've edited the question to clarify it. SO [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/395857) ChatGPT regardless of human verification.

Comment: feel free to check my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422013/chatgpt-should-be-incorporated-into-the-site/422019#422019) since I think it addresses some related topics/details.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed.  Why not discuss this topic?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Same, no idea. Good timing to reopen given today's release of [Hugging Face Introduces StackLLaMA: A 7B Parameter Language Model Based on LLaMA and Trained on Data from Stack Exchange Using RLHF](https://www.marktechpost.com/2023/04/12/hugging-face-introduces-stackllama-a-7b-parameter-language-model-based-on-llama-and-trained-on-data-from-stack-exchange-using-rlhf/), and the quality of GPT-4.

Answer (score 24):

I would argue that the potential quality of the answers generated automatically (using ChatGPT-like services) **is irrelevant**.

- If such answers are mostly¹ bad -> they should not be allowed.
- If the answers are generally¹ good -> then, ChatGPT-answer could have been obtained by the user themselves similar to search engines; thus, a user could have asked ChatGPT the question directly without asking it on Stack Exchange. Nobody would find posting a "screenshot" of Google search results as an answer useful.

**Therefore, I don't see a place for fully automatically-generated answers on Stack Exchange at all.** Thus, however accurate those services become, I don't see the value in allowing them on Stack Exchange² **as answers**³.

---

(part of this answer is rewritten from [my answer on Academia SE Meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5221/56594))

¹ mostly/generally are very subjective, and determining the exact number might be hard; however, for this answer it is irrelevant.

² I can easily see a different than Stack Exchange service which is very valuable for users providing automatically-generated answers, potentially curated by human users. It is just a different service and business.

³ Stack Exchange can probably use ChatGPT-like services in "Ask Wizard" or other mechanisms. But not as an answer itself.

Comment: Shouldn't we then require users to check ChatGPT **today** before posting a question? It's already very good at coding questions so it seems reasonable to require users to try the ChatGPT solution before going on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @JonathanReez do we already **require** users to check Google? I don't see how it is different in that regard.

Comment: My current interpretation of the rules is **no**, we don't require them to check Google. We only don't allow questions that have been asked on SE itself, even if answered on other sites. But then... why would ChatGPT be any different? Why would we mandate users to check ChatGPT (or a future version of it) if we don't mandate it for Google?

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't see why we should mandate users to check ChatGPT as well.

Comment: But... that's literally what your answer states? *thus, a user could have asked ChatGPT the question directly without asking it on Stack Exchange. Nobody would find posting a "screenshot" of Google search results as an answer useful.*

Comment: So, either the question shouldn't have been asked at all because its trivially answered by ChatGPT+ or it's a valid question and **any** valid answer should be acceptable, including an autogenerated one. I struggle to understand why it would matter whether or not the correct answer is human generated or not.

Comment: Nope. Not at all. My answer states that neither posting of Google search screenshots nor ChatGPT-generated answers has a place on SE. Nothing that I am saying about mandating users to check Google or Chat GPT. They could. They also can ask on Quora\Habrahabr\Reddit\younameit.

Comment: Ok, then I remain confused as to why we should care whether a valid/correct answer is human-generated or machine-generated. We don't accept screenshots from Google but in practice we do accept quotes found in Google with a reference to the source.

Comment: We may not enforce that users search before asking, but we do require/ask of them to do so. The first point of [how to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page is "search and research". When you ask questions you are also presented with a generated list of questions on the site too. So, we may not require you to tongue test to ask question, but we strongly recommend you to do so.

Comment: Except you are forgetting you still need to ask ChatGPT the right questions to get decent answers. Many don't know how to do that. It also doesn't yet run the code that's produced & run benchmarks, which in a SO answer would be required. So still a big scope for canonical GPT derived and verified answers to be featured on SO.

Comment: @TomWenseleers I see that as a plus in some twisted way. If chatgpt can't understand your question, a human could have a problem with it. Something like "does this question have all the reasonable elements to be answered?"

Comment: @Braiam I agree - I definitely ask any question first to ChatGPT4 now. Usually that already gets you some useful pointers or manages to answer your question entirely. It's rare now with ChatGPT4 not to get an answer at least as good than what you might get as a reply on SO. It usually rephrases your question in a clearer way as well. So it really helps to guide your thinking.

Answer (score 11):

> How good should a generative question-answering system or a language
> model be to be allowed to write answers on a Stack Exchange site?

Let's imagine it is perfect.

Why would anyone ask on Stack Overflow then? Why not ask the AI directly?

Technology changes fast, we already have problems with outdated answers. If AI could give us correct answers, why would we create a static collection of answers generated by AI, that may not be up to date?

Searching is always an issue, too. Why are people dumping their questions on Stack Overflow without searching? Because it takes time. If we allow AI-generated content there will be even more of it, which makes searching even harder. And again why would anyone search or ask on Stack Overflow if they can just ask AI?

---

But most likely it will never be that good. And it does not matter, because it is simply not an appropriate tool for the Stack Exchange platform. We want human knowledge and insight. Human reasoning. That is something AI cannot give us.

Comment: "*We want human knowledge and insight. That is something AI cannot give us.*" it can. But therein lies the problem. An AI can examine a large volume of human-generated content then summarise the insights they've expressed. Let's say humans agree that feature X is inconvenient because of A, B, and C. Therefore experienced people suggest feature Y which has less potential downsides. An AI can indeed relay the gist here. But only for things humans have expressed an opinion on. Let's say 10 years later such AI summaries are the norm. There are less humans sharing their experience. Less to sum up.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, AI is trained on human data, and while there are situations where it can appropriately summarize that knowledge, there will always be situations where it will not be able to because we are encountering a completely new problem that requires new approach and solution. Maybe it can give some ideas and trigger people to go in particular direction they would not consider, but that is all.

Comment: "Let's imagine it is perfect." -> that's the easiest case indeed :) "We want human knowledge and insight. That is something AI cannot give us." -> Why not? QA systems can be pretty good to query human knowledge in at least some domains or question types.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Because you want the human knowledge that is not already out there. You want human ability to solve new problems and there will always be such problems.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile so you mean human reasoning then?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yes, I thought that "insight" covers it.

Comment: "Why not ask the AI directly?" what happens if I don't know that the AI (actually ML) exist? Or the AI is behind a paywall? Or the AI is overloaded? There's a time misalocation problem that SE asynchronous nature solves. Also, sometimes my queries are not as useful as someone that reads my question and compiles a better query. The AI might be perfect, but it can't be better than the inputs presented either.

Comment: @Braiam "Why not ask the AI directly?" was not meant literally. I was meant as a counterpoint for argument that we should allow AI answers and that only problem with AI answers is that they could be wrong while they sound very convincing. If the AI answers are wrong, then we should definitely ban AI as incorrect answers that sound convincing do a lot of damage and AI allows people to write plenty of such wrong answers they would not be able to produce manually. And if the AI is almost always correct, then again it makes no sense to allow AI answers as people can just ask AI instead.

Comment: ... if someone does not want or cannot ask AI, their questions are always welcome as long as they follow community guidelines and they don't expect that someone else will ask AI for them :)

Comment: Except you are forgetting you still need to ask ChatGPT the right questions to get decent answers. Many don't know how to do that. It also doesn't yet run the code that's produced & run benchmarks, which in a SO answer would be required. So still a big scope for canonical GPT derived and verified answers to be featured on SO.

Comment: @TomWenseleers Who would verify those AI answers? The mere fact that you are talking about verified answers is exactly what the problem is with AI generated answers. They can be correct purely by chance and most are full of hallucinations and blatantly wrong. We should not waste our time on any of those. And again, if some day some AI would be able to give us correct answers all the time, then I am pretty sure that such AI would be able to understand asked questions and presented problems without the need for tweaking the prompt to exhaustion or as you say asking the right question.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile Well for one thing the OP should have more powers to delete bad or irrelevant answers. It shouldn't cost you reputation to downvote or delete a bad answer e.g. if you posted a question. For programming related questions I think verification would be easy: just ask for reproducible code & benchmarks. ChatGPT can't run your code itself yet. That would work for all my 3 examples here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390348#390348. Easier than trying to detect if GPT was used if I hadn't told you.

Comment: @TomWenseleers Also you don't have to run code to know it is correct. People run code just in case, because we can make mistakes. AI that KNOWS would not need to run the code. And most code does not require benchmarking. It is very rarely that Q/A pair has some.

Comment: @TomWenseleers No, OP shouldn't have extra powers on answers under their questions. Plenty of time they are in no position to properly asses the answer. Yes, it may compile or run or solve their immediate problem, but that does not mean it is good answer.  Similarly people may want to discard answers they think are not right just because answer suggests completely different and correct approach. and answers are not meant just for the question asker.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile Well practically all the answers with R & Python & Matlab code that I look at has reproducible code.... You still need to run code to have a benchmark on your machine & be able to compare to other methods, which is often what's requested. And I would just allow ChatGPT or Github Copilot assisted answers for these sorts of cases...

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile In my experience the OP is in the best position to assess the accuracy of answers (incl which answers are the best). Moderators often don't have a clue about the specific problem at hand. Completely irrelevant & nonworking answers could be taken out right away with further intervention... Would decrease the burden on moderators significantly.

Comment: @TomWenseleers Moderators don't have to asses accuracy of answers. It is not their job to do that. Just because some askers will be able to give proper assessment of received answers, that does not mean that all can. We need to model rules that will take into account all users. Giving OP more power over answers would be a poor choice. It would be nice if it would be easier for experts to moderate bad answers, but that is separate issue.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile Still don't understand why checking if for a programming related question where GPT was used reproducible code is included plus output would be any harder for moderators than to check if GPT might have been used... Up & downvoting by knowledgeable experts should be rewarded & facilitated too yes. Now I often don't downvote bad answers because it would cost me reputation. Up & downvoting of good or bad answers should gain you more reputation - it's an essential task... As long as best answers would have highest nr of votes I wouldn't care about bad answers being there too.

Comment: @TomWenseleers the problem is scale. there is not enough experts to verify each and every answer out there. And AI gives people ability to post unverified answers in huge amounts comparing to what they could if they would write answers themselves. The only ability to fight such crap AI answers is blanket ban and our human ability to recognize such answers and remove them on basis they are AI generated. Anything else does not scale.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile Which is why regular users, maybe dependent on their reputation in a particular field, should be given more powers to kick out the bad answers. Also not saying GPT should be allowed everywhere on the site. But for programming, given that >80% of all software developers now use it already, it's clear you won't stop it. And with a blanket ban, people would post GPT answers anyway & not disclose it, which would be worse... You should also be able to train much better AI Bots to do a lot of the moderation-that would scale.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile ChatGPT4 is pretty good at rating SO answers actually. If I ask it to rate the answers here e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130661/blind-source-separation-of-convex-mixture/618990#618990 it gives correct comments about each answer & gives the given answers all a 6/10 except mine which gets a 9/10, which seems quite correct to me... Probably too expensive still to do this at scale, but just saying...

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile I posted some examples here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390348#390348

Comment: @TomWenseleers I just landed on some of your posts on SO Meta and it is clear that no matter what others say and what arguments they present, you will not change your position. Which is fine, but it makes no sense in discussing this further. When you actually find a working solution (not imaginary one) that can solve scale of bad AI posts that does not include humans (because there are not enough of us here) or only in very minimal manner, you can always report back. And again, if you come up with AI that can distinguish between good or bad AI answers we can just use AI directly.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile I felt obliged to share my experiences with using ChatGPT4 & generative AI, which are totally at odds with everything I read here. But yes, I'll also leave it at that. That the SO community does with that input what they want. Most of the answers & replies of others on AI are totally outdated - they have no clue what they are talking about really...

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile Weren't you on strike actually? Or you make an exception when it concerns bashing the potential of AI? :-)

Comment: @TomWenseleers I am on strike on main sites. Meta sites are different as they are place of discussion about how sites work or should work.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile Thanks - I see - for me it was the first time posting things here. But when it comes to discussing ChatGPT it all feels more like activism to me, more than a reasoned data-based discussion. I find posting here super frustrating. I think I'll retreat back to Stack Overflow & Cross Validated. Or ChatGPT4: always up for a chat & no votes to close questions there...

Answer (score 6):

> How good should a generative question-answering system or a language model be to be allowed to write answers on a Stack Exchange site?

Put simply we assume that Q&A generation system would be training/learning from SO answers and other sources; hence there'd be no gain (theoretically?) in allowing it to output into its learning data/corpus (or cross-posting parts from outside SO). I don't see a threshold where we could consider the AI generated content as being original.

Accuracy in that case would assume the AI is producing relevant answers that haven't been posted by humans on the SE repository or elsewhere - it has yet to be demonstrated that ChatGPT is doing more than collating on-topic content and composing syntactically coherent sentences.

In conclusion ChatGPT would make sense as a SaaS Q&A [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle) not as a participant in a human problem-solving site.

Comment: I took a closer look at one AI answer I saw (one of the higher quality ones); a targeted Google search of the question title brings up the same info that was in that answer. LMGTFY with different steps?

Comment: *it has yet to be demonstrated that ChatGPT is doing more than collating on-topic content and composing syntactically coherent sentences* => has this been demonstrated for humans? After all we have a similar neural network in our brains.

Comment: @JonathanReez of course it has, usually it's called creativity.

Comment: What test can conclusively prove the presence or lack of creativity in a given individual/computer system? Are you sure ChatGPT wouldn't pass said test better than a large percentage of humans?

Comment: @JonathanReez [proof for humans](https://youtu.be/kLwK-Yt5iB0?t=69) looks something like this, but any spontaneous act will do - it doesn't have to be flamboyant. Put simply, a sort of [Creatio ex nihilo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creatio_ex_nihilo).

Comment: ChatGPT generates plenty of coherent, reasonable text that's never existed before, yes. Your answer seems to be hung up on *collating on-topic content and composing syntactically coherent sentences* and AFAIK there's no reason to believe humans aren't doing the exact same thing internally. We're nothing but fancy auto-completion and prediction neural nets.

Comment: @JonathanReez your claims lack proof.

Comment: 1. Could you add a reference for the idea that humans aren't *collating on-topic content and composing syntactically coherent sentences* internally? 2. What kind of proof would you like? ChatGPT is free and open for all to test.

Comment: @JonathanReez supply proof.

Comment: [Here you go](https://note89.github.io/the-advent-of-code-ai-edition/) => what percentage of software engineers can do better than that? Surely not 100%? Note that the problems are all original and never seen before by the AI.

Comment: @Jonathan ChatGPT generates plausible text, consistent with its training data & input, but it doesn't know what it's talking about, and it has no way of representing or evaluating the truth of its utterances. Sure, it can say true things, but it can also say complete nonsense, and it can't tell the difference. Eg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WsuA.png

Comment: @PM2Ring sure but a lot of humans likewise write text without really understanding what they’re talking about. That’s how you get poor StackOverflow answers. ChatGPT is estimated to have an IQ of 80 at this point.

Comment: @JonathanReez sounds like we need much stronger tools to use against low quality content and be much more assertive in dealing with it. Rather than using the low quality content to justify more low quality content.

Comment: @VLAZ OPs questions basically asks what the IQ of a future GPT should be in order for it to be acceptable on stack overflow. In theory a future system might have an IQ of 130 and thus beat 99% of human engineers in writing StackOverflow answers. What then?

Comment: @JonathanReez if it actually consistently writes better answers (remember that IQ isn't a measure of "how well you are at answering on SE") then Mission. Fucking. Accomplished. There is that "if" in the beginning, though which needs a lot of work.

Comment: @JonathanReez https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.00077.pdf "When writing a summary, humans tend to choose content from one or two sentences and merge them into a single summary sentence". So humans are also often just collating on-topic content :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt people seem to believe they have a magical "soul" that generates "true inspiration", as opposed to ChatGPT which lacks one.

Comment: I've had ChatGPT4 write down a verbal problem statement as a differential equation system and solve it correctly using Wolfram Alpha. I would count that under reasoning capability. This answer was pretty good too, with prompt just being original question plus 2 extra ones to ask for some extra details: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than

Comment: @JonathanReez Well they did give ChatGPT4 an IQ test & it scored 155 apparently, which would be top 1%, https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/i-gave-chatgpt-an-iq-test-heres-what-i-discovered/. I think that's a bit of an overestimate, but the vast knowledge helps of course. And for answering many university entrance exams it ends up in the top10%, https://openai.com/research/gpt-4. All of the info on SO on ChatGPT is terribly outdated. And any question about it that's remotely positive gets closed down immediately.

Comment: @JonathanReez Here I posted a couple of representative examples of what I got out of the latest version, ChatGPT4: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384652/what-quality-threshold-should-be-established-for-language-models-question-answer/384664?noredirect=1#comment1303473_384664