# GPT-generated "search as you type" responses

Tags: discussion, search, asking-questions

There is a current hot meta post on SO regarding [banning ChatGPT answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/616460), which I *fully* agree with ([plus some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned/422343#422343)).

However, I still think GPT bots themselves have a lot of value. They're trained on existing data sets, so they're effectively just search engines that present a reorganization of existing information in the form of readable text. Also, they *can* generate valid and often correct answers, especially to simple questions.

To that end, and along the lines of "embracing the future", I think it could be really useful, or at least interesting, to have GPT-generated responses (trained on relevant datasets, perhaps site content, or ChatGPT) appear as you are typing your question (on almost all sites<sup>*</sup>), along side the existing search-as-you-type results.

Especially for highly active and popular sites, having these results displayed could, hypothetically, greatly reduce the number of low quality or duplicate questions that end up posted by essentially giving the user better search results in a very readable form.

Even though I support the answer ban, I think it would also be, well, kind of crazy to not take advantage of a good technology in an attempt to improve site quality. While I think copying actual posts from bot responses is a bad thing, I don't think the algorithms are inherently bad or useless. Also, if it works as a pre-post question filter, it could work *really well*. So I think it's worth a shot.

Thoughts?

Even if not this, are there other ways to get value out of these algorithms here?

---

<sup>*</sup> "Almost" all sites: So there are definitely some sites where this wouldn't be OK. In particular, sites where bad advice can lead to injury (e.g., *[Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/tour)*, and *[Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour)*). It would also have to be very clear that it was a bot, or the user would have to actively press a button or something to see the suggestion. This would have to be tested, and released in a limited capacity only on the most appropriate sites. While nothing prevents current answers from containing bad advice, unlike actual answers, the search results don't get votes or comments.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421836/16886597

Comment: How would that integrate into the SE content rating mechanism, i.e. vote-on-stuff-that's-useful? If there are no duplicates any longer because GPT just blends them together as needed, users don't get to see the source(s) – and it seems it be difficult to say what the relevant sources even are.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi For the content rating it doesn't matter I don't think; since you'd essentially be expanding "search before asking" to include "ask a bot" in the definition of "search". So it's not really site content, it just becomes more like generic search results. Same process as if you searched the internet first, found your answer, and so didn't post a question. Otoh, as for crediting sources of the bot's information; yeah, that's a good point, and probably one (of a few) big minuses for this suggestion.

Comment: Haha, watching the score go down; clearly this was not a great idea. There must be some way to get *some* value out of these algorithms, though, even if not this. 

Comment: @JasonC The base problem is that ChatGPT has absolutely no concept of "correct" or "accurate" with respect to what it produces. It just strings text together that its model thinks is likely to be associated with the input and what it's already picked. Thus, a very high percentage of the output is wrong. Given that the output is "eloquent bullshit" (i.e. what it was designed to do) a *lot* of people are deceived into thinking it's correct. It often takes an expert, or at least someone who already knows the correct answer, to determine that the response is, actually, just "bullshit".

Comment: IMO, it would be a major disservice to inflict such answers on users. One of the worst things you can do for someone asking a question is to provide an answer that *sounds* really good, but is actually bad. It costs them a *lot* of time to determine that such an answer is bad and introduces a *lot* of misunderstandings. If ChatGPT or other automated response service was actually designed to provide correct and accurate answers, and did so the vast majority of the time, then that would be a completely different situation. We're just not there, yet, and *definitely* not there with ChatGPT.

Comment: Oh, and not to mention that ChatGPT isn't going to be free. Why should Stack Overflow pay to provide such answers to users? ChatGPT is, currently, free, as a trial, but OpenAI has every intent to monetize it as a service. Providing output that is "as you type" would *maximize* the number of calls to generate output and, thus, maximize the expense of getting that output.

Comment: @Makyen Agreed on "no concept of correct". And your second comment, totally, and well put. As for what SO pays for, how they allocate their budget isn't really something we can speak to, it just depends on whether or not it's worth it in some indirect way, which, I have no idea. But yeah, everything else, I'm also convinced now that this wouldn't work as a search-as-you-type content thing.

Comment: What if, instead of generating content, it was used to generate links to related answers as a hypothetical improvement over the current search algorithm? I'd be really curious also to see what happened if, instead displaying GPT generated content from your question, it displayed the related *search* results using the GPT generated content as input. So you -> GPT -> current search -> display results. Would that improve search results?

Comment: (Anecdotally, fwiw, the other day a coworker of mine asked ChatGPT to "generate an algorithm to register a point cloud to a surface model" -- if that doesn't make sense to you suffice it to say it's a topic my coworker and I know a lot about -- and it did indeed spit out a pretty solid and correct answer. I know it doesn't understand "correct". I'm not saying that's convincing, I'm just saying ChatGPT has generated decent content at least once, heh.) (PS I meant as for what SE* pays for, not SO, above.)

Comment: @JasonC "What if, instead of generating content, it was used to generate links to related answers as a hypothetical improvement over the current search algorithm?" You might want to search (ahem) how ChatGPT handles scientific references, which are practically the same task. There is a good Q&A on academics.SE, for example. TLDR: ChatGPT literally makes up references/links. As a language model, it does not understand that a) they have to point somewhere and b) that the content pointed to must be relevant; it only knows what links should read like.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In my comment, in the second part ("I'd be really curious also to see..."), [I meant this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HUMD.png). The top diagram there is the "request links directly" idea, which you're pointing out as not very good.  The bottom diagram there is an alternative that I think might be interesting; essentially using GPT as an intermediate "translator" pre-filter between whatever a human types in and whatever query is run through the SE search, to try to improve search results by basically translating human text to a longer string of well-formed relevant key phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like something along these lines (debatably) has been implemented (can be enabled in [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/#labs)):

[image]

I haven't really played with it much yet, though.

Answer (score -7):

I believe what you're proposing is a cul-de-sac enhancement that has much less value than you might think.

**(A) ChatGPT might be a temporary complement to Stack Exchange/Overflow. But it will eventually become a replacement.**

I believe too many people are viewing ChatGPT as a tool with little better value than Wikipedia. The potential of ChatGPT is enormous — but that enormity means it will eventually become the place to ask questions. Not the place to get information for answers on Stack Exchange.

That's not necessarily a bad thing. Don't get me wrong, despite our somewhat rocky relationship, I'm fond of Stack Exchange. But all technologies become obsolete. AI-driven knowledge bases are the next logical step. And once they become practical, the value of Stack Exchange drops considerably. In fact, the day Google decides to use the output of ChatGPT in its results will be, IMO, the beginning of the end of Stack Exchange.

But if you think about it, *that's desirable.* Well, maybe not for the business of Stack Exchange, but as far as the world's access to well correlated information is concerned, it's *definitely* what the future wants to see.<sup>1</sup> Especially if it can do it in one's native language. Right now, SE is still very much in the English-speaking world.

**(B) IMO, if SE has a sense of duty to the future, what the company should be doing is giving ChatGPT its own voice.**

This might have been suggested by others. It also might be deemed radical and an antithetical desire for the future of Stack Exchange, but what I believe Stack Exchange should do is work with ChatGPT's programmers to integrate ChatGPT as a unique user with access to all Stacks.

Why?

Because allowing ChatGPT to participate as a respondent for (and this is breathtaking) *all questions asked throughout the network* (with the possible exception of Meta... but I'd even let it respond here) gives the ChatGPT programmers unique and invaluable resources:

- Millions of users who can indicate whether or not ChatGPT's answers were useful.
- Access to *selected answers* that either validate ChatGPT's quality or allow the programmers and/or software to evaluate why another selected answer was deemed better.
- A hierarchy of curated answers demonstrating a sweep of quality and value.<sup>2</sup>

Of course, for this to work really well, it would be valuable that *no other account* be allowed to post ChatGPT-generated answers. That would reduce the value of the effort by clouding the results.

I can also imagine the problem of discovering the "user" representing ChatGPT, which might (OK, would...) cause human users to react in a biased manner toward its responses.

But I can't personally think of a faster way to help ChatGPT develop in a real-world context. And if its developers haven't asked the Staff for this opportunity, I can't imagine why.

But, ChatGPT will become competition for Stack Exchange, so I can imagine why the Staff would say no.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *Can you imagine a day when an instructor, planning a course's syllabus, can go to something like ChatGPT and ask it to develop **a unique textbook for that syllabus** based on the latest research in the field? Maybe I'm an unimaginative simpleton, but that blows my mind.*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *Note, however, that since all questions on all Stacks are entirely public, the ChatGPT people might already be doing all of that without the added benefit of a lot of experienced humans contributing to the validation process.*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *Well... Stack Exchange might also want to avoid giving birth to Skynet....*</sub>

Comment: I have a feeling that this answer missed what (Chat)GPT is. It is *very* far away from the expert knowledge that SE gives access to. The difference is not one of requiring more training data and/or feedback but fundamentally about design. It’s not the next logical *step*, at the moment it’s a huge leap into the dark.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Not at all. It doesn't matter if ChatGPT is months away from becoming an expert knowledge base such as SE gives access to or a century, I believe my answer still stands. Although the phrase "next logical step" might have been somewhat wishful thinking. (It's worth pointing out that if ChatGPT is the huge leap into the dark you suggest, then it should be absolutely and permanently banned for being untrustworthy to anyone who couldn't answer the question without its help.)

Comment: Why is it that all people I've seen arguing for integrating ChatGPT completely miss what **Chat**GPT is about. It's not a wise sage giving advice. It's a chat bot. A very well-made chatbot but really not a knowledge. Some of the answers it gives are correct but some are *staggeringly* wrong. Yet are worded in a way that many non-experts can be fooled. This is the real problem - in order to get a useful answer, you need to know what it is. I once asked ChatGPT "Is Germany a landlocked country" and it confidently said "yes", then described how it borders the North sea and the Baltic sea.

Comment: @VLAZ *Today* some of the answers are staggeringly wrong. I have no illusions about what ChatGPT is today, nor any (as others appear to have) about what "it" (whether it's ChatGPT or a descendant) will be used for in the future. It's going to replace humans on the other side of help chats, with an voice synth, it will replace humans in phone help centers. It will replace SE. It's foolish to assert that because we're at the beginning of the path that the end isn't obvious. And my point is that integrating it will help with its development. After all, nothing says "that's wrong" like -20.

Comment: I do not have any confidence that the answers will be judged by their merit. We already have *a huge* problem with that where answers that *seem* correct but are bad still receive positive reception. Once an answer gets some positive traction, it's almost impossible to reverse it. [Check my recap of a bug that stems from an SO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385005) (after the third quote). The answer was completely wrong for 4 years (3 of which had the comment that pointed out the problem) before it got an edit that introduced correct code. By that time it was at +11 / -7.

Comment: @VLAZ Claiming (and rightfully so) that humans can't consistently rank the quality of answers is a great reason to down vote my answer! But it also underscores my claim that, eventually, this technology will replace SE. Eventually it will become more trustworthy than humans. Maybe not in my lifetime. But I've seen amazing things in the last 55 years. +1-1=0?

Comment: I've not claimed that there is no future for the technology. Just that integrating ChatGPT, in its current state, is doing users a disservice. Because it's not a knowledge base. Again, it's a chatbot. It's in the name. It's good for longer conversations, one-off questions can give different results than if you had a conversation around the topic.

Comment: @JBH While „AI“ may reach the point you allude to in the future, (Chat)GPT won’t. It’s fundamentally not built to and no amount of catering to it will change that. *Eventually* another technology may be suitable but it is not here yet.  I for one welcome our future AI overlords and until they are here it would be nice if we did not taint the training data set that is SE.

Comment: I don't think ChatGPT / GPT-3 / GPT-x will ever become a *replacement* for SE sites. The GPT algorithm series isn't equipped to do the type of problem solving and self-evaluation that humans do (or that would be required of an AI in this situation). Also, GPT doesn't create *new* information, any information not in its training set wouldn't make it to its output; in particular, knowledge that humans have that isn't included in its training set wouldn't make it into its answers, whereas that information *can* make it to answers on SE. So, necessary information for an equivalency is missing.

Comment: In terms of problem solving and information availability, it's hard to compete with a few hundred million (or whatever SE's user base is) complex neural networks, each with a few decades worth of diverse training data, especially for an algorithm focused on text generation. :)

Comment: @JasonC I'm a EE, and there was a time in my career (back in the 1990s) when we EEs knew, *we knew,* that it was impossible to build a 1nm MOSFET gate. It couldn't be done, and the math supported it. Right up until some amazing people over at the Lawrence Berkeley National Laboratory [did it](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/10/6/13187820/one-nanometer-transistor-berkeley-lab-moores-law). What did I learn from that? Humans are *really, really good* at underestimating the future.

Comment: @JBH I didn't say AI wouldn't replace SE -- I'm not clairvoyant (although some futures are easier to estimate than others depending on background and context). I'm referring specifically to the GPT series of algorithms.

Comment: @JBH Btw, your MOSFET analogy is flawed. It is still provably impossible to build a 1nm MOSFET gate *out of the traditional materials that were always used for building MOSFETs*. What you really knew was that it wasn't possible, *at least not with current materials*. The EEs doing the math weren't wrong, that math still holds, and that future was estimated accurately. The Berkeley lab used different materials, just like a replacement AI would need a different style of algorithm. In your analogy, you compared MOSFETs to ChatGPT, but you should compare MOSFET *materials* to ChatGPT.

Comment: @JasonC That's sophistry. It was believed it was impossible to frost the inside of a light bulb until someone figured out how to do it. How it was done doesn't change what happened. The fact that in the 90s we couldn't foresee the development of materials that would overcome the limitations we knew to exist *is exactly the point I'm making.* Humans are really, really good at underestimating the future.

Comment: @JBH I think you should read about GPT a bit. :) My cell phone will never be a replacement for my printer. Maybe some day, cell phones will be replacements for printers, but mine never will. It doesn't even have a place to put paper. Maybe some day cell phones will have some high tech paperless way to print things. But this one that I have in my pocket right now won't. It's an accurate and straightforward "estimate". ChatGPT won't replace SE. Some other algorithm might. This isn't narrow thinking. It's more like how cheese will never replace cars, even though something might replace cars.