# People are using ChatGPT to answer my question, and I think this is inappropriate. Is it allowed?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

People are using ChatGPT to answer my question, and I think this is inappropriate.

I just saw a new user post an answer to my question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/39433/10189. While the author did tell me about this, I felt like it's still inappropriate.

Is this allowed?

Comment: best raised on [vi's meta](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for your suggestion. I [just did](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1591/10189) and extended my content there so it's not just a copy-paste. Regarding my post here, I was a little angry about this problem so I did it in a hurry.

Comment: flag it with a custom flag. Its a current ongoing network wide issue so visibility is a good thing

Comment: (Now posted [on the meta site](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/people-are-using-chatgpt-to-answer-my-question-and-i-think-this-is-inappropriat).)

Comment: If there is content which was just copy & pasted from ChatGPT and the post did not follow the referencing requirements, then the post is in clear violation of SE-wide policy. SE's policy is that copied content which you did not create **requires** that the user follow the [referencing requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). The staff [answer to: "Is attribution required for machine-generated text when posting on Stack Exchange?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384648/271271) makes it clear that the referencing requirements apply to AI generated text.

Comment: The requirement to follow the referencing requirements doesn't make it inherently inappropriate to use ChatGPT generated content. The company has [explicitly declined to make an SE-wide policy that is directly about permitting/rejecting ChatGPT content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002/271271), leaving setting such policies that are specific to ChatGPT to each individual site.