# What is the proper way to attribute Large Language Models (such as GPT-3) when posting on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, attribution

This is a follow up to [Is attribution required for machine-generated text when posting on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384647/is-attribution-required-for-machine-generated-text-when-posting-on-stack-exchang?noredirect=1&lq=1)

What is the proper way to attribute Large Language Models (such as GPT-3) when posting on Stack Exchange? Is it enough to mention it in the edit description or should the attribution be included in the post itself? Is there a specific format for attributions?

My question applies to both new posts and edits to existing posts, assuming the attribution formats must be different for both cases.

Update: see the edit history of this post for a sample attribution

Comment: How can you put it in the edit description when you post an answer/question? It just needs to be in the body of the post, after you quote the text you copied from elsewhere.

Comment: @Luuklag you can start with a placeholder an edit it in later. I did it just now with my answer.

Comment: Is this only for edits, or in general? I did post [an answer containing ChatGPT's responses](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/249548/44325) and just mentioned it. I couldn't source further references for the content because it was spouting nonsense though.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. for both edits and new posts, assuming the attribution format is different for each

Comment: I think you should ask separately for edits vs for new posts, as those sound like two different questions to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For edits, I think mentioning use of the LLM in the edit description is sufficient.  If there are concerns about an edit, it is in a place where someone would naturally look when reviewing the edit.

For new posts, I think it should be attributed in the post itself (e.g., at the end of the post).