# Please update /help/referencing on all sites to reflect the Stack Exchange policy that machine-generated text requires attribution

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, copyright

On December 12, 2022, [animuson clarified that the rules surrounding plagarism on the Stack Exchange Network apply to all content not created by the poster, even if the work is otherwise not copyrighted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384648/572). This is specifically important to machine-generated content.

The [/help/referencing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) page is not editable by moderators and is universal across all sites in the network. Since the policy laid out by animuson is also universal and considered Network policy, this should be reflected somewhere other than a Meta Stack Exchange post.

Although sites may have additional rules or policies around the acceptability of machine generated text, the baseline rule that minimally requires attribution for the content should be captured in the Help Center.

Answer (score 6):

This has been completed as of February 22, 2024. Please see more details on [this separate post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396626/208518) where I covered this and other changes. As per the suggestions on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/396652/208518), further changes to that page are on my roadmap to implement.