# Will original answers but translated by AI receive the same treatment as answers spontaneously generated by AI?

Tags: discussion, answers, localization, chatgpt

As announced on [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned), the use of content generated by ChatGPT is temporarily banned.

It was stated in [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

> Stack Overflow is a community built on trust. The community trusts
> that users are submitting answers that reflect what they actually know
> to be accurate and that they and their peers have the knowledge and
> skill set to verify and validate those answers. This trust is broken
> when users copy and paste information into answers without validating
> that the answer provided by GPT is correct, ensuring that the sources
> used in the answer are properly cited (a service GPT does not
> provide), and verifying that the answer provided by GPT clearly and
> concisely answers the question asked.

As a native Portuguese language user, I frequently use translation tools to translate content generated by myself into languages such as:

- English.
- French.
- German.
- Spanish.

Recently, I have started to incorporate the use of ChatGPT into my translation tools and have obtained good results.

My questions are:

- Are answers generated in the user's native language but translated by Artificial Intelligence included in the prohibition of ChatGPT?
- What precautions should be taken when publishing original content but translated?
- Is it necessary to inform that the answer was translated through AI tool?
- Is it necessary to provide a link to the original content?

Comment: ChatGPT will give lovely translation that look beautiful, shining with pure light, very friendly, but contain glaring and fatal errors that only one that really understand the target language will be able to spot. Friendly tip: stay away from it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide)

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of "[Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396/271271)", because that question and staff answer make it crystal clear that *there is no Stack Exchange Network-wide policy* regarding AI generated content being acceptable, other than that [AI generated content requires attribution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384647/is-attribution-required-for-machine-generated-text-when-posting-on-stack-exchang/384648#384648). Thus, this question can *only* be answered with respect to a single site.

Comment: So, if you want an answer about this issue for Stack Overflow, then you need to ask on Meta Stack Overflow. If you want an answer about this issue for other sites, then you need to ask about it on the child meta site for that site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally moderators and other interested users can spot AI generated output once they've seen enough of it and there are detectors that aid in that. If a post is flagged as AI output and the various AI output detectors confirm it then moderators will delete it and likely suspend you too.

The problem with ChatGPT is that it generates plausible text so if you need to use it to generate output in a language you're not familiar with then you're not going to know whether the translation is accurate or just grammatically correct nonsense.

There are plenty of specialist translation services that are not based on ChatGPT or other similar technology so use them instead if you must. If you do so you do need to indicate that the original text is yours but it was translated by computer. I'd be quite wary of doing that because if you get comments on the answer you'd need to be able to understand and respond to them i.e. translate both ways.