# Where to ask / migrate questions about ChatGPT

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, migration, chatgpt

TLDR: The original intention of this post was to work as a "sign post" to point people looking for a site recommendation about ChatGPT:

[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691)

But just closing as duplicate might not be good, so here I'm briefly sharing a story and asking a question...

---

Recently there was a question about a problem using ChatGPT that was migrated from the original site to two other sites but those migrations were rejected. Despite how the migration was handled and the things that might require improvements, like the help articles about what is on topic and what do not ask, those looking for guidance about where to ask/migrate a question about ChatGPT, IHMO, should start by reading the above [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) but it might be hard for most people to understand which is the proper site, so I asked on Artificial Intelligence Meta the following question

- [Are questions about specific web apps, i.e. ChatGPT, on-topic on AI?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2909/42632)

The summary is that questions asking how ChatGPT works could be asked there, but questions about using it not.

The "good news" is that questions about using ChatGPT, with some limitations, might be on-topic on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).

Examples of off-topic questions in Web Applications

- How to install [ChatGPT](https://github.com/acheong08/ChatGPT) (a third party GitHub project)
- Troubleshooting ChatGPT (i.e. unexpected thread deletion related to network errors)

Do you have examples of kind questions about ChatGPT, other than using ChatGPT to answer questions on SE sites, that might be pointed to other SE sites, i.e. <s>Stack Overflow</s>, Data Science, Cross Validated?

P.S. Please don't migrate bad questions and if you decide to migrate a question assure that the migrated question has a good tag on the destination site (it has other tags than [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged))

---

Asking questions about ChatGPT on Stack Overflow

[Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/1595451) prohibits the use of content generated by ChatGPT, this means besides using ChatGPT content to answer questions the following is banned too:

- Asking for help to fix code generated by ChatGPT
- Asking for help to elucidate what is the correct between two or more ChatGPT responses to the same question
- ...

Since ChatGPT doesn't have an API, I'm wondering if there is anything that might be OK to ask on Stack Overflow about ChatGPT.

---

Related

- [Troubleshooting guidance](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3799/88163) (Web Applications)
- [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/289691)
- [A proposed philosophy of question migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285467/289691)
- [Asking about ChatGPT without using content generated by it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422165/1595451)

Answer (score 4):

Besides the options presented in the previous answer, with the latest available information, ChatGPT-related questions (questions about ChatGPT itself) might get an answer on *[GenAI](https://genai.stackexchange.com/)*.

Answer (score -5):

- If about AI: https://ai.stackexchange.com, http://stats.stackexchange.com/ or http://datascience.stackexchange.com/. E.g., [How does ChatGPT know math?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38217/4)
- If about purely coding, SO. E.g., [ChatGPT API with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74783294/395857)

Comment: The question is not on topic on AI since their mod tried to migrate it several times. It is not about programming so no SO. I see no evidence it would be on topic for the other sites, since it's a question about an error that people are getting with the website.

Comment: @Laurel maybe not the best example indeed if we look at the question body. I changed the example.

Comment: I'm talking about the question that was [closed on AI](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38268/42632) and mentioned in a meta post linked in the question.

Comment: @Laurel why not move it to webapps SE?

Comment: That was the other site where the migration was rejected (by Rubén closing it). The web apps meta q about troubleshooting above is why.

Comment: @Laurel I see. Then move to Reddit or OpenAI discord.

Comment: Strictly ChatGPT hasn't an API. The enpoint used in the referred question in SO uses and endpoint that belongs to [Open AI API](https://openai.com/api/) - https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions (I just edited the title and body of the SO question)

Comment: @Rubén Announced yesterday by OpenAI: [OpenAI ChatGPT API Waitlist](https://share.hsforms.com/1u4goaXwDRKC9-x9IvKno0A4sk30).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thank you very much.