# Is there a list of ChatGPT or other AI-related discussions and policies for our sites?

Tags: support, answers, etiquette, specific-site, chatgpt

Lately, the use of [ChatGPT](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/) on the network has become controversial, with Stack Overflow [completely banning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) using *generated text for content* and several other sites considering bans.

Could we get a list of threads and policies so that we can all get a high-level view of what is going on both network-wide and in different corners of the network?

Comment: Related [Where to ask / migrate questions about ChatGPT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384797/289691)

Comment: I want to thank you for this question, and you & everyone who's contributed for the answer here. I've been looking through these discussions on a semi-regular basis. It has been _immensely_ valuable for understanding the broader opinions, how they vary from site to site, and how they evolve with time.

Answer (score 77):

This answer is a community effort. Please edit in links from your site's Meta!

---

### Meta Stack Exchange

- Pro: [Could ChatGPT be a viable way to answer people's questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384355)
- Con: [Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396)
- Stack Exchange's guidance to site moderators on issuing suspensions related to AI-generated content: [What is the network policy regarding AI Generated content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389582)
- [Is attribution required for machine-generated text when posting on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384647)
- [Should ChatGPT be banned on MSE itself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385710/should-chatgpt-be-banned-on-mse-itself)
- [Examples of ChatGPT being right and wrong on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390348#390348)
- [How accurately could one differentiate between simple copy & paste of AI generated content and improved and fact checked AI generated content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390324/how-accurately-could-one-differentiate-between-simple-copy-paste-of-ai-generat/390362#390362)
- [Is uncited LLM usage considered a CoC violation under the Inauthentic Usage policy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393679)

---

### Per-site metas

| Site | Meta Post(s) | Main result | Answer banner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3D Printing | [AI generated content is problematic](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571) |  |  |
| Academia | - [Should this site take an official position on answers generated by ChatGPT?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5219) - [Automatically-generated text is banned on Academia.SE](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5225) |  | [In favour](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5402/165557) |
| Amateur Radio | TBD. |  |  |
| Android Enthusiasts | [How should we treat ChatGPT (and other AI-generated) posts?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2721) |  |  |
| Anime & Manga | [How should we treat ChatGPT (and other AI-generated) posts?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4567) |  |  |
| Arduino | TBD. |  |  |
| Arqade | [Should we ban AI-generated content on Arqade?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16663/) |  | [In favour](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16993/297372), [enabled](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/49888) |
| Artificial Intelligence | [Please do not post AI-generated content as actual posts](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2905) |  |  |
| Arts & Crafts | [What is the Arts & Crafts site policy for AI-generated content?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/620) |  |  |
| Ask Ubuntu | - [Ban ChatGPT and AI-generated answers on Ask Ubuntu?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20185) - [Announcement: AI generated content is now permanently banned on Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20209) |  | [In favour](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20436/1624654) |
| Astronomy | [Should we at least temporarily ban chatbot-generated content (e.g. chatGPT) until it becomes clearer what it means for Stack Exchange?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/890) |  |  |
| Blender | [Should posts generated with the help of AI be marked as AI-generated content?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3018/) |  |  |
| Bicycles | [Proposed ChatGPT Ban](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1506/proposed-chatgpt-ban) |  |  |
| Biology | [Ban ChatGPT and AI-generated answers on Biology.SE](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4323) |  |  |
| Chemistry | [What is official policy toward AI generated content on Chemistry SE?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5277) |  | [In favour](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5400/129302). [also this](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5394/129302). [enabled](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/12603) |
| Chess | [Acceptability of ChatGPT generated answers on Chess SE](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1171/26335) |  |  |
| Chinese | - [Do we want to allow answers written wholly by e.g. ChatGPT?](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1963) - [Examples of an AI (Sage) answering questions at Chinese.SE [reference post]](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1965) |  |  |
| Christianity | [Are you using AI to answer questions here?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7369/) | Banned | [In favour](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7369/are-you-using-ai-to-answer-questions-here?answertab=scoredesc#comment18310_7369) |
| Code Golf |  |  | [Not needed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26260/115091) |
| Code Review | [What Site Policy should we have for code written by ChatGPT?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10855/125403) |  |  |
| Community Building | TBD. |  |  |
| Cross Validated | [What to do about answers written by ChatGPT](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6422) |  | [Opted out](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6636/) |
| Cryptography | [What should our policy on AI-generated answers be?](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1642) |  |  |
| Data Science | [On AI-generated answers](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2637/54678) |  |  |
| Database Administrators | [Are ChatGPT answers allowed here?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3506) |  |  |
| DevOps |  |  | [meta discussion](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/397/38667) |
| Earth Science | [Should we define an ESSE AI-use policy?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1996/should-we-define-an-esse-ai-use-policy?cb=1) |  |  |
| Electrical Engineering | - [Should questions about ChatGPT responses be closed?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9793/) - [How can users who were suspended for posting alleged ChatGPT answers appeal the suspension?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9833/) |  |  |
| English Language & Usage | [Announcement: AI generated answers are officially banned here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15500) |  |  |
| English Language Learners | - [Is it on topic to ask about English advice given by ChatGPT?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/is-it-on-topic-to-ask-about-english-advice-given-by-chatgpt) - [Are answers written by AI Chatbots suitable for the site?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5878/are-answers-written-by-ai-chatbots-suitable-for-the-site) |  |  |
| Ethereum | [Accounts farming rep using chatGPT](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/724) |  |  |
| French Language • Langue française | [FSE Policy on AI?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/908) |  |  |
| Gardening & Landscaping | [What is the Gardening and Landscaping position on posts generated by ChatGPT?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/968/7298) |  |  |
| GenAI | [Is it acceptable to post AI-generated answers?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10/806) |  |  |
| Geographic Information Systems | [What is our policy on AI-generated content in GIS SE?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5389/29431) |  |  |
| Graphic Design | [Are artificial intelligence answers permitted?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3834/41100) |  |  |
| History | [Should there be a policy on History SE for the use of AI-generated answers?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4402) | Banned | [Requested](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4482/60097) |
| History of Science and Mathematics | [What is HSMSE policy on ChatGPT?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/413) |  |  |
| Home Improvement | [Can we get the "No AI" banner enabled?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/can-we-get-the-no-ai-banner-enabled) | Banned | Requested |
| Interpersonal Skills | [How do we deal with chatGPT generated answers?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4099) |  |  |
| Japanese | [Are AI-generated answers banned?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/are-ai-generated-answers-banned) |  |  |
| Latin | [Why are you banning chatGPT answers?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/640/why-are-you-banning-chatgpt-answers) |  |  |
| Law | - [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) - [Does the ToS allow any third-party to run Turing-tests or otherwise unleash GAI-in-training onto our Stackexchange site?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1384) - [Do the recent and upcoming policy changes and subsequent moderators' strike affect how LawSE moderates AI content?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1749/48193) |  |  |
| Literature | [Does Literature [our site] have a policy on AI-generated content?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1824/17802) |  |  |
| Math Educators | [Guidelines for Questions Posted on Math Educators SE](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/773/23453) |  |  |
| Mathematics | - [What is our policy on AI-generated content?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35342) - [New user posts 8 answers, all likely AI-generated, in the span of 82 minutes; I think we either need or are close to needing an official policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35651) |  | [in favour](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36170/926489) |
| MathOverflow | - [ChatGPT strikes MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5531) - [Policy toward GPT-generated conjectures?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5645) |  |  |
| Medical Sciences | [Ban ChatGPT and AI-generated answers on MedicalSciences.SE](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1392) | [Banned](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1406) | [Yes](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1431) |
| Movies & TV | [How should we deal with AI-generated posts?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4983/1006) |  | [In favour](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4986/98509) |
| Music: Practice & Theory | [Discussion of content generated by machine learning, AKA "AI"](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3930/6070) |  |  |
| Open Source | [Should ChatGPT- and similar AI-generated content be banned?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/q/921/458) |  |  |
| Operations Research | [How do we handle AI-generated answers?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/375) |  |  |
| Parenting | [Policy on ChatGPT generated posts](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1494/316) |  |  |
| Personal Finance & Money | - [Should chatGPT created answers be banned on this site?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3080/22489) - [Use of chatGPT and other AI generators is banned](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3082/22489) |  |  |
| Pets | [Community poll: Do we want a banner warning against AI generated answers?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2427/community-poll-do-we-want-a-banner-warning-against-ai-generated-answers?cb=1) | Banned | [Yes](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2427/25617) |
| Physical Fitness | [What to do about AI bots](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/q/903/34721) |  |  |
| Physics | [Please don't use computer-generated text for questions or answers on Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14281) |  | [In favour](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14595/351695) |
| Politics | [Use of ChatGPT to provide answers](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6454) | Banned | [Yes](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6703/42309) |
| Programming Language Design and Implementation | [Should we ban AI-generated answers?](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/152/7) | [Banned](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/154/169) |  |
| Project Management | [AI-Generated Answers on Project Management](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/918/) | Standard policy - attribution required | [No support, but also no objections, for banner](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/930/30) |
| Psychology & Neuroscience | [Ban ChatGPT and AI-generated answers on Psych & Neuro.SE](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2633) |  |  |
| Puzzling | [Is ChatGPT allowed for solving puzzles?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/) |  |  |
| Retrocomputing | [ChatGPT- Yes or No?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1169) |  |  |
| Reverse Engineering | [StackOverflow states: "Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned" -- What should be our policy? Same or not?](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/429/16786) |  |  |
| Robotics | [Use of ChatGPT is inappropriate for Robotics questions](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1489/37) |  |  |
| Role-Playing Games | - [Should this stack ban ChatGPT?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12383/62294) - [Is it acceptable to use LLMs for improving the English of answers and questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12499/) | Banned | [No thanks](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12537/23970) |
| Science Fiction & Fantasy | [Should AI-generated posts be allowed?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13817) |  |  |
| Seasoned Advice | [Policy on ChatGPT generated posts](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3783) |  |  |
| Server Fault | [ChatGPT Answers Not Permitted](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9845/) |  |  |
| Signal Processing | - [Should ChatGPT answers be labeled?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/50076) - [ChatGPT answers](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1767/50076) |  |  |
| Skeptics |  |  | [meta discussion](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5019/66816) |
| Software Engineering | [Avoid using ChatGPT or other AI-powered solutions to generate answers to questions on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9448) | Prohibited | [Yes - answer banner](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9563/4) |
| Space Exploration | - [Shall we at least temporarily ban chatbot-generated content (e.g. ChatGPT) until it becomes clearer what it means for Stack Exchange?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2999) - [Should we accept questions about information provided by ChatGPT?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3006/8859) |  |  |
| Stack Apps | [AI generated content should NOT be allowed on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/10507) |  |  |
| Stack Overflow | - [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) - [New help center article and banner on the site about GPT-Generated content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421991) - [What should I do if I suspect that a question or answer is written by ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421988) - [How can we determine whether an answer used ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421880) - [Are questions about ChatGPT code okay to ask?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422064) - [Why was my answer deleted for using ChatGPT even when I didn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422066) - [Are answers written using machine translation or grammar correction tools considered 'AI-generated' for purposes of the ban on AI-generated content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424036/11107541) - [All questions on Meta Stack Overflow with the ChatGPT tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt), which includes several more questions | Banned | Yes |
| Stack Overflow на русском | [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12247) |  |  |
| Stack Overflow en español | - [cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5450) - [Política temporal: CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462) |  | [In favour](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5620/312662) |
| Stack Overflow em Português | [Conteúdo gerado por ChatGPT não é permitido na rede](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8842) |  |  |
| Super User | - [Should we ban ChatGPT on Super User?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14847) - [Use of ChatGPT is now banned on Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14862) |  |  |
| TeX - LaTeX | [Should AI answers be banned?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10049/should-ai-answers-be-banned) |  |  |
| The Workplace | [What is our stance regarding AI-generated answers?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7203/73791) |  |  |
| Travel | [ChatGPT on Travel.stackexchange](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8437) |  |  |
| Unix & Linux | [How do we want to handle AI-generated answers?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6021) |  | [In favour](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7184/550426) |
| Vi and Vim | [People are using ChatGPT to answer my question, and I think this is inappropriate](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1591) |  |  |
| Web Applications | [Should GPT / ChatGPT generated answers be banned?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4877) |  | [In favour](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5211/305006) |
| Worldbuilding | - [Should we ban posts using ChatGPT or similar software?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9991) - [Announcement: AI generated content banned on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10067/40609) |  | [In favour](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10328/100417), [enabled](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/35994) |
| Writing | [AI-generated answers are no longer allowed on Writing.SE](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2545/) | Banned | [Yes Please](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2588/33442) |

Comment: Candidate: *[Are all generative AIs banned?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422949/are-all-generative-ais-banned)*. The title suggests it is too broad, but maybe it isn't.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum not relevant anymore, it was closed as duplicate.

Comment: Are there any sites that affirmatively allow ChatGPT, or is it either banned or no explicit policy on all sites?

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard It was reopened.

Comment: @isaacg Your comment looks like a follow-up question. Such questions should be posted as new questions, not as a comment.