# Why hate Reddit and ChatGPT?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt, reddit

Does the Stack Exchange community hate Reddit?

I mean, Reddit is much better Stack Exchange. Isn't it high time to change our mindset? Stack Exchange is dying without any new questions and answers. I think we should learn from them rather than hate them. Moreover, why the hate on an AI who is helping people? I mean, I don't get it.

I will decide from your answers and comments if I should stay here or leave. Toxicity will result in me leaving.
Edit: science means debate so reddit is thousand times better than stack exchange because you get better understanding and answers there. Mostly specific and precise answers are found there but in stack exchange you get really normal level answer which is bokish type but not either that close to books.
Will not leave stack exchange because it is good and funny in its own way.

Comment: Sometimes listening a song helps. https://youtu.be/yuFuwXd-B9E

Comment: Well as a fan of Taylor Swift, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dkk9gvTmCXY seems appropriate too

Comment: 11,329 new questions and answers were added to just the Stack Overflow site yesterday.

Comment: Do Stack Exchange community hate Reddit? No. Do redditers hate SE? I don't know nor care.  Common theme seems to be: Active participants on one platform but not on the other declare war without any substantial evidence, rumors at best. A popular way to kill time. I can only hope our meta-sites provide a safe place where both believers and non-believers can share their opinions and find a common ground, if there is one. Otherwise both platforms can co-exist. In peace, not pieces.

Comment: Reddit can sometimes be better; surprisingly it often covers [the long tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail#Chris_Anderson_and_Clay_Shirky) better than Stack Exchange (due to the gamification, tending to ***only*** cover beginner questions (contrary to the design intent of Stack Exchange)). Say, detailed information about technical problems with mechanical keyboards (ought to be on Super User), but it is a different kind of trash (there ***is*** gold in there, but it is often buried in pages and pages of chitter-chatter - all the traditional problems with forums).

Comment: Re *"Toxicity will result in me leaving"*: The classic rage quit post. I think you have already made the decision.

Comment: Do we hate reddit or forum sites? I guess it depends who you ask. From the [writing.se] site's `/help/on-topic` page: "_This is not a web forum. \[...\] a forum is for posing questions that are intended to spark discussions, whereas Stack Exchange is for asking specific questions that can be answered definitively and clearly. **Forums are awesome, and we love them!** But this is a place for focused questions and answers. So while "what should I write" is a fine question for a forum, it won't attract clear, definitive answers here and so does not fit our format._" (emphasis added).

Answer (score 28):

> Do Stack Exchange community hate Reddit?

Uh, we don't hate Reddit, but we also don't do the same thing. Reddit is closer to a set of discussion boards, with threading and such. We're a Q&A site and our model is *fundamentally different*. We're more focused on the topic on the main sites, and the 'social' and 'discussion' angles are covered elsewhere.

> I mean Reddit is much more better Stack Exchange.

Uh... "Reddit is a better Q&A site"? Not really. See above.

> Because Stack Exchange is dying without no new question and answers.

[image: "Citation needed" imagery from XKCD]
<sub>[XKCD 285](https://xkcd.com/285/)</sub>

> I think we should learn from them rather hate them.

The current Vice President of Community Management at Stack Exchange used to work for them, so I think we're good there.

> Moreover why the hate on a AI who is helping people?

Cause people misuse it. They just literally copy and paste things they don't try themselves. A lot of it is plausible but useless, and it wastes people's time. [SE *declined* to ban ChatGPT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide). [Every single community here that banned it did so because it caused them problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384922/is-there-a-list-of-chatgpt-discussions-and-policies-for-our-sites).

> I will decide from your answers and comments that should I stay here or leave. Toxicity will result me leaving.

Uh, do as you feel is best but sometimes if something doesn't give you joy... well, walking away isn't a bad idea. That said, I'm not sure what threatening to leave will accomplish.

Comment: You said everything I thought to say and more. Only thing I would add is a link to [What about the community is "toxic" to new users?](/q/342779) in response to the last quote.

Comment: For the "citation needed" on SE dying, it's quite true that the influx rate of new good questions and contributors for some smaller sites is low, but they've probably always been like that since beta, so I wouldn't take that as evidence of them dying. I'd wager/hope they're growing very slowly. (data needed)