# What is the false positive rate of GPT detectors for content on the SE network?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, chatgpt

I read in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389583/178179) written by  [Philippe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/936316/philippe):

> We've also identified that current GPT detectors have an unacceptably high false positive rate for content on our network and should not be regarded as reliable indicators of GPT authorship

What is the false positive rate of GPT detectors for content on the SE network?

Comment: There’s a lot I would like to know about their methodology here.

Comment: If only we could get an answer to [Can we please get more information on the "network policy regarding AI Generated content" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389595/997587), which already asks for this info: "_Numbers and methodology please._"

Comment: Are you planning to train one? I know a user who has a lot of training data.

Comment: It's different for each one. It also depends on what you consider a "positive" result (i.e. what result level actually indicates the text really is AI generated) from each one. What's *really* indicative of a positive result is quite different between different detectors.

Comment: At least on Stack Overflow, it has long been known to moderators (before staff ever brought it up) that many of these detectors suffer from severe accuracy issues and cannot be relied on as the sole basis for moderation action.  I am not aware of any moderator who has relied on them as more than one signal among many, and one moderator who's handled a lot of our AI-content flags has said that they ignore the detector results entirely in their assessments.

Comment: @W.O. actually, I do believe there was a study made. The problem isn't whether there was a study—that, I don't doubt—it's whether the study was well designed and what conclusions can be drawn from its results. But I'm sure they did run a few detectors on a large selection of SE posts and found a high false positive rate there. That isn't news, nor is it controversial. Anyone who's used these tools know they have a very low accuracy. Which is why mods never depended on them.

Comment: What *is* unclear is what statistical evidence supports an inference that *actual moderator actions* were taken with an unacceptably high false-positive rate.  **That** is the the study I would like to see.

Comment: Fair enough, I need to get a bit more clued-up in what they're trying to do. @terdon

Comment: What if someone uses gpt to take their legit answer and improve the verbiage. Would that be banned?

Comment: @SurpriseDog Yes, per Stack Overflow's policy, that is banned. The policy bans *all* use of generative AI to generate content posted on Stack Overflow. (We feel [communal editing is the best way to polish posts from those with limited English skills](//stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions). I cannot speak for the policies adopted by other SE sites, as the company refused to establish a consistent, universal policy, which led to scattershot policies being invented on a per-site basis, and, thus, led directly to unnecessary confusion and seemingly arbitrary enforcement/implementation.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The duplicate asks for information from the company about the policy and their reasoning. This question simply seems to ask for the truth. While there is overlap this question here is important enough to warrant its own answers. For example if a third party estimates the false positive rate somehow, it can be posted here not there.

Comment: This could remain closed, as it can be (has been?) answered elsewhere: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389621/282094 and a post suggesting that the accuracy isn't sufficient: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide/384468#comment1282259_384396 (Network -wide ban declined).

Comment: @Rob My gut-feeling is that this question here would like to have quantitative reliable information as answer. In your links I cannot find that. If it's not there I would say that this question hasn't been answered so far anywhere.

Comment: @Rob Exactly. "Show us the data" is a question directed to the company. This question here doesn't ask anything from the company specifically and anyone could answer it. And there is no answer yet. I don't see any estimated false error rates anywhere (maybe I overlooked it?). I wouldn't count "it varies" as satisfying answer.

Comment: @Trilarion, This question has been through the review process and the majority agreed with me, you have not met the threshold for reopening. There are FAQs here about: Closing, Reopening, and Reviewing, if we are wrong that's what we need to know; with a link to the FAQ, and a sentence quoted where we should start reading from.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, but no need for explaining to me how SE works, I know that all enough myself being here already so many years. I just explained my opinion.

Comment: @Trilarion, If that were true you'd know that the review is made without everyone's input, you can only ask for it to be overturned if you can clearly explain the error in the reviewer's (or moderator's) actions.

Comment: @Rob I always operated under the assumption that I can curate as I see fit (and don't have to explain myself). Community consensus is builtin by the restriction to a single vote per user for each question and aggregating over all contributing users. Right now I get the feeling that people simply aren't interested much in the false positive rate, because "company bashing" is currently more important, but that's just my impression and I'm happy to accept any community consensus while still standing with my opinion and vote.

Comment: @Trilarion, you are entitled to an opinion, and I've told you that I read it; maybe the other reviewers read it too, you are pinging Franck and everyone following with each comment. You don't have to explain yourself, but if you write a well written comment we are more likely to agree with you. Similarly we don't have to explain our review to you, I simply didn't want you to feel ignored, or that we denied your appeal for no reason.

Comment: @Trilarion, --- 2nd issue: You are entitled to flag, close, reopen vote - You were denied, your appeal of the decision has not succeeded, the reviewer's decision stands  --- In future you'll need to accept the review or use the contact link below. --- We, the reviewers, are not bashing anyone (except Franck's inbox); we review correctly as explained above and in the FAQs - as you've said needs no explaining.

Comment: @Rob I don't feel ignored, not even a tiny bit. I feel a bit stalked though. I have no idea who "we" are and why you are sending me these comments. I do not really understand what you want to tell me in all the comments. I'm wondering if any action from my side is required but I don't think so. I think you are wasting your time with me. To get out of this loop, why don't we just move on with our SE lives? :)