# Hot meta posts section is no more?

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, hot-questions, community-bulletin

I was browsing Stack Overflow for tags of interest-related questions and I noticed that there was no 'hot meta posts' section on the right side! I navigated to the corresponding meta and found the same.

Comment: Seeing them gradually disappear from sites is expected - sorry, as the cache refreshes at slightly different times on different sites, the content will go missing when the refresh happens. We're seeing a bunch of exceptions coming from the hourly refresh, so that's likely what's caused this.

Comment: Looks like SO's Bulletin is back - so whatever caused this seems to be ... coming around.

Comment: We had an issue with Redis that affected bulletins. I believe they're coming back now (might take a bit for all sites to update) and we're keeping an eye on things to make sure it stays that way.

Comment: Seems to be gone again

Comment: @dbugger Yep, both Hot Meta Posts and Featured are gone again for me. One has to wonder why these glitches never happen to the Blog section of the bulletin. 

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Or they do, but we never notice because nobody cares about the Blog.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thanks for your patience, the issue should be resolved now.

I unfortunately don't have any particularly juicy details to share about the underlying cause, but the short version is that we had a route that was hitting Redis when we didn't expect it to hit Redis and that ended up creating too much load in combination with our hourly scheduled routes.

As far as the bulletins go, they should self-correct over the next hour or two across the network.