# Featured posts on MSE are missing on the sidebar across the network

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-bulletin, featured-tag

On all sites, the questions [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) on Meta SE are no longer being displayed, even though [the tag remains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) on the two questions.

([Seems the same thing is happening with Hot Meta posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389886/hot-meta-posts-section-is-no-more), though I and some other users can still see them for whatever reasons.)

Comment: I have looked at this on all sites (I have a tool) and it's very hit-and-miss. Some sites have hot meta posts, others have featured meta posts... none have the network-wide featured posts. We're not sure what happened here but we are investigating to see what's up.

Comment: Happy to know that this is not intentional.

Comment: Featured posts have now returned.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship - probably a cache thing, but I don't see them on SciFi or on SO. (I see them in other places, though)

Comment: We had an issue with Redis that affected bulletins. I believe they're coming back now (might take a bit for all sites to update) and we're keeping an eye on things to make sure it stays that way.

Comment: @RandomPerson: I *wish* I could trust SE that this is not intentional. However, given that [Philippe has been manually removing the "featured" tag from meta threads discussing the current unpleasantness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389843/256777), the sheer timing of this "unintentional" disappearance of featured meta posts makes me very skeptical indeed. This absolutely looks more like a [Memory Hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hole) operation, and a singularly tone-deaf and inept one, but that is the SE style I have come to expect since 2019.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship - they're gone again.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yeah, the timing is very strange. Not to doubt what Adam said, but I really hope this is just a glitch and not caused by them trying to limit the visibility of featured/hot posts one way or another.

Comment: @CDR What did you think, that it'd always be here? The sidebar needs to sleep from time to time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for your patience, the issue should be resolved now.

I unfortunately don't have any particularly juicy details to share about the underlying cause, but the short version is that we had a route that was hitting Redis when we didn't expect it to hit Redis and that ended up creating too much load in combination with our hourly scheduled routes.

As far as the bulletins go, they should self-correct over the next hour or two across the network.