# Questions featured on per-site-metas no longer display on the sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, community-bulletin, featured-tag

[This](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/its-time-for-me-to-resign) post announcing the resignation of a moderator is [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) on meta.academica.SE, but it no longer displays on the main site as it should be doing.

Related:

- [Featured posts on MSE are missing on the sidebar across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389888/featured-posts-are-missing-across-the-network)
- [Hot meta posts section is no more?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389886/hot-meta-posts-section-is-no-more)

Per [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389888/featured-posts-are-missing-across-the-network?noredirect=1#comment1300843_389888) by [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija), it's a bug, and not intentional.

Comment: *tinfoil hat on*: Catija did not say it was unintentional, just that it was a bug. It can be both intentional *and* a bug. It’s a strangely convenient time for exactly that bug to occur.

Comment: If this is going to persist, I think the sites need to follow [what Academia SE did](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/196930).

Comment: @ThomasMarkovisonStrike As far as I can tell, redis is angry and throwing errors. It's a bug. It's not even that code changed or whatever... the data is just not being served properly.

Comment: Tagging this [tag:status-review] as well - for now, I'm assuming [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor), since I see them reappear on various sites already. For the record, [I'm supporting the strike too](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9522694#9522694).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed the very day it was reported. Though an answer wasn't posted here, it's most likely the same issue as that of the linked questions.

Adam Lear explained in [his](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389894/1278220) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389895/1278220) to the other reports:

> I unfortunately don't have any particularly juicy details to share about the underlying cause, but the short version is that we had a route that was hitting Redis when we didn't expect it to hit Redis and that ended up creating too much load in combination with our hourly scheduled routes.

So yeah.

<sub><sup>(Posting this based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/396049/1278220).)</sup></sub>