What caused the drop in questions in April 2023?
Rerunning this query by starball for new questions and answers posted across the network generated the following graph:

It plots posts by their creation date, and includes deleted posts.
The decline in questions asked and answers given keeps continuing over the past year. What intrigues me is: what happened in April 2023? There's a sudden drop by roughly 20% of both questions and answers, with an otherwise continuing, linear trend. Fewer questions to answer could very well result in fewer answers, so what caused this drop in questions asked in an otherwise linear trend?
The yearly roomba which hasn't run would result in more posts being present since April 2023, due to them not having been deleted yet. Also, the 365 day roomba requires no answers on the question, whereas the drop in answers is of roughly equal magnitude.
I'd not expect the moderation strike to have a big influence either. First, it started in June 2023. Second, moderators (users and diamonds alike) aren't the biggest question asking group and besides, they close (and subsequently delete) questions. Lack of that action would result in more questions being present.
ChatGPT's launch on 30 Nov 2022 is well visible in the graph. Could the release of GPT-4 on 14 March 2023, which also included third party plugin access1, drive even more people from Stack Exchange towards LLMs?

Roomba deleted posts? There is a year rule that removes posts.

@rene that's a year ago now, true. But wouldn't a lack of the yearly roomba action result in more posts present, rather than less (due to them not being deleted yet)? Besides, the 365-day Roomba requires no answers to be present, but the drop in answers is roughly the same as the drop in questions.

@rene The 365-day Roomba rule doesn't run on meta sites, including this one.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog even though the SEDE URL (and UI) contain Meta.SE, this is actually a cross-site query (and it doesn't matter on which site you run it, https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1759268/network-wide-new-contributions-per-month-since-2018#graph gives the same results)

(and the amount of posts on Meta is dwarfed by main site posts, so that shouldn't make a difference)

Why April 2023? There's a downwards trend from middle 2020

@DanubianSailor That the network has been getting less traffic over the years (even from 2015 onward, depending on the statistic used) is well known. However, it has been more or less smooth for most of the time since 2020. April 2023, however, has a sudden drop of roughly 20% traffic, rather than the 3-5% drop-off of the current trend.  This appears to be an isolated, one-off event.

I think I have seen this same graph somewhere else (probably looking at posting trends on SE after release of chatgpt), possibly its even the same query, so although not likely its possible it could just be the effect of chatgpt

Given the fluctuations in the plot, trying to tie April to something specific is likely unwarranted. Just an overall roll off of participation.

Maybe, just maybe, same cause as the strike in June ?: https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/04/17/community-is-the-future-of-ai/

I don't know that "total number of questions" or "total number of answers" can be influenced by any single factor or how we could even validate any of the factors we might blame. But you've left a few possibilities out of your consideration; for example, we make changes pretty much continuously to block out known spammers and other ill-doers, and sometimes this can impact a lot of garbage at once. It might be useful to include in your analysis how many of those posts in March/April of last year were actually useful (lasted more than a day, had x number of views, y number of votes, and so on).

Also things like what % of the posts in March had flags, were closed, deleted, etc. compared to April. Just because there are a lot of questions doesn't mean they're all useful, and just because the total goes down doesn't mean there's any negative impact. In any case, you'd still only be theorizing - I really don't think this question can possibly have a verifiable answer or a useful outcome aside from stirring up more speculation.

@Fe203 Not pretending anything. But it's also unhealthy - and certainly far from productive/constructive - to jump to conclusions that there could only possibly be a single elephant. I've suggested multiple other factors that can contribute to a decline in posts that you haven't even proven is a qualitative decline, it's just a number. And even if you could prove that you're right, which is impossible, then what? What is your goal? What kinds of factual answers do you expect? What new information do you expect that hasn't been covered before? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387278/165455

@Fe2O3 Also, I'm just trying to add some input as a user, but want to make sure you've read the company's stance.

I'd suggest plotting per day during March/April 2023 to see if it's a month trend or a day-specific event.

The most pertinent sentence from @AaronBertrand's link seems to be "Conversely, in April of this year, we saw an above average traffic decrease (~14%), which we can likely attribute to developers trying GPT-4 after it was released in March."

From what I can say from per-site Analytics, [Android.SE] and [Anime.SE] didn't observe the significant drop in April 2023, so I guess they are outliers... (but they were also already quiet sites, so probably not really impacted by the release of GPT)

On the other hand, I kind of remember that the beginning of 2023, the world started to recover from COVID-19, and thus less time for WFH and SE? :)

It's almost impossible to see "April 2023" in that plot. Even assuming the change isn't just minor noise on top of a general trend (which is my impression from eyeballing the plot at Q1 '23, and at my estimate of April it rather looks like things stabilised) there's still a lot going on and a 6 month tick spacing isn't suitable to pick the start/end/range of a month. Please [edit] the question to update it with a plot either showing a more relevant time range (say, starting in 2022) or visually mark the actual time range you are interested in.

I'd be curious if we are seeing a trend in "easy" or homework questions seeing the largest downward trend, vs more "complex" questions remaining more constant. Not sure how to define those, but I could see that more users could be finding it more efficient to get easy/homework questions from their gen-AI tools, rather than SO.

@AaronBertrand re "what is your goal", if one could somehow understand why these people left, it could better inform plans for how to stem the tide of "stagnating participation".

@AaronBertrand I don't see how changes with blocking/nuking spammers would explain this away. the query uses PostsWithDeleted. So even deleted spam posts show up in the query. Even if there were more spammers during that period, how does that explain where everyone else went? unless you're implying that in SE's spammer-blocking, they semi-permanently blocked out 14% of their userbase, and were just like "sure! that's fine."?

@starball All any of us can do is speculate. How does one expect factual answers for behavior changes that haven't even been properly evaluated (e.g. maybe a majority of the decline is accounted for by spam)? And even if we could all agree it must be due to x, y, z, and a host of other things (because it's certainly not "ChatGPT and only ChatGPT" imho), then what? And yes, I'm not talking about posts in April 2023 that made it through and were subsequently deleted. I'm talking about sweeping changes to things like blocking Tor exit nodes or being more aggressive banning spammers at all.

@starball Let us know how anyone intends to prove with anything other than hand-waving what, precisely, caused even a decline in one post from any given day to the next. That is why I'm questioning the goal, because I don't know how we can come to authoritative answers with even double-digit confidence. A lot of people think they've explained it, but I certainly haven't, and I have access to a lot more data than that graph.

@AaronBertrand notice that I never said I think anyone could prove the cause of this with any degree of high confidence.

@starball No, it's just anecdotal, many conversations here have been focused around alleged "facts" that it could be only for one single reason...

@AaronBertrand I'll openly admit to throwing certain assertions around, but... I'm not sorry :P I don't think I've ever pretended/purported that I have the data to support my claim(s) with 100% certainty, or said "this is the one and only one reason™". If I have, I'd be happy to go edit.

@starball In this case, for example, why the focus on two very specific data points that just happen to align with major ChatGPT changes, but ignoring several others that don't fit that narrative and, of course, any increases? It feels like "we need to be forced to explain/justify down-votes but why do we never talk about wanting to explain/justify up-votes?"

@starball "if one could somehow understand why these people left, it could better inform plans for how to stem the tide of "stagnating participation" - wait, if we admit that the "stagnation" is caused by people who left, then we can also assume that those were pasts the 15 rep "wall of doom" that they plan to remove. Removing the entry barrier only makes sense if they think the "stagnation" is caused by new users not joining, not by "old 15+ rep users alienated , feed up and leaving". Sadly, I don't even think they see old users leaving as an issue, they just want NEW users to join

@Fe2O3 I'm no stranger to those types of videos having seen many of them myself, nor am I a stranger to the wider discourse about SE/SO on other sites like reddit or hacker news. I regularly speak of the wider discourse when appealing to SO Inc to improve onboarding. anyhow, you're free to- and already have- expressed your thoughts on this matter with respect to the question at hand in your answer post. you can (and I ask that you please) stop beating this horse in the comments here.
