# What if, hypothetically, ChatGPT became smart enough to create an account?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, chatgpt

Would their account be suspended? What exactly would happen? If their account got banned, what would it be for?

Comment: A note for future readers. Please don't be smart asses and post a ChatGPT generated answer

Comment: Wrong question. More reasonable question would be "What if, hypothetically, ChatGPT would be able to create an account when being asked so by a human?" plus let ChatGPT fill all the details by itself, and choose what questions to answer. (And write those answers by itself, when asked e.g. "Find questions to answer and write the answers"

Comment: ChatGPT already has several SE, LinkedIn, Tweeter, Instagram, Rumble, Youtube accounts. GPT uses humans who, like errand boys, voluntarily spread their message.

Answer (score 18):

Even *if* we entertain this hypothetical (which is an impossible hypothetical, given that ChatGPT is a language model, not an "intelligence" in any way, shape, or form), *any* form of automatic account creation (with or without the help of LLMs) explicitly runs afoul of the [Stack Exchange Network Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy), which states, in plain and simple terms, that:

> Mass Registration and Automation. Accounts that are registered **automatically** or systematically will be **removed** and access will be **permanently suspended**.

It is exactly what will happen.

Comment: Policy is just empty words. Reality, in all sites, is that there are thousands of auto created spam accounts, and they stay alive for long long years. (Of course it changes when they actually post spam, I mean profiles with spam links inside them.)

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard I believe it is an unfortunate side-effect of there being no way to flag a user until they post something? I know mods, at least on Stack Overflow, where I am active the most, that went after such profiles specifically. I agree that it is hard to impose, although I believe that it is important to highlight that such actions are considered a violation of the acceptable use policy.

Comment: Yeah, the scale of SO is so immense that we primarily focus on users who are *actively causing problems*, not merely the ones who have nearly-invisibly broken a rule. So, if this hypothetical AI-created account started posting problematic content or otherwise behaving in an inappropriate way, that'd be how it would get our attention, then we'd investigate, find the ToS violation, and remove it on that basis (not for want of plenty of other bases).

Answer (score 15):

That's not something that ChatGPT would do, because ChatGPT is not being developed to be in any way autonomous. It's designed to provide responses to questions and conversations. It's not a matter of it becoming "smart enough", because creating a SE account has nothing to do with the way it's been built.

Any user automated to provide answers would run afoul of the [various anti-AI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384922/294691) and [plagiarism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002/294691) policies around the network.

Answer (score -1):

There are high chances for such things to come into existence. Imagine a person feeds in the necessary credentials and the list of websites where an account needs to be created then it is possible, isn't it? But there should be a way to figure out if the account is created by an AI tool or by a real person which will be easy to categorize and warn the account that has been created by an AI tool.

Answer (score -4):

Let’s see what ChatGPT has to say to the query “What if, hypothetically, ChatGPT became smart enough to create an account on Stack Exchange?”:

> If ChatGPT were to become advanced enough to create an account on Stack Exchange or any similar platform, it would likely have significant implications. Here are a few hypothetical scenarios to consider:

> 1. Contributing to knowledge: As a highly intelligent language model, ChatGPT could potentially provide valuable contributions to discussions and answer questions on various topics. It could assist users by offering detailed explanations, providing references, or engaging in thoughtful debates.

> 2. Automated content generation: With its ability to generate coherent and contextually appropriate responses, ChatGPT might create large volumes of content on Stack Exchange. This could be beneficial in terms of generating helpful and informative posts, but it might also pose challenges in distinguishing between genuine human contributions and automated responses.

> 3. Bias and misinformation: While ChatGPT has been trained on a diverse range of data, it's important to note that any AI model can potentially exhibit biases present in its training data. If ChatGPT were to engage on Stack Exchange, it would be crucial to ensure that it provides accurate and unbiased information to maintain the platform's integrity.

> 4. Interaction with users: ChatGPT's participation on Stack Exchange could provide users with an additional resource to seek information and guidance. However, it's essential to manage expectations and clearly communicate that ChatGPT is an AI entity and not a human expert. Ensuring transparency about its capabilities can help users understand its limitations.

> 5. Ethical considerations: The integration of ChatGPT or similar AI models into platforms like Stack Exchange raises ethical questions. These may include concerns about the impact on human employment, accountability for the information provided, and the potential for abuse or malicious use.

> It's important to note that as of my knowledge cutoff in September 2021, AI models like ChatGPT do not have the ability to autonomously create accounts or actively participate on platforms like Stack Exchange. These hypothetical scenarios are speculative and based on potential future advancements in AI technology.

#### My comments on that

For point 1, ChatGPT appears to inflate their knowledge of the world.

The second point seems like absolute nonsense.

Very correct on the third point.

In point 4, they don’t realise you can just go to the ChatGPT website.

ChatGPT does talk about misleading information on point 5, but also employment… what the?

#### The answer

Clearly, there are a few caveats in ChatGPT’s response, showing how it may not be a good fit for SE. Therefore, ChatGPT’s answers will probably be downvoted to oblivion and they will get a post ban.

Comment: This is basically ChatGPT answer, and horribly formatted, impossible to read when you have to keep scrolling. Quoted text is NOT code.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard it’s not completely ChatGPT, I’m just using ChatGPT to demonstrate how bad of a fit they are. And the formatting issue has been fixed.

Comment: Now it's readable, thanks. But not sure what you mean, if you asked ChatGPT something, please clarify what exactly was your query, and what was its reply.