# Add a warning about generative AI on other sites (only to sites which banned generative AI) of Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, answers, generative-ai

On Stack Overflow (only in English) there is the warning about generative AI answers:

[image: Warning about genAI-answers]

> Reminder: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).

Can you add this warning on other sites (only on sites which banned generative AI) of the Stack Exchange network? Don't forget please about localised sites (in [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), and [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)) — they need a new string in [Transifex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transifex).

Comment: IIRC this is/was an A/B test, so i'm not sure if they've even collected enough data to determine it's usefulness at this point considering the situation with moderators on SO, the AI Policy, and the number of unhandled flags.

Comment: Related: [Testing an "AI-generated content" policy banner on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426353)

Comment: This request is off-topic here on MSE. Requests for this banner must be made by *each individual site*, so should be requested either by the moderators of the site or through per-site metas. It is inappropriate to ask here for such changes to multiple sites. As was negotiated with Stack Overflow, see "[Moderation strike: Results of negotiations](/q/391847/271271)", the banner which you are asking about can be enabled/disabled on a *per site basis* and is customizable on a *per site basis* (so an entry in transifex is not appropriate, as the text is already defined per site).

Comment: @Makyen [MOST sites of SE banned genAI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384923/1346379). So this warning should be on MOST sites of Stack Exchange, this feature request is relates to MOST network site

Comment: @zcoop98 thanks for link. I tried find this on MSE, but I have forgotten, that this post is only on MSO.

Comment: @Зонтик Some sites, even those who banned generative AI, may not want the banner, such as if they don't experience such posts in a high enough volume (unlike SO). Most sites' members don't participate here, and any change that only affects a specific site must have consensus from within that site's community to be implemented.

Comment: Also, remember the [BEANS principle](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:BEANS). Telling someone not to do something may instead entice them to do that thing just to see what happens if they get found out.

Comment: @Makyen That seems to go against the entire idea of having a network Meta site. While the answer may be that every site needs to ask for this option individually, asking for the option to exist in the first place seems completely relevant here.

Comment: @Joachim What goes against the use of a network meta is trying to *impose* a feature onto all sites, or all sites in a particular category (e.g., all sites that have banned AI-generated content) where the response to the situation is *explicitly* decided on a per-site basis. There's a *huge* difference between asking for the capability for sites to decide on their own if they want such a banner enabled (something that was already agreed to by SE) and requesting that it be active on every such site, particularly when it's already designed to be decided and customized on a per-site basis.

Comment: @Makyen Ah, I had addressed that to the OP via a now-deleted comment (to turn the question into a "can different sites have the option to..?"), and they responded saying they changed it. Apparently they only changed it to indeed impose the feature on sites that ban gen-AI).. Then I do I agree with your assessment (but use a different close reason, as not seeking input).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update: See [Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/323179) which unfortunately doesn't give sites the option to customize the banner text.

---

Any interested moderators were encouraged to open a discussion on their own metas to discuss if they should have the banner on their site and if so, what it should say. This gives sites the option to explain the nuances of their own AI policy, and link to the resources most relevant to their site (namely the policies on their own metas).

If nobody has posted a discussion yet, you should feel free to post one yourself (even if you're not a mod).

(As an aside, because it's entirely customizable per site, there's no need for it to be in Transifex, as Makyen says.)

Comment: Done for Ask Ubuntu: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20403/57576

Comment: Were we? Maybe I saw it but I certainly don't remember it if I did.

Comment: @BryanKrause It was in chat somewhere. Very easy to miss.