# Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content

Tags: support, answers, announcements, chatgpt

#### February 22, 2024 Update

The help center articles have been rolled out network-wide. See [revision 15 of the February 7th post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396626/208518) for more details.

**If you're interested in enabling one of these banners on your site, please see the "How can I enable this on my site?" section near the bottom of this post.**

---

#### February 7, 2024 Update

I've created [a separate post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396626/208518) to get feedback on changes to an existing help center article, and a draft for a separate new help center article. It will be open for feedback for a week.

---

#### January 31, 2024 Update

**TL;DR:** The Community Team will work on drafting a network-wide Help Center article that explains that AI-generated content is prohibited unless it is posted with appropriate attribution, and then making the “answers must be cited” variant below the default option for all network sites. More details in the coming weeks.

[As was pointed out in the comment thread by Joe W](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera#comment1325120_395881) (thank you!), [our current Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) (more specifically, its [Inauthentic Usage policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage)) prohibits posting AI-generated content without appropriate attribution (explanation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393682/208518)). With that in mind, it doesn’t make sense that the “answers must be cited” variant, shown below as one of the possible two options for sites to opt-in to, would be optional. As such, we’ll be rolling out the “answers must be cited” option as the default for all Stack Exchange sites in the coming weeks. Sorry for the crossed wires on this, making for a slightly messier roll-out than originally planned.

Since a part of the originally proposed process for sites to request any of the two variants was that they’d need to agree on language for a Help Center article that explains their site’s policy on AI-generated content, before making that rollout, I’ll be drafting a Help Center article that’s supposed to be available on all network sites, and coming back to Meta Stack Exchange for feedback on it before publishing it. The idea is that that article would serve as the bare minimum for all sites, and sites would then be able to further tweak their policy to suit their needs, either by iterating on the “answers must be cited” policy, or by going through the request process laid out below to request the banner be changed to the “not allowed” variant instead.

I’ll make a separate post to gather feedback on the Help Center article draft, but will update this post once that’s up.

---

#### January 10, 2024 Update

The experiment has now been graduated, and the banner has been enabled on SO. Please see the bottom-most section of this question for more details on how to request it be enabled on your site.

---

#### tl;dr

We’ve recently run an [experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426353/testing-an-ai-generated-content-policy-banner-on-stack-overflow) to test a banner highlighting the “AI-generated content” policy on Stack Overflow. Next week we’ll be graduating the experiment that ran on Stack Overflow, and adding functionality to allow the "AI-generated content" policy banner to be enabled on Stack Overflow and all other sites in the Stack Exchange network. The variant group had no significant impact on answer rates; however, it did see a reduction in posts flagged for AI-generated content. Please see [the post on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426353/testing-an-ai-generated-content-policy-banner-on-stack-overflow) for more details on the experiment results.

The banner on SO looked something like this:

[image: Image showing the answer field, in focus, with a banner saying "Reminder: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. Learn more"]

#### Next steps:

- All sites in the Stack Exchange network will be able to opt in (the feature is off by default, network-wide)
- We will initially offer two banner text options that all sites in the Stack Exchange network can opt-in to. Those options are the following:

  - `**Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on [Site Name]. Learn more`
  - `**Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools must be cited on [Site Name]. Learn more`
- The banner will display once users select the answer field
- The [“new contributor” banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287) will no longer be shown in the answer field
- All users will see this banner when posting an answer with the option to dismiss. Once dismissed, logged-in users will not see this banner again

#### "How can I enable this on my site?"

If this is something you think your community is interested in opting into, please start a discussion in its Meta site to get community consensus on the appropriate course of action.

Both options have a "Learn more" link, which will point to a per-site help center article, whose contents should also be a part of the community discussion — this article should explain what the site's policy on AI-generated content is ([here's SO's article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy), as an example).

Once a consensus is reached, [escalate it to the Community Management Team by adding the [status-review] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca), so the team can assess the request.

---

If you have any questions about the process, please post them as an answer below.

Comment: If there's consensus on a per-site meta that we want the banner, what needs to be done to enable it? E.g. on [ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13138/215103).

Comment: Request it on that site's Meta, as per the last paragraph, and escalate it to the CM Team ;)

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed that we're stuck with pre-generated options, because I would love to also briefly mention the other rules of the site on such a banner (e.g., be thorough, don't plagiarize).

Comment: I’m curious as to the reason for requiring a new discussion for each site, about these banners, instead of just simply enabling them for sites which have banned AI-generated content. That is, the first paragraph for sites which have banned it, and the second one for the remaining sites.

Comment: Not all sites have a policy about AI-generated content (as far as I'm aware), @AndreasmovedtoCodidact, so the separate discussions ensure that each community has a policy that suits their own needs, and that proper guidance and documentation of that policy is created as a part of that process. Hopefully my latest edit makes that a bit clearer.

Comment: Hi, I present an observation regarding the placement of this banner and the corresponding effect. (The choice of the specific placement (inside the textarea) may end up contributing to an accusatory and distressing experience). I have already posted it in the AskUbuntu meta, I request that you look at it and consider it: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20408/1157519

Comment: _"All users will see this banner when posting an answer with the option to dismiss. Once dismissed, logged-in users will not see this banner again"_ probably this should require something like 20 points to be dismissable. But I'm just "thinking too loud".

Comment: Make this mandatory across all SE sites. Please.

Comment: @ElEctric Not all SE sites have agreed to ban AI-generated content, and even among those that have, some implement it more strictly than others. There isn't a unified network policy on this, hence no unified network banner.

Comment: It's not really artificial intelligence (which would be an incredible technological and sociological breakthrough). I do hope we get to have a say in the wording on our site if we go for this.

Comment: A banner would be great if it pops up only when and if one copies a chunk of characters. With this implementation, I worry that it would have the same effect as telling people that adblockers are forbidden — it notifies them that they are an option respectively. We shouldn't continuously notify people about AI options, but we should clarify our stance when we encounter a possible infringement — when someone copies and pastes their answer.

Comment: I am a little confused about the second option for requiring AI answers to be cited when another answer from a staff member suggests that answers that do not cite AI answers are violating the code of conduct. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393682

Comment: That is a good point, @JoeW — there might've been some crossed wires with communications here, internally. Gonna determine next steps internally and update once we have 'em. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393682/208518) answer your question, @Plusjamaisquoiencore? If not, I'd propose creating a separate question to ask for clarification on it, as the comment section here is a bit inadequate to go into any more detail than that answer already provides.

Comment: @JNat Thank you, I had read this before, so I gather it means "attribution" (to the AI). But it does not seem to include the attribution the AI might provide (accurately or not) to the content it is outputting. Furthermore consider a X network user quoting content from SE with attribution and an AI being trained on this. It is not clear how the AI would attribute output based on this, but that's another question altogether.

Comment: Not only that. I would like to suggest that SE partner up with an AI-content checker tool so that we will be able to prevent the content from popping up.

Comment: @JNat Thank you for that update, it clears up my confusion.

Answer (score 48):

You've suggested two options for the banner's text, both written in English. I suspect that they will be allowed to translate via Traducir/Transifex. But the translation pipeline is still broken for non-English Stack Exchange sites, see  [Recently added translations don't reach the site again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395096/339911).

If it doesn't use the normal Traducir/Transifex pipeline, but works for instance like the text used for forbidden tags — through conversation with a community manager, we need somehow (on local Meta?) to propose translated versions for both or only for one selected option.

Anyway as a first step I would like to know how it expected to work on non-English sites.

Answer (score 41):

It would be great to also allow for a similar banner on the page where *questions* are composed.  Over on Physics.SE, we often get questions that are of the following form:

> Why is it the case that [false statement] is true? I asked ChatGPT about it and here's what it said:
>
> [paragraph that is actively misleading or false]
>
> Now I'm confused.

Such questions are also against [our site policy,](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14281/please-dont-use-computer-generated-text-for-questions-or-answers-on-physics) just like AI-generated answers are.  But if there's a "no AI" banner that shows up above the "answers" text entry box and not above the "questions" text entry box, it might lead new users to think that it's fine to ask questions about confusing AI-generated text.

Comment: Sounds like you should customize the [Ask Question popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/323179). (You should of course put more than just the AI policy in here—I suspect there are more common problems that askers are running into.)

Comment: Indeed, as Laurel pointed out the Ask Question page already has built-in, customizable UI that would address the concerns here — please see the link provided in Laurel's comment for details on how to request said customization.

Answer (score 13):

You note

> Both options have a "Learn more" link, which will point to a per-site help center article, whose contents should also be a part of the community discussion — this article should explain what the site's policy on AI-generated content is ...

Can sites link to a Meta post containing the policy instead? Like [this one](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20209/1438484) for Ask Ubuntu? Or does it need to be finalized into a Help Center article?

Comment: I think that each community can discuss the banner text and link in meta-site.

Comment: The link is hard-coded, @cocomac, so a help center article would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

*"generated by artificial intelligence tools"** is a broad description. The ["learn more"/AI policy page of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy) also talks of

> any answer crafted in part or in whole using a tool that writes a response automatically based on a prompt it is provided

So when we take this literally, this would effectively make it impossible to use contemporary translation services like DeepL or Google Translate, or grammar checkers for assistance, since those are AI tools as well which *write a response automatically based on a prompt*.

However, [this Stackoverflow Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424036/are-answers-written-using-machine-translation-or-grammar-correction-tools-consid) gives me the impression that translation tools are not prohibited in general, at least not when they are specialized on translations which preserve the original meaning. Moreover, the formerly mentioned AI policy page only contains examples in terms of LLM based services, and not translation tools or grammar checkers based on other kind of AI models. That leaves anyone like me - who is not an English native speaker and uses a translation service from time to time - in a very unsatisfying state of uncertainty if that is still ok or not.

I understand the desire not to restrict the AI ban to LLMs alone, since we do not know what new fancy kind of AI tool will hit the market next month, and if the term LLM will still fit to them, but when certain AI tools like translation services are allowed (maybe under certain restrictions), IMHO the AI policy pages should be clearer about that than the current Stackoverflow AI policy. Even in case translation services will be banned in general since they all fall into this broad interpretion of "generative AI", then the policy should state that as well.

Comment: This is one of those rules (like the rule against plagiarism) that get enforced arbitrarily because it is impossible to enforce at scale across all content. It's there so that sites have a reason to delete content they don't want, not because the community is going to try to hunt down all uses of AI and remove them. How would anyone know if you used an AI-based tool if you didn't tell them? If your post reads like it was written by a human, it's good quality, and you have a history of good posts, it won't be flagged. If you're a new user on a site, you'll have to be a little more careful.

Comment: @ColleenV: the current policy speaks about AI tools, but leaves translations tools completely out. By not saying one word about them this creates uncertainty among non-native English speakers like me about what is allowed and what is forbidden. That is IMHO quite unsatisfying.

Comment: I'm not saying the wording is good. I think it's kind of dumb to focus so hard on AI tools and not the problem the rule is actually trying to solve (people posting garbage that's difficult to curate). I'm just commenting that, in general, people who are worried about the quality of their posts and are engaging with the site in good faith probably don't have to worry.

Comment: @ColleenV: if *people who are worried about the quality of their posts and are engaging with the site in good faith probably don't have to worry*, why not mentioning this in the policy?

Comment: @DocBrown by the time we're done mentioning every such edge case the policy will be  10 answers long. If the avg reader reads your post and it reads like an ai generated answer, it's likely to get treated like one even if you are using the translation tool and not chatgpt directly.

Comment: @KevinB: "translation tools" are not an edge case.

Comment: @DocBrown they are similarly unclear though. One can easily call chatgpt itself a translation tool and not be entirely wrong. What of translation tools that can be broken to output answers? technically... translation tool was used... what's important is the intent and the outcome, moreso that the path that resulted in the answer.

Comment: @KevinB: absolutely, that's why I wrote *"tools specialized on translations which preserve the original meaning"* in my answer. I think it should be possible to find a wording that gives answerers a little more certainty that it is ok to use translation tools to a certain extent. It should probably not focus on the tool, but how the result should look like, and that the presented expertise should be the expertise of the answerer.

Comment: Is it possible for a translation service based on an LLM to not produce AI generated content? Would a user of said service be able to identify that distinction?

Comment: @KevinB: that's quite unimportant. My question is, is the phrase "AI generated content" - without any restrictions - a too broad description which overshoots the mark?

Comment: @DocBrown Why? It's the "AI Generated" part that we have a problem with. User generated content, that is spellchecked or grammar checked, even if the checking is done with AI, is fine.

Comment: @KevinB: is it? I thought your primary concern are LLMs - currently. AFAIK translations services like DeepL do not use LLMs. They use artificial neural networks, of course.

Comment: @DocBrown LLM's, in the sense that they overwhelmingly *only* generate content. Some companies have found ways to use them more precisely for grammar/translations, but there's others that have simply thrown a face on top of dumping everything into a "rephrase this copy" prompt... which is no better than asking chatgpt directly. Worse even, as it gives a false sense of it being somehow better.

Comment: @ColleenV: thanks for the upvote. You wrote *"just because I think the rule is dumb doesn't mean I think your question about it is not worthwhile"* - are we talking about the same rule? I thought you meant the AI policy of Stackoverflow. If you say that "rule is dumb", you are going even a step further than me (who thinks that rule is just a little bit incomplete).

Comment: the problem with saying "translation/grammar services are allowed" is that's a broad spectrum, as i've already explained. even the one you demonstrated clearly falls into the "generative" category because it is doing far more than just improving grammar.

Comment: @KevinB: then please find a better wording, or give a reference to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424041 - but don't leave it completely to the imagination of the community members.

Comment: The current wording covers it adequately. no AI generated content.

Comment: @KevinB: so you want to ban any translation service? Then say so.

Comment: If the translation service generates content, yes. Not all translation services do. Translation services *did* exist prior to chatgpt.

Comment: Prior to chatgpt we generally frowned upon using translation services because there needs to be an ability for the parties (the asker and the answerers) to be able to understand one another, and one can't accurately communicate if they can't read what they're posting.

Comment: @KevinB: and "generate content" is what you understand by what I cited above from the AI policy of SO (2nd paragraph in my answer)? So you disagree to the Meta.SO question I cited already (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424041/)?

Comment: Are you citing the OP in that post? or ryan's answer, i was citing your prior question on grammar/translations.

Comment: @KevinB: I updated my comment, should be clearer now.

Comment: I flatly disagree with ryan here, as [it's been proven](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425162) using these tools in that way produces inaccurate results.

Comment: @KevinB: well, if the ones who are responsible  for the AI policy text on Stackoverflow (or other sites) agree to you, then they should clearly state this in the policy text, and not give just LLMs as example. If they think translation tools are ok under certain restrictions, they should say that. That's my point.

Comment: @KevinB: having a look into the link in your last comment: where is there a proof that "these tools (like DeepL or Google Translate) produce inaccurate results?

Comment: I appreciate you calling this out as a reminder for any folks who might be interested in defining policy on this for their site. As a reminder, if you're actually proposing changes to the SO policy itself, though, those would be preferable on MSO rather than as an answer to this question, @DocBrown ^_^

Comment: @JNat: actually, I was considering to ask this at MSO, but I think my influence on the policy text will only be small. Do you think the policy text will be discussed with the community? I was under impression this will be done among diamond moderators.

Comment: I would imagine a discussion on the policy wouldn't be an issue, @DocBrown — it's standard practice for other policies to be discussed on Meta, and it is common for those discussions to be started by community members rather than mods seeking their feedback.

Comment: @JNat: given the fact that the SO policy might become a template for other sites, I guess someone should start to discuss it, maybe you are right. But I think I have to care a lot about my wording, otherwise the question will collect a lot of downvotes, especially from the "Zero-AI" fraction ;-) - not that I really care about those virtual points, but I would prefer a constructive discussion, not a heated one.

Comment: @DocBrown this banner already exists on SO, unless you meant discussing the policy itself. (the existing discussions on MSO played a large part in the development of the policy itself)

Comment: @KevinB: yes, I mean the text on https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy, not the banner or the banner text. IMHO that text is mostly ok, it should just be a little bit more explicit about responsible AI usage. But I guess there was already a non-public discussion in the past among mods about this text, so I am under impression this could be in vain.

Comment: I mean, the featured post on MSO regarding the SO policy is where most of the public discussion occurred for SO. it's unlikely more feedback that just retreads an idea that has already proven unpopular wouldn't similarly be unpopular now. it has 128 answers.

Comment: @KevinB: that featured [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) was written a year before the current AI policy text came online. I don't question the generative AI ban, assuming "generative AI" is what the policy explains by the give examples What IMHO should be improved is the fact that the policy does not say a single word if there is some responsible AI usage allowed (where I think of other AI based services than the current LLMs).

Comment: I don’t disagree, but the chances are high any new post discussing the policy will simply be closed as a duplicate. ‍♂️ make a new post if you want, I’m not telling you not to and can’t anyway.

Answer (score -2):

#### Poor Colour Choice

I think this is a good concept and, when tweaked a bit, should be implemented. I agree that verbiage might need to be altered allowing for translations that use AI. I also agree that the banner should be placed on query as well as response composition panels.

The only problem is that the light grey / blue colour is all but invisible. It's such a neutral, friendly colour, much more suitable for an informational bar.

This is a warning bar and ought to be bold and distinct. Make it **RED**.