# Reminder about AI generated answers for non-English SOs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, localization, generative-ai

On the big Stack Overflow we have a notice in the answer box about the AI-generated answers policy:

> [image]

Can we spread the same for the rest of the Stack Overflow sites in non-English languages: [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), and [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: You'd need to do that via a meta question on each site showing support for it.

Comment: Related: *[Is there a list of ChatGPT or other AI-related discussions and policies for our sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384922/)*