# Linking "Similar questions" suggestions from every Stack Exchange website

Tags: feature-request, search, asking-questions, similar-questions

## Suggestions for an addition to the "Similar questions" feature

Each Stack Exchange site has a "Similar questions" list under which the user generates the title for their question.

Here is an example:
[image: "Similar questions" list shown under "Title" entry]

This is very helpful for checking whether a similar question has already been asked and answered. It is also great how it automatically opens in a new tab rather than continuing on the same one, which would have made the user lose their progress in the question they were asking if the question they checked turned out not being similar enough.

I do have two suggestions on that topic, one being an addition to that, the other being towards a similar result.

### Additional data search results

The "Similar questions" feature seems only to be searching within each of their own websites. Another way to describe it would be similar to Google search results: If you search on Google "cat videos", it not only includes videos from YouTube but other sources that have videos of cats, such as Tiktok, Instagram, etc. In the case I am bringing up, I'd like to suggest a Stack Exchange site would include "Similar questions" results from the other Stack Exchange sites the more detail they enter into their question. Not only would that help with finding whether their question had already been answered, but they can also more likely easily notice whether they are in the correct Stack Exchange community.

Although the authentic [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) website includes the search bar for checking within all of the websites like I had mentioned above, it may possibly result in something different, especially because in my suggestion, the users would rather be given the suggestion when asking their questions rather than them searching for it themself. It would also somehow be similar to double-checking. Including Metas would also be a great source, assuming the use of those is rather to have those questions that may possibly not be considered the correct category checked there before continuing.

### Suggestion to which Stack Exchange website is appropriate

With a similar goal as above, I'd like to suggest there is a suggestion to which Stack Exchange website is appropriate for the user's questions as they type. For example, if I start writing the body or title for a question about how to develop a game in the [Arqade Stack Exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), it would pick up the words "game" and "develop", and point me towards [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) instead while still holding a draft of my question as I access Game Development (and if I were to be a new user, create my account). Of course, there should include a "No, I'm in the correct place" button as well. Maybe a way of rather encouraging the users to check whether they are in the correct place is a better way to explain this rather than stating it.

I understand these would most likely include data storage, length of time to process gained, regular expressions, and/or either continuous updates or a function that notices new changes, but this would result in an easier-to-navigate overall Stack Exchange build, especially with there being over 100 of them.

Comment: Note: you can search all sites on https://stackexchange.com/. Recommendation: update your title to describe what your proposals are, and consider splitting the two into individual feature-request posts with links to each other. Although your first one might want reconsidering if you didn't know about https://stackexchange.com/'s all-site search feature. Maybe you'd want to propose somehow telling people it exists.

Comment: @starball Thank you for notifying me. I will still keep it in there, and I wrote a reason for how it may end with a different result from what you mentioned because of the addition.

Comment: Each site has its own purpose; except a few isolated examples, a question that is on topic on one community is considered off topic on another (even between sites like math overflow and mathematics). As you mentioned, google already gives you search results across different platforms, and there is a functionality within SE as well. The only real "benefit" of your suggestion would be redirecting people to the appropriate site to ask their questions, but I don't think an automated system is capable of that. Sometimes I cannot decide whether something should be on SO or SU.

Comment: About suggesting to which SE site the question be appropriate, [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with "crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/289691)