# Can I ask the same question on more than one Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions, stack-exchange

I have a question relevant to Android SE, Programmers SE and Stack Overflow. Should/Can I ask on all three sites?

**Update**:
I'd like restate my question:

If I have a question relevant to more than one Stack Exchange site, should I ask it on all relevant sites?

Comment: are you really sure, the question relevant for all 3 sites?

Comment: I think this question is transcendent even if my issue were not relevant for the 3 sites.
Should I change "I have a question..." by "If I'd have a question..." ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073

Comment: See also: [How can I "ping" other communities / Stack Exchange sites without cross-posting the question? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355553/how-can-i-ping-other-communities-stack-exchange-sites-without-cross-posting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have thought it unlikely that a single question would be relevant to three sites - particularly the three sites you mention.

Looking at the FAQs for [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq) -

> Android - Stack Exchange is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people too using the Android operating system.
>
> Android - Stack Exchange is not for programming questions. Please ask your developer questions on Stack Overflow.

we see straight away that there is **no** overlap between the two sites. A question relevant and on topic for one site **is automatically** off topic for the other. Of course your question could be off topic on **both**.

As you've stated in a comment that your "question is not about development" then it's off topic for Stack Overflow so that leaves a choice between Android and Programmers'.

We can also see that if it's on topic for Android it's probably off topic for Programmers' as Programmers' is for questions about the development process (amongst other things).

While this answer is directed at the three sites in your original question the same logic applies (most of the time) for your broader question. The only sites were there is significant overlap are Super User and Ask Ubuntu, Unix & Linux and Apple - but even there your question should only be posted on **one** site.

Comment: I think you are wrong when you said "There is no overlap between the two sites". FAQ says "Please ask your developer questions on Stack Overflow". My question is not about development, but is relevant to OS.

Comment: @texai - if your question isn't about development then it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @texai if it is not about development, then it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow

Comment: Ok ok, I've changed the question. Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 9):

No.

Ask on the site you feel is the best match to your question (or, often, your *job title*).

If you don't get an acceptable answer, it is OK to **delete** the question -- flag it for mod attention if necessary -- and re-ask on another site.

Also, any talk of cutting and pasting questions on multiple sites is a very bad idea.

**Your questions should *always* be tailored to the specific community of people that you are asking.**

Answer (score 1):

You should ask question on any one of the SE sites and then let the community decide where it belongs to and migrate accordingly.