# Ask question over multiple sites

Tags: feature-request, multiple-accounts

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can I ask the same question in more than one stackExchange site ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80216/can-i-ask-the-same-question-in-more-than-one-stackexchange-site)
>   [Is it possible to post questions across a couple of the sites because it's debatable which site it fits best?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata)

I would like to make a feature request to ask a question over multiple sites. There are instances that to solve a particular problem, collective discussion is required.

For example, if I faced a problem booting with Windows, Ubuntu and some other BSD OS, it could be possibly due multiple factors from each of the involved OSs. If I fail to find answer on Ask Ubuntu, I might want to consult *nix site. If they can't help either, the Super User site may provide the solution. A second example would be an Android user trying to install Linux distro on his tablet - the Android site can help with unlocking the bootloader, while the folks at Ask Ubuntu can help the user install Ubuntu on his device. Or it might be someone from Super User that has the solution.

So my suggestion is that I ask meta moderators to review the question for it appear on multiple sites with the existing discussion and posts. The promotion may only take place after it has spent a number of days unresolved (a week or so maybe).

Comment: @ChrisF @Yi Jiang Those questions discusses repeat posting of the same question. I, on the other hand, is suggesting that one single question and all it's answer viewable from multiple sites.

Comment: As the other answers explain, this is not what the intension is. You ask the question on one site where it fits 100%. If a question doesn't get answered there, it can be flagged and migrated to another SE site. The questions should never live in more then one place.

Comment: @Diago, I don't care where it lives, I just want the question and it's answers viewable to multiple sites at the same time.

Comment: If you need help from multiple sites, your question is too broad, split it. If your question gets poor reception on one site and you think it's also ok on another site, flag it and ask a moderator to migrate it (often you'll want to edit it, at the very least retag it).

Answer (score 1):

If the OP wants to ask the question in several places, surely the facility is already there.

But equally if you want to ask a question on the Ubuntu site, which doesn't get a suitable reply won't you at least want to re-phrase it a bit before putting it on to the *nix site?

If a question is not answered then isn't it possible that the question is bad - rather than it just being the location that is wrong?

In any event I'm not convinced that this problem is so common that it needs an automated solution.  So, I'm out.

Comment: I'm in agreement that those are possible reasons that the question is not being resolved which why I suggested that if the questioner requests it to be viewable in other sites, it should be reviewed by meta moderators.

Comment: @Toki, review by the moderators is a fair point - but I will guess that they are already busy.

Comment: This is a free service, no one has the right to put pressure on other users. If users have the patience to wait for an answer, they can have the patience to wait for it to be reviewed. And while I'm at it I protest the closure of the question as what I'm asking is fundamentally different from the questions tagged as duplicates.

Comment: Ubuntu -> Unix is a bit of an exceptions, most questions on Ubuntu would be ok on Unix too, you'd just need to retag a little.