# Can the same question be asked on more than one site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, answers, serverfault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I ask the same question in more than one stackExchange site ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80216/can-i-ask-the-same-question-in-more-than-one-stackexchange-site)

As mainly a web developer I look at and answer questions that I see on Stack Overflow.

As part of my day to day job I often have to configure and setup IIS and web servers.

However, whilst I do this, it does not make me want to refresh Server Fault continuously throughout the day, even though I'm sure I could possibly answer a few.

When I have an IIS/WebServer related question then I ask it on Server Fault.

However, I'm sure there are a lot of people looking at Stack Overflow that would be able to answer my question equally well.

Is there a way of requesting that a question could appear on both sites? Even just for a small time frame? It could possibly be very heavily REP capped, e.g. you can ask a question on one site, and suggest that it be displayed on any other sites that you have more than 1k rep on. Something like that?

Stack Overflow is always so great at getting so many good answers to so many questions. I always find Server Fault and Super User quite disappointing that they're not as good. As I said, I am a culprit in this as I do not look as the other sites as regularly as Stack Overflow, there's only so much you can do. It's kind of a catch 22 situation!