# Are questions about how to use Process Monitor on topic to Super User?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1712217/how-can-i-view-details-for-a-specific-process-using-the-process-monitor-on-windo) on Super User, because it seemed that Super User was the most appropriate SE site, based on its [on topic page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). My reasoning was that I was asking for general help about using software.

However, I was a bit concerned whether Server Fault could have been a more appropriate site for the question, since my question was about using a program often used for system administration, and [Server Fault's on topic page](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) lists questions about "tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these" as on topic.

Did I make the right choice with the SE site I posted my question to?

Comment: It could be equally on-topic for both sites: cf. https://serverfault.com/search?q=%22process+monitor%22 and https://superuser.com/search?q=%22process+monitor%22

Comment: Question X being on-topic for site Y does not mean it is off-topic for site Z.

Comment: In general, if a question pertains to a single computer not part of a domain, it will most likely be on-topic in Super User. If it pertains to a computer that is part of a domain, it will probably be on-topic in Server Fault.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's definitely on-topic for Super User. In fact, they even have a [process-monitor](/questions/tagged/process-monitor) tag (which you seem to have used):

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. ([See questions tagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/process-monitor) [process-monitor](/questions/tagged/process-monitor))

Don't worry about your question being on-topic for multiple sites; you could always follow this [advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80216/can-i-ask-the-same-question-on-more-than-one-stack-exchange-site) from [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood):

> Ask on the site you feel is the best match to your question (or, often, your *job title*).
>
> If you don't get an acceptable answer, it is OK to **delete** the question -- flag it for mod attention if necessary -- and re-ask on another site.
>
> [...]
>
> Your questions should always be *tailored* to the specific community of people that you are asking.