# What should be done when a question that is asked on two SE sites is found?

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions

I read in another question that asking the same question on different SE sites is generally not acceptable.
What should I do if i find a question is asked in two different SE sites for which the question would be on-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the site which seems less on-topic, flag for mod attention, and give the mod a link to the crossposted question.  They can take it from there.

Answer (score 3):

I references this exact case in the Meta post I made some moments before you here: [Clarification regarding cross-posting rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87739/clarification-regarding-cross-posting-rules) where the moderator wrote:

> There is no concept of closing as a duplicate on another site. Each site is autonomous. This is a rare case of where the question might actually be appropriate on BOTH sites-- one set of answer from the point of view of an expert on the subject, the other from a skeptic challenging the science.

In a comment on [Is stretching beneficial after exercise?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/stretching-after-exercise)

Comment: The case I am referring to is different. The questions I have seen are the same in both the sites, and they are on-topic on both the sites; actually, the question should suit better one of the sites because it is more specific. The problem is that the questions are not asking different point of views for the same subject.

Comment: Ah okay. I guess it's more similar to the issue I caused the prompted me to ask for a clarification in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[On an earlier thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata), the accepted answer to “is cross-posting acceptable?” is

> NO
>
> Ask the question on the site you think is most applicable. If like in this case, it does not get any answer ask a moderator to migrate the question or alternatively delete it and re-ask it.

And Jeff writes that

> Just to be 100% clear, copy-pasting a question across sites with no changes is considered abusive behavor.

I'm active on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), which has the occasional cross-post with [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). When I see a user asking the same question on two or more sites, I leave a comment (on both sites) with a link to the other question and requesting the asker to stick to one site. Examples: [UL+AU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9182/copy-a-directory-to-external-hdd), [UL+SU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/keymapping-problem-when-working-with-emacs-and-openbox). [U&L's FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) explicitly tells not to cross-post. Ideally, the question gets closed on all but one sites before it starts to get redundant answers (which is the main problem with cross-posts).

Note that this about the case when a user posts the same question at substantially the same time on more than one site. If one of the versions has answers, the others should be closed.
Otherwise, which version to keep is up to the asker, unless the question is off-topic on one of the sites.

If someone asks a question on one site, and there's a previous question on another site that could be considered a duplicate, let it live: each site should live its own life. But leave a comment with a link to the earlier discussion, so that people don't duplicate earlier work. And leave a link in the other direction too, since the answers to the new question may shed more light.