# Cross posting and help center/guidelines

Tags: discussion, help-center, cross-posting

Cross posting is disallowed, but doesn't seem to be [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=%22cross+post%22) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=%22cross+posting%22).  It's clear from a search on meta, but should it be made more conspicuous for beginning users?

[Related question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: Cross posting? Do you mean spamming a question on multiple sites to increase odds of an answer? Or re-asking a question after a comment that "*you might get a better response at X*"? Or something else? The term is [vague enough](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87739/212780) that it might just fit better here on meta. The help center *does* say to go to meta for any additional questions.

Comment: It probably would fit in the last section of [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Geobits - From the original context, it's in regards the "you might get a better response"/"this is more on topic at" case.

Comment: I agree with @Bobson.  [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223495/english-term-for-naive-user-test-or-idiot-test) is the question that led me to post here.  I've also obliviously crossposted after the original was closed as offtopic, in search of someone who'd know the answer.  Question in point: [first posting](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53752/microhard-910-920-compatibility) [second posting](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/795/how-can-microhard-920-series-modems-be-made-compatible-with-microhard-910-series/802#802)

Comment: While cross-posting is discouraged on the Stack Exchange network, it is not enforced by the software.  I'm not sure we should concern ourselves with cross-posting in each individual site's Help Center, unless it is done in [DontAsk](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Off topicness isn't enforced by the software either, except in the sense that the post gets voted closed, but that can apply to cross-posting too.