# Is it ok to delete question on one Stack Exchange site (for lack of response) and post it on another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, site-crossover, cross-posting

When asking questions related to SharePoint, I generally post them on [SharePoint Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/). But sometimes I don't receive any responses to my question, so I delete the question from SharePoint Stack Exchange and repost it on Stack Overflow.

Is this behavior correct, or will I be penalized for it if this happens frequently?

Comment: If your deletion removes good answers - don't do it

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87739/clarification-regarding-cross-posting-rules

Comment: @JanDvorak: I delete my questions when there isn't any response to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only delete a question when it has no answers or one answer with no upvotes. There is, however, a penalty for deleting too many questions - do it too often and you will be blocked from asking for a while.

If the question can't be deleted you could ask for migration - but this is likely to be rejected, after all your question is on topic on the Sharepoint site.

Other than that there's nothing to stop you doing what you outline in your question.

Comment: If you delete a question without answers the only thing you lose related to the Q ban is the ability to improve the question later.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting negative-scored question, and possibly deleting zero-scored questions does count towards a question ban, if the question was less than 30 days old when deleted, so you should not do so regularly.

Deleting positive-scored questions is afaik not penalized, but I would not do it regardless. If a question is well-received, what does it matter that it has not received an answer yet? On low-traffic sites it can take a while. It may still get one, or someone may encounter the same problem and put a bounty on it. If everyone on a low-traffic site deleted their unanswered questions, the problem would be self-reinforcing.

The matter of cross-posting is independent on whether you delete your previous question and thereby 'hide your tracks', so to speak. If the question is on-topic on both sites, you wait a sufficient amount of time between reasking, and you tailor the question for each site individually, I don't see a problem.

You could even use the answer you get on one site to self-answer the question on the other site, including a reference to the first answer. That way the site with less traffic gets a good answer, and future visitors will be more likely to find it.

Comment: If you delete a question without answers the only thing you lose related to the Q ban is the ability to improve the question later.

Comment: I was under the impression that deleted questions are weighted more, since they cannot accumulate additional downvotes. However I have no source for this and may be completely wrong.

Comment: Cross-posting is not allowed.  Period.  Even if it is on-topic on both sites and you wait a while and get no answers... cross-posting is still not allowed.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917.  (I'm not commenting on the tailoring part because it's not very clear to me what you mean by that, or indeed how much tailoring would happen in practice, but I suspect that even with some tailoring, cross-posting probably still will not be appropriate.)

Comment: To quote [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75012/182796): "this can be OK, so long as the question is tailored to each audience on the different sites and is materially different in each case. "