# Cross-site posting feature

Tags: feature-request, site-crossover, cross-posting

I sometimes have questions that are suitable for 2 or more Stack Exchange sites. For example, a question on configuring a development database for a website.

This question could be posted on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Wouldn't it be a good feature if you can post the question on one site, then just register it as a 'cross-site post' so that the question and all its answers can be visible on all the sites that it is marked for.

This will cut down on cross-site posting, and allow the same question to be answered by experts with different expertise.

This will promote cross site collaboration, as different users from different sites will be able to see how other parties are answering or commenting on the same question.

Comment: And, ummm, why is one site not enough?

Comment: I am not talking about migrating questions. I am asking on how to have 1 question be visible on multiple sites at once.

Comment: I actually have a question on querying 2 separate databases using 1 login. That question could be solved programmatically or by configuring the databases. So it could be under stack overflow or database admin. Instead of posting 2 different question, it will be useful for a cross site collaboration.

Comment: "this can be OK, so long as the question is _tailored_ to each audience on the different sites and is materially different in each case..." ([Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info))

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate! The other questions are about how users should behave at present, i.e. without cross-posting as a feature in the StackExchange software. This question is about whether that feature is desirable.

Comment: The second duplicate is all about it @reinierpost

Comment: Patrick: True, it also wonders about features, but it's not as specific.

Answer (score 4):

You could **tailor** your question for each site:

- for stack overflow ask about the programmatic issue
- for database admin ask about configuring the database.

Make sure your question is **different** on each site.

Comment: What i am asking for is a way for different people to collaborate. Stack overflow is usually visited by programmers, database admin is visited by administrators. So it will be useful if they could work together to comment and answer questions that crosses expertise. Instead of walling each question off, different roles could provide different views on the same question.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @reinierpost <shrug>. I downvoted the question to indicate that it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can register in multiple sites and in this way, someone who is an expert in programming and database administration can have an account on both sites, so there is nothing that prevents users to answer your question on either site. That makes the feature request useless.

[Cross-posting isn't necessarily bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87749/245360), but usually it is best to post on one site. Just copying a question to another site seems the wrong thing to do. There should be some distinction in them: the question should either emphasize programming *or* database administration. And you can't emphasize with your feature request.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: And that is because?

Comment: Because this doesn't answer whether implementing crossposting in the software, which would allow a single question to appear on multiple sites without duplicating it, would be a good idea.

Comment: @reinierpost I quote: "That makes the feature request useless.", "There should be some distinction in them... And you can't emphasize with your feature request." I clearly stated it is a bad idea *plus* I gave my reasons for it. Why do you think I didn't answer the question?